# Tips for golfing in Mathematica

Tags: code-golf, tips

What general tips do you have for golfing in Mathematica? I'm looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to Mathematica (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Tips below vary from the most economical to the most often used:

1. Use Mathematica's high-level commands where possible, even bulky ones:

   - `MorphologicalComponents`: [Code-Golf: Count Islands](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6979/code-golf-count-islands/6980#6980)
   - Image manipulation capabilities: e.g. [Today (September 24) is HONDA birthday](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12627/today-september-24-is-honda-birthday/12639#12639)
   - `Subsets`
   - `IntegerPartitions`
   - [Distance and Similarity measures:](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/DistanceAndSimilarityMeasures.html) e.g. `EuclideanDistance` can be a byte saver. Note however, that it's usually shorter to write `Total@Abs[a-b]` instead of `a~ManhattanDistance~b` and `Max@Abs[a-b]` instead of `a~ChessboardDistance~b`.
2. Use `Graphics and` `Text` for Ascii art: e.g [Star programming!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7107/star-programming/7109#7109)
   and [Build an analog clock](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10759/build-an-analog-clock/10761#10761)
3. Dedicated symbols:

   - logic and set operations symbols instead of their long form names: 
     ⋂, ⋃, ∧, ∨
   - `Map` and `Apply`: `/@`, `//@`. `@@`, `@@@`
4. Prefix and infix notation:

   - `Print@"hello"` in place of `Print["hello"]`
   - `a~f~b` in place of `f[a,b]`
5. When a function is used only once, a pure function may economize a character or two.
6. Joining strings in a list. `""<>{"a","b","c"}` instead of `StringJoin@{"a","b","c"}`
7. Exploit listable functions. The longer the lists the better.

   `{a, b, c} + {x, y, z}= {a+x, b+y, c+z}`

   `{2, 3, 4} {5, 6, 7}= {10, 18, 28}`

   `{{a, b}, {c, d}}^{2, 3} = {{a^2, b^2}, {c^3, d^3}}`

Comment: It's *always* shorter to write `(Norm[#-#2]&)` instead of `EuclideanDistance`.

Answer (score 41):

Some built-in functions with long names can be replaced with shorter expressions.

For example:

- `Total` => `Tr` for 1d arrays
- `Transpose` => `Thread` or `` (`\[Transpose]`)
- `True` => `1<2`
- `False` => `1>2`
- `Times` => `1##&`
- `Alternatives` => `$|##&`
- `IntegerQ` => `⌊#⌋==#&` or `1∣#&` (Thanks to [@Misha Lavrov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/74672/misha-lavrov))
- `a[[1]]` => `#&@@a`
- `a[[All,1]]` => `#&@@@a`
- `ConstantArray[a,n]` => `Array[a&,n]` or `Table[a,n]`
- `Union@a` => `{}⋃a` or `a⋃a`
- `ToExpression@n` => `FromDigits@n` if `n` is a number
- `Divisible[n,m]` => `m∣n`
- `FromDigits[n,2]` => `Fold[#+##&,n]` if `n` is a list of `0`s and `1`s
- `Complex@z` => `{1,I}.z` where `z` is a list of the form `{x,y}`
- `Rest@FoldList[f[#,#2]&,x,l]` => `t=x;(t=f[t,#])&/@l`
- `Table[f[i,l],{i,Length@l}]` => `i=1;f[i++,l]&/@l`
- `CoefficientList[f,x]` => `(f+O@x^n)[[3]]` if you know that the degree of the polynomial `f` is `n` and the constant term is not zero
- `FractionalPart[x]` => `Mod[x,1]` if x is nonnegative

Comment: I don't get the `Transpose[]` thing

Comment: @belisarius `Thread[{{a,b},{c,d}}]`==`Thread[List[{a,b},{c,d}]]`==`{List[a,c],List[b,d]}`==`{{a,c},{b,d}}`==`Transpose[{{a,b},{c,d}}]`

Comment: Oh, I see. Very clever:)

Comment: I think your `Fold` trick for `FromDigits` also works for any other base except `10`. E.g. `FromDigits[n,5]` --> `Fold[4#+##&,n]` (with the bonus of saving an extra byte for bases `100` and `1000`).

Comment: How many bytes is `\[Transpose]`?

Comment: @mbomb007 3 bytes in UTF-8. In fact this character is `U+F3C7`.

Comment: Is it possible to type the symbol with a keyboard, or would I need to copy/paste it?

Comment: @mbomb007 Just type `\[Transpose]` in a Mathematica notebook.

Comment: I mean is it possible to type it on PPCG?

Comment: @mbomb007 ``. It's in the private use area.

Comment: What "private use area"?

Comment: @mbomb007 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas

Comment: I finally installed 10.3. If we're considering full programs, I don't think `Echo` is an option, because it prints `>>` (and a space) to STDOUT before printing the actual string.

Comment: `⌊` and `⌋` take at least 3 bytes each, I think? So the `IntegerQ` replacement is longer.

Comment: For `Complex[x,y] => {1,I}.{x,y}`, I think `x+y*I` is much shorter with the same effect?

Comment: As mentioned, `⌊#⌋==#&` is not an improvement on `IntegerQ` (it's the same number of bytes as `Floor@#==#&`) but `1∣#&` (where `∣` is the 3-byte Unicode symbol for `\[Divides]`) is. Example: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173447

Comment: @ShieruAsakoto that form is useful with `Complex@@z` vs `{1,I}.z` where `z={x,y}`

Comment: `Identity`/`#&` (single argument identity function) -> `D` or `N`

Answer (score 25):

### Lists with repeated values

This is quite a common vector to work with:

```
{0,0}
```

It turns out this can be shortened by a byte:

```
0{,}
```

Even more bytes are saved if the vector is longer than two zeros. This can also be used to initialise zero matrices, e.g. the following gives a 2x2 matrix of zeros:

```
0{{,},{,}}
```

This can also be used for non-zero values if they're sufficiently large or sufficiently many or negative. Compare the following pairs:

```
{100,100}
0{,}+100
```

```
{-1,-1}
0{,}-1
```

```
{3,3,3,3}
0{,,,}+3
```

But remember that starting at 6 values, you're better off with `1~Table~6` in this case (potentially earlier, depending on precedence requirements).

The reason this works is that `,` introduces two arguments to the list, but omitted arguments (anywhere in Mathematica) are implicit `Null`s. Furthermore, multiplication is `Listable`, and `0*x` is `0` for almost any `x` (except for things like `Infinity` and `Indeterminate`), so here is what's happening:

```
  0{,}
= 0*{,}
= 0*{Null,Null}
= {0*Null,0*Null}
= {0,0}
```

For lists of `1`s, you can use a similar trick by making use of exponentiation rules. There are two different ways to save bytes if you have at least three `1`s in the list:

```
{1,1,1}
1^{,,}
{,,}^0
```

Comment: +1; this just goes to show that while Mathematica may have a built-in for everything, golfing in it can be a real challenge.

Comment: If you want an array that's ultimately filled with 1s, then `1^{,,,}` is one byte smaller than `0{,,,}+1`.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Oh, good catch. That makes it shorter at three values and you can also use `{,,}^0`. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 22):

## Know your pure function arguments

When golfing code, you'll often employ a functional approach, where you use anonymous (pure) functions with the `&` shorthand syntax. There are a lot of different ways to access the arguments of such a function, and you can often shave off a couple of bytes by having a good grasp on the possibilities.

### Accessing single arguments

You probably know this if you've used pure functions before. The **n**th argument is referred to as `#n`, and `#` acts as an alias for `#1`. So if, say, you want to write a function that takes as parameters another function and its argument (to pass the argument to that function), use

```
#@#2&
```

This does *not* work with negative numbers (such as you might use when accessing lists).

### Accessing named arguments (new in V10)

One of the major new language features in Mathematica 10 is `Association`s, which are basically key-value maps with arbitrary key types, written like

```
<| x -> 1, "abc" -> 2, 5 -> 3 |>
```

If such an association is passed in as the *first* argument to a pure function, you can access some if its arguments as named parameters:

```
{#, #2, #3, #abc, #xyz} & [<| "abc" -> "1st", "xyz" -> "2nd", abc -> "3rd" |>, "4th", "5th"]
(* {<| "abc" -> "1st", "xyz" -> "2nd", abc -> "3rd" |>, "4th", "5th", "1st", "2nd"} *)
```

Note that `#` still refers to the entire association as expected. For the named parameters to work, the keys have to be *strings* (it won't work if you use undefined variables for instance), and those strings must begin with a letter and only contain letters and digits.

### The "self" argument `#0`

A lesser known feature is that `#0` also exists, and gives you the function object itself. This can be really useful in quines and generalised quines. In fact, the shortest Mathematica quine (I know of) is

```
ToString[#0][] & []
```

What's slightly annoying is that it won't give you the exact characters you entered. E.g. if use `@` for function application, it will still render as `[...]` and spaces will be inserted in some places. This will usually make the quine a bit longer than you'd like it to be, but it will always work, by golfing the quine first, and then just copying its output - which should now be a real quine.

Apart from quines, this also means that you can write recursive code without having to name your function. Compare these three (naive but golfed) Fibonacci implementations:

```
f@0=0;f@1=1;f@n_:=f[n-1]+f[n-2]
f@n_:=If[n<2,n,f[n-1]+f[n-2]]
If[#<2,#,#0[#-1]+#0[#-2]]&
```

### Sequences of arguments

Now this is where the real magic starts. Sequences aren't used often in golfing, because `Sequence` it's just too long a name to be worth it most of the time. But in pure functions is where they shine. If you're not familiar with sequences, they are basically like splats in some other languages, if you use a sequence in a `List` or the argument list of a function, it's elements will automatically be expanded into separate slots. So

```
{1, Sequence[2, 3, 4], 5} == {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
f["a", Sequence[0, {}], "b"] == f["a", 0, {}, "b"]
```

Now, in pure functions `##` or `##1` is a sequence of all the arguments. Likewise, `##2` is a sequence of all arguments starting from the second, `##3` all arguments starting from the third etc. So for a start, we can just reimplement `Sequence` as `##&`, saving 5 bytes. As an example usage, this provides us with an alternative to `Join@@list` (see [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12930/8478)), which doesn't save any bytes, but is good to know about anyway:

```
 ##&@@@list
```

This effectively flattens the first level of a nested list. What else can we do with this? Here is a 1-byte saving for `RotateLeft`:

```
 RotateLeft@list
 {##2,#}&@@list
```

For these things alone it's worth keeping this feature in mind. However, we can do better! Sequences get really interesting when consider that operators are actually implemented as functions under the hood. E.g. `a+b` actually evaluates to `Plus[a,b]`. So if we give that a sequence...

```
1+##&[1,2,3]
=> Plus[1,##] 
=> Plus[1,1,2,3]
=> 7
```

This trick has been use [in this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12922/8478) to save a byte on `Times`, because juxtaposition is technically also just an operator:

```
1##&[1,2,3]
=> Times[1,##]
=> Times[1,1,2,3]
=> 6
```

You can also use it to save a byte on `Unequal` if you have a single-character value or variable you know is not in your arguments (`N` will probably work in 99% of the cases):

```
Unequal[a,b,c]
N!=##&[a,b,c]
```

This gets even more interesting with unary operators and `-` and `/` - the latter two are actually implemented in terms of multiplication and exponentiation. Here is a list of things you can do, where the last column assumes that the function was passed the arguments `a, b, c`:

```
Operator    Function                Expanded                    Equivalent to

+##         Plus[##]                Plus[a,b,c]                 a+b+c
1##         Times[1,##]             Times[1,a,b,c]              a*b*c
-##         Times[-1,##]            Times[-1,a,b,c]             -a*b*c
x+##        Plus[x,##]              Plus[x,a,b,c]               x+a+b+c
x-##        Plus[x,Times[-1,##]]    Plus[x,Times[-1,a,b,c]]     x-a*b*c
x##         Times[x,##]             Times[x,a,b,c]              x*a*b*c
x/##        Times[x,Power[##,-1]]   Times[x,Power[a,b,c,-1]]    x*a^b^c^-1
##/x        Times[##,Power[x,-1]]   Times[a,b,c,Power[x,-1]]    a*b*c/x
x^##        Power[x,##]             Power[x,a,b,c]              x^a^b^c
##^x        Power[##,x]             Power[a,b,c,#]              a^b^c^x
x.##        Dot[x,##]               Dot[x,a,b,c]                x.a.b.c
```

Other common operators are `!=`, `==`, `&&`, `||`. Less common ones to keep in mind are `|`, `@*`, `/*`. To conclude, here is a little bonus trick:

```
####        Times[##,##]            Times[a,b,c,a,b,c]          (a*b*c)^2
```

Keep experimenting with these, and let me know if you find any other useful or particularly interesting applications!

Comment: I think you meant `{##2,#}&@@list` rather than `{##2,#}&@list`.

Comment: @theorist Good catch, thank you!

Answer (score 19):

`Sqrt@2` or `2^.5` => `√2`

`a[[1]]`=>`a〚1〛`

`#+#2&`=>`+##&`

`Flatten@a`=>`Join@@a` (sometimes)

`Function[x,x^2]`=>`xx^2` or `#^2&`

`a〚1;;-1;;2〛`=>`a〚;;;;2〛`

`a〚2;;-1 ;;2〛`=>`a〚2;;;;2〛`

`a〚All,1〛`=>`a〚;;,1〛`

`{{1}}〚1,1〛`=>`Tr@{{1}}`

`0&~Array~10`=>`0Range@10`

`Range[10^3]`=>`Range@1*^3`

Comment: Note that when measuring by bytes, using `〚` and `〛` takes 3 bytes each (assume UTF8)

Comment: Note that, while`Sqrt@2` ⟹ √2, `2^.5` !⟹ √2 (at least not exactly), as the latter will return a numerical result rather than a symbolic one, i.e., 1.14121...

Answer (score 14):

### Operators as Functions

[Inspired by Dennis's recent discovery for Julia](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/81028/8478) I thought I'd look into this for Mathematica. I was aware that Mathematica defines a large number of unused operators, but never paid much attention to it.

For reference, [the list of all operators can be found here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) in the form of a precedence table. The triangle in the last column indicates whether that operator has a built-in meaning or not. While not all of those that don't can be defined easily, most of them can.

Conveniently, there are two unused operators with a codepoint less than 256, such that they can be used as single bytes in an ISO 8859-1 encoded source file:

- `±` (0xB1) can be used either as a unary prefix operator or a binary infix operator.
- `·` (0xB7) can be used as a variadic or n-ary infix operator, for n > 2.

There's one more catch though: for some weird reason when *defining* these operators you need one space in front of them, or else Mathematica tries to parse a multiplication. When using them you don't need any spaces though:

```
±x_:=2x
x_ ±y_:=x+y
x_ ·y_ ·z_:=x*y+z
Print[±5]  (* 10 *)
Print[3±4] (*  7 *)
Print[3·4·5] (* 17 *)
```

Compare this with:

```
f@x_:=2x
x_~g~y_:=x+y
h[x_,y_,z_]:=x*y+z
Print[f@5]   (* 10 *)
Print[3~g~4] (*  7 *)
Print[h[x,y,z]] (* 17 *)
```

So this saves one byte when defining the function and two bytes when using it. Note that the definition of `·` will not save bytes for four operands and will start costing bytes for more operands, but the usage may still save bytes, depending the precedence of operators used in the arguments. It's also good to note that you can cheaply define a variadic function that can then be called much more efficiently:

```
x_ ·y__:={y}
Print[1·2·3·4·5] (* {2, 3, 4, 5} *)
```

But note that it's not easily possible to call these variadic functions with a single argument. (You could do `CenterDot[x]` or `##&[]·x` but if you actually need that there's a good chance you're better off with a different solution.)

Of course, this isn't saving anything for solutions where an unnamed function suffices, but sometimes you need to define helper functions for use later on, and sometimes it's shorter to define named functions e.g. to set up different definitions for different parameters. In those cases, using an operator instead can save a decent amount of bytes.

Note that using these ISO 8859-1 encoded files requires `$CharacterEncoding` to be set to a compatible value, like the Windows default `WindowsANSI`. On some systems this defaults to `UTF-8` which won't be able to read these code points from single bytes.

Comment: This is really great, I did not know Mathematica had a list of operators, and even included their precedence. Those two operators you found I'm sure will come in handy.

Answer (score 11):

1. **Explore recursive solutions** -  Mathematica is multi-paradigm, but the functional approach is often the most economical. `NestWhile` can be a very compact solution to searching problems, and `NestWhileList` and `FoldList` are powerful when you need to return or process the results of intermediate iterations. `Map (/@)`, `Apply (@@, @@@)`, `MapThread`, and really everything on Wolfram's [Functional Programming](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/FunctionalProgramming.html) documentation page is potent stuff.
2. **Shortened form for increment/decrement** - For example, instead of `While[i<1,*code*;i++]` you can do
   `While[i++<1,*code*]`
3. **Don't forget you can pre-increment/decrement** - For example, `--i` instead of `i--`. This can sometimes save you a few bytes in the surrounding code by eliminating a preparatory operation.
4. Corollary to David Carraher's #5: **When the same function is used many times, assigning a symbol to it can save bytes.** For example, if you are using `ToExpression` 4 times in a solution, `t=ToExpression` enables you to use `t@*expression*` thereafter. However, before you do this consider whether the repeated application of the same function indicates an opportunity for a more economical recursive approach.

Comment: `MapThread` can often be replaced by `\[Transpose]`. [TIO](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvJFpBQcE3sSAkoyg1MSU6Tae62lDHSMe4VqfaRMdUx6y2NhaoIJYLrjbNwcFBA0PR@/52BQVNBQiI/f8fAA).

Answer (score 11):

## Choosing values based on integer

The naive approach to choose between `y` and `z`, depending on whether `x` is `0` or `1` is

```
If[x<1,y,z]
```

However, there's a shorter way:

```
y[z][[x]]
```

This works because `[[0]]` gives the `Head` of an expression, in this case `y`, whereas `[[1]]` just gives the first element - in this case the first argument, `z`.

You can even use this to choose between more than two values:

```
u[v,w][[x]]
```

Note that this won't work if `u` is a function that actually evaluates to something. It's important that Mathematica keeps `u[v,w]` as it is. However, this works in most cases, including if `u` is a is a number, a string or a list.

Credits for this trick go to alephalpha - I discovered this in one of his answer.

If `x` is 1-based instead of zero-based, just use

```
{y,z}[[x]]
```

or

```
{u,v,w}[[x]]
```

In some rare cases, you can even make use of the fact that multiplication is not evaluated for some values:

```
{"abc","def"}[[x]]
("abc""def")[[x]]
```

Note though that Mathematica will actually reorder the arguments, of a multiplication if it remains unevaluated, so the above is *identical* to

```
("def""abc")[[x]]
```

Answer (score 9):

### Alternatives to `Length`

*This has been entirely rewritten with some suggestions from LegionMammal978 and Misha Lavrov. Many thanks to both of them.*

In many cases, `Length` can be shortened a bit by making use of `Tr`. The basic idea is to turn the input into a list of `1`s, so that `Tr` sums them up which will then equal the length of the list.

The most common way to do this is to use `1^x` (for a list `x`). This works because `Power` is `Listable` and `1^n` for most atomic values `n` is just `1` (including all numbers, strings and symbols). So we can already save one byte with this:

```
Length@x
Tr[1^x]
```

Of course, this assumes that `x` is an expression with higher precedence than `^`.

If `x` contains only `0`s and `1`s, we can save another byte using `Factorial` (assuming `x` has higher precedence than `!`):

```
Length@x
Tr[x!]
```

In some rare cases, `x` might have lower precedence than `^` but still higher precedence than multiplication. In that case it will also have lower precedence than `@`, so we really need to compare with `Length[x]`. An example of such an operator is `.`. In those cases, you can still save a byte with this form:

```
Length[x.y]
Tr[0x.y+1]
```

Finally, some remarks about what kind of lists this works on:

As mentioned at the top, this works on flat lists containing only numbers, strings and symbols. However, it will also work on some deeper lists, although it actually computes something slightly different. For an **n**-D rectangular array, using `Tr` gives you the *shortest* dimension (as opposed to the first). If you know that the outermost dimension is the shortest, or you know they're all the same, than the `Tr`-expressions are still equivalent to `Length`.

Comment: Just found an even shorter solution: `Length@x == Tr[1^x]`. Should work with most lists.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 that's amazing, thanks :). I'll edit it in soon.

Comment: Twice now, I've found myself using `Tr[x!]` instead of `Tr[1^x]` to save one byte in the special case where `x` only contains zeroes and ones.

Comment: @MishaLavrov That's really neat! :)

Answer (score 9):

## Don't use `{}` if you are using `@@@`.

In some cases, you may encounter an expression like:

```
f@@@{{a,b},{c,d}}
```

It is possible to reduce bytes by writing:

```
f@@@{a|b,c|d}
```

`Alternatives` has a very low precedence, so it's generally okay to write expressions (a notable exception is pure functions; you can use it only in the leftmost element of `Alternatives`).

```
f@@@{f@a|b~g~1,#^2&@c|d@2}
```

Note that `f@@a|b|c` (instead of `f@@{a,b,c}`) does not work because `Apply` has a higher precedence than `Alternative`.

In this case, you should simply use `f@@{a,b,c}`.

Answer (score 7):

## Don't write 0-argument functions

There is no need for code like this:

```
f[]:=DoSomething[1,2]
(*...*)
f[]
(*...*)
f[]
```

You can simply use a variable with `:=` to force re-evaluation of the right-hand side:

```
f:=DoSomething[1,2]
(*...*)
f
(*...*)
f
```

This also means that you can alias any action that you perform often (even if it's just something like `n++`) to a single character at the cost of 5 bytes. So in the case of `n++` it pays back after the fourth use:

```
n++;n++;n++;n++
f:=n++;f;f;f;f
```

Answer (score 6):

### Mathematica 10 only

**Operator forms**

Mathematica 10 supports so-called "operator forms", which basically means some functions can be curried. Currying a function is to create a new function by fixing one of its operators. Say, you're using `SortBy[list, somereallylongfunction&]` a lot of different `list`s. Before, you probably would have assigned `SortBy` to `s` and the pure function to `f` so

```
s=SortBy;
f=somereallylongfunction&;
list1~s~f;
list2~s~f;
list3~s~f;
```

Now you can curry `SortBy`, which means you can now do

```
s=SortBy[somereallylongfunction&];
s@list1;
s@list2;
s@list3;
```

The same works for a lot of other functions, which take a list or function argument, including (but not limited to) `Select`, `Map`, `Nearest`, etc.

ybeltukov over on Mathematica.SE was able [to produce a complete list of these](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60045/2305):

```
{"AllTrue", "AnyTrue", "Append", "Apply", "AssociationMap", "Cases", 
 "Count", "CountDistinctBy", "CountsBy", "Delete", "DeleteCases", 
 "DeleteDuplicatesBy", "Extract", "FirstCase", "FirstPosition", 
 "FreeQ", "GroupBy", "Insert", "KeyDrop", "KeyExistsQ", "KeyMap", 
 "KeySelect", "KeySortBy", "KeyTake", "Map", "MapAt", "MapIndexed", 
 "MatchQ", "MaximalBy", "MemberQ", "Merge", "MinimalBy", "NoneTrue", 
 "Position", "Prepend", "Replace", "ReplacePart", "Scan", "Select", 
 "SelectFirst", "SortBy", "StringCases"}
```

**Composition and RightComposition**

There are new shorthands for `Composition` (`@*`) and `RightComposition` (`/*`). An obviously contrived example where these can save characters is seen in the following three equivalent lines

```
Last@Range@# & /@ Range[5]
Last@*Range /@ Range[5]
Range /* Last /@ Range[5]
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need a list of numbers sorted in reverse, don't use

```
Reverse@Sort@x
```

but

```
-Sort@-x
```

to save six bytes. Sorting by a negative value is also useful for `SortBy` scenarios:

```
Reverse@SortBy[x,Last]
SortBy[x,-Last@#&]
```

Comment: What about `-Sort@-x`?

Comment: @JungHwanMin Oh, uhhh, yeah, that's much better. :)

Answer (score 6):

## Use `Null` as an iteration variable

As has been mentioned [elsewhere](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100629/81203), missing arguments are interpreted as `Null`. Since iterators such as those used in `Sum` or `Table` localize the iteration variable, symbols such as `Null` can be used as the iteration variable, potentially saving bytes.

For example,

```
Sum[,{,10}]
```

is interpreted as `Sum[Null,{Null,10}]`, which evaluates to the expected `55`.

Answer (score 5):

## Checking if a list is sorted

This is essentially a corollary of [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/45188/8478) but this is a sufficiently common task that I think it warrants its own answer.

The naive way to check if a list is in order is to use

```
OrderedQ@a
```

We can do one byte better with

```
Sort@a==a
```

However, this doesn't work if we don't have the thing we want to check in a variable already. (We'd need something like `Sort[a=...]==a` which is unnecessarily long.) However, there's another option:

```
#<=##&@@a
```

The best thing is that this can be used to check whether the input is reverse sorted for the same byte count:

```
#>=##&@@a
```

One more byte can be saved if a) we know that the list elements are distinct and b) we know a lower bound between 0 and 9 (inclusive; or upper bound for reverse sorted order):

```
0<##&@@a
5>##&@@a
```

To see why this works, check out "Sequences of arguments" in the tip linked at the top.

Comment: Alternatively, (strict) lower-bound for reverse-sorted also work: `##>0&@@a`. Similar for upper-bound for sorted.

Comment: @user202729 Oh good point, feel free to edit (otherwise I'll try to do it on the weekend if I remember).

Answer (score 5):

## Use `%` to get a free variable

**This tip is only applicable if Mathematica's REPL environment can be assumed.** `%` is not defined when code is run as a script.

When you *can* make use of the REPL features, don't do this:

```
a=someLongExpression;some[other*a,expression@a,using^a]
```

Instead, remember that Mathematica stores the last evaluated (newline-terminated) expression in `%`:

```
someLongExpression;
some[other*%,expression@%,using^%]
```

The added newline costs a byte, but you are saving two by removing `a=`, so overall this saves one byte.

In some cases (e.g. when you want to print the value of `a` anyway), you can even leave off the `;`, saving two bytes:

```
someLongExpression
some[other*%,expression@%,using^%]
```

One or two bytes may seem fairly minor, but this is an important case, because it makes extraction of repeated expressions (which is a very common technique) much more useful when golfing:

The normal technique of extracting repeated expressions costs four bytes of overhead, which need to be saved by further uses of the expression. Here is a short table of the minimum number of uses of an expression (by length of the expression) for extraction into a named variable to save anything:

```
Length   Min. Uses
2        6
3        4
4        3
5        3
6        2
...      2
```

By using the unnamed variable, it will be possible to save a couple of bytes much more often:

```
When ; is required                        When ; can be omitted

Length   Min. Uses                        Length   Min. Uses
2        5                                2        4
3        3                                3        3
4        3                                4        2
5        2                                ...      2
...      2
```

---

I don't think `%%` or `%n` can be used for golfing, because if you don't use them at least twice, you can just put the expression right where it's needed. And if you use it twice, the additional character in the variable name cancels out the savings from omitting some `x=`.

Comment: Note that it doesn't work in script mode.

Comment: @alephalpha What is script mode?

Comment: A [mathematica script](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframLanguageScripts.html).

Comment: @alephalpha Oh right, I shut off my brain there for a second... so that would mean it can't be really be used at all, unless the REPL environment can be assumed.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica 10.2: `BlockMap` is `Partition`+`Map`

This tip could also be titled, "Read the release notes, all of them". (For reference, [here are the release notes for 10.2](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn102.html) and [here of today's 10.3 release](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn103.html).)

Anyway, even minor releases contain a wealth of new features, and one of the more useful ones (for golfing) from 10.2 is the new `BlockMap` function. It essentially combines `Partition` and `Map`, which is great for is golfers, because `Partition` is used quite often, and it's a really annoyingly long function name. The new function won't shorten `Partition` by itself, but whenever you want to map a function onto the partitions (which probably happens more often than not), you can now save a byte or two:

```
#&/@l~Partition~2
BlockMap[#&,l,2]
```

```
#&/@Partition[l,3,1]
BlockMap[#&,l,3,1]
```

The savings get even bigger when the new position of the unnamed function allows you to save yourself some parentheses:

```
#&@@(#&/@Partition[l,3,1])
#&@@BlockMap[#&,l,3,1]
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea why didn't also add `BlockApply` while they were at it...

Also note that `BlockMap` does not support the 4th parameter you can use with `Partition` to get a cyclic list:

```
Partition[Range@5, 2, 1, 1]
(* Gives {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 1}} *)
BlockMap[f, Range@5, 2, 1, 1]
(* Nope... *)
```

Comment: `MovingMap[f,list,n-1]` instead of `BlockMap[f,list,n,1]` when `n-1` is at least as short as `n`; `MovingMap` also supports padding with a constant/list (but on the left by default).

Answer (score 5):

#### Repeating a string

Instead of `StringRepeat[str,n]` use `(0Range[n]+str)<>""`. Or if `str` doesn't depend on any slot arguments, even better is `Array[str&,n]<>""` as per [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60086/30688) tip.

Comment: Corollary: instead of `StringRepeat[s,n+1]` use `Array[s&,n]<>s` (even when you already have `n+1` in a variable, too).

Comment: Better, `Table[str,n]<>""`

Answer (score 4):

You can stick an expression in `Break` which can save one or two characters. Example (*other details not golfed for clarity*):

```
result = False;
Break[]
```

can be turned into

```
Break[result = False]
```

to save one character. If the expression in question does not have lower precedence than function application you can even save another character:

```
Print@x;
Break[]
```

can be turned into

```
Break@Print@x
```

Although undocumented, the argument to `Break` seems to be returned by the surrounding loop, which can potentially lead to even more savings.

Answer (score 4):

[Here is a list with loads of operator input forms](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) which can shorten a lot of things. Some of these have been mentioned in other posts, but the list is *long* and I'm always surprised to find a few new things on there:

Comment: However, this only works when the operator uses less UTF-8 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

To remove all whitespace from a string `s`, use

```
StringSplit@s<>""
```

That is, use `StringSplit`'s default (split into non-whitespace components) and simply join them back together. The same is probably still the shortest if you want to get rid of any other character or substring:

```
s~StringSplit~"x"<>""
```

Answer (score 4):

### Alternatives to `Range`

A very common task is to apply some sort of function to all numbers from 1 to a `n` (usually given as input). There are essentially 3 ways to do this (using an unnamed identity function as an example):

```
#&/@Range@n
Array[#&,n]
Table[i,{i,n}]
```

I tend to go for the first one (for whatever reason), but this is rarely the best choice.

#### Using `Array` instead

The above example shows that using `Array` has the same byte count. However, it has the advantage that it is a single expression. In particular, if you want to further process the result with a function `f` you can use prefix notation, which saves a byte over `Range`:

```
f[#&/@Range@n]
f@Array[#&,n]
```

Furthermore, you may be able omit parentheses around your unnamed function which you might have needed with `Range`, e.g.

```
15/(#&)/@Range@n
15/Array[#&,n]
```

If you *don't* want to use it further (or with an operator which has lesser precedence), you can instead write `Array` itself in infix notation and also save a byte:

```
#&/@Range@n
#&~Array~n
```

Hence, `Array` is almost certainly better than `Range`.

#### Using `Table` instead

Now table has to make up for 3 bytes, or at least 2 when infix notation is an option:

```
#&/@Range@n
i~Table~{i,n}
```

When *not* using infix notation, `Table` might allow you to omit parentheses if your function consists of several statements:

```
(#;#)&/@Range@n
Table[i;i,{i,n}]
```

This is still longer, but gives extra savings with in the case mentioned below.

The real savings stem from the fact that `Table` gives the running variable a name should not be dismissed. Often, you'll have nested unnamed functions where you want to use the outer variable inside one of the inner functions. When that happens, `Table` is shorter than `Range`:

```
(i=#;i&[])&/@Range@n
Table[i&[],{i,n}]
i&[]~Table~{i,n}
```

Not only do you save the characters for assigning `i`, you might also be able to reduce the function to a single statement in the process, which allows you to use infix notation on top of it. For reference, `Array` is also longer in this case, but still shorter than `Range`:

```
(i=#;i&[])&~Array~n
```

#### When would you actually use `Range`?

Whenever you don't need a function call to process the values, e.g. when the mapping can be performed via a vectorised operation. For instance:

```
5#&~Array~n
5Range@n
```

```
#^2&~Array~n
Range@n^2
```

Of course, it's also shorter if you don't want to map any function at all, e.g.

```
Mean@Array[#&,n]
Mean@Range@n
```

Comment: Finally someone else who uses `f/@Range[x]` regularly...

Answer (score 4):

## Finding the smallest number that satisfies a condition

Some construct like `i=1;While[cond[i],i++]` is fine as is, but there is an alternative that is two bytes shorter:

```
1//.i_/;cond[i]:>i+1
```

The above code repeatedly replaces a number `i` with `i+1` while it meets the condition `cond[i]`. In this case, `i` starts at `1`.

Note that the default maximum number of iterations is 2^16 (= 65536). If you need more iterations than that, `While` would be better. (`MaxIterations->∞` is too long)

Answer (score 4):

## Storing functions and expressions in a variable

If your answer ends up using the same functions or expressions multiple times, you may want to consider storing them in variables.

If your expression is length `l` and you use it `n` times, it would normally use up `l * n` bytes.

However, if you store it in a length-1 variable, it would take only `3 + l + n` bytes (or `2 + l + n` bytes, if you assign the variable where you won't need `CompoundExpression (;)` or parentheses).

---

For example, let's consider a simple problem, finding [twin primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime) less than N.

One could write this 54 byte solution:

```
Select[Range@#,PrimeQ@#&&(PrimeQ[#+2]||PrimeQ[#-2])&]&
```

In this example, the function `PrimeQ` is used three times.

By assigning `PrimeQ` a variable name, the byte count can be reduced. Both of the following are 48 bytes (54 - 6 bytes):

```
Select[p=PrimeQ;Range@#,p@#&&(p[#+2]||p[#-2])&]&
Select[Range@#,(p=PrimeQ)@#&&(p[#+2]||p[#-2])&]&
```

Answer (score 4):

## Abuse [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

You can sometimes replace `If` with a logical operator.

For instance, let's say you want to make a function that checks whether a number is prime, and print `2*(number) - 1` is if it's true:

```
If[PrimeQ@#,Print[2#-1]]&
```

It's shorter if you use `&&` instead:

```
PrimeQ@#&&Print[2#-1]&
```

Even when you have multiple expressions, you still save byte(s):

```
If[PrimeQ@#,a++;Print[2#-1]]&

PrimeQ@#&&a++&&Print[2#-1]&
(* or *)
PrimeQ@#&&(a++;Print[2#-1])&
```

You can use `||` for cases when you want the condition to be `False`:

```
If[!PrimeQ@#,Print[2#-1]]&
(* or *)
If[PrimeQ@#,,Print[2#-1]]&
(* can become *)
PrimeQ@#||Print[2#-1]&
```

These tricks work because logical operators can be [short-circuited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation); the second argument and thereafter don't even need to be valid boolean expressions.

Of course, this does not work if you need the return value of `If` or when you need both truthy and falsy arguments of `If`.

Answer (score 4):

## Special characters

**This post is community wiki. Feel free to edit and add more characters that you find useful.**

Mathematica has many special [named characters](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InputAndOutputInNotebooks.html#4718). Some of them are helpful for golfing. But these characters are hard to type outside Mathematica. Some are even in the [Private Use Areas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas).

The following is a list of commonly used named characters, so that you can copy and paste.

Other than the 2-byte `°` (`\[Degree]`), all of these characters are 3 bytes long.

- ``: `\[Conjugate]`, conjugate of a complex number
- ``: `\[ConjugateTranspose]`, conjugate transpose of a matrix
- ``: `\[Cross]`, cross product
- `°`: `\[Degree]`, degree, symbol that equals `Pi/180`
- ``: `\[DirectedEdge]`, directed edges in a graph; `->` often works instead
- `∣`: `\[Divides]`, `a∣b` means `b` is divisible by `a`
- `∈`: `\[Element]`, tests membership in a domain or region (e.g. `Primes`, `Ball[]`)
- `⧦`: `\[Equivalent]`, logical equivalence
- ``: `\[Function]`, anonymous functions; in Mathematica 12.3 or newer versions you can write `|->`
- ``: `\[HermitianConjugate]`, the same as `` (`\[ConjugateTranspose]`)
- ``: `\[Implies]`, logical implication
- `∞`: `\[Infinity]`, infinity
- `⋂`: `\[Intersection]`, set intersection
- `⌈`: `\[LeftCeiling]`, `⌈x⌉` is the ceiling of `x`
- `⌊`: `\[LeftFloor]`, `⌊x⌋` is the floor of `x`
- `⊼`: `\[Nand]`, logical nand
- `⊽`: `\[Nor]`, logical nor
- ``: `\[Piecewise]`, `{{a,b}...}` is mostly equivalent to `Which[b,a,...,True,0]`
- `⌉`: `\[RightCeiling]`, `⌈x⌉` is the ceiling of `x`
- `⌋`: `\[RightFloor]`, `⌊x⌋` is the floor of `x`
- `√`: `\[Sqrt]`, square root
- ``: `\[Transpose]`, transpose of a matrix
- ``: `\[UndirectedEdge]`, undirected edges in a graph; `<->` often works instead
- `⋃`: `\[Union]`, set union
- ``: `\[VectorLess]`, `xy` means `x[[i]]<y[[i]]` for every `i`
- ``: `\[VectorLessEqual]`, `xy` means `x[[i]]<=y[[i]]` for every `i`
- ``: `\[VectorGreater]`, `xy` means `x[[i]]>y[[i]]` for every `i`
- ``: `\[VectorGreaterEqual]`, `xy` means `x[[i]]>=y[[i]]` for every `i`
- ``: `\[Xnor]`, logical xnor
- `⊻`: `\[Xor]`, logical xor

More can be found in this link: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListingOfNamedCharacters.html

Answer (score 3):

## Using `Optional (:)`

[`Optional (:)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html) can be used to expand lists in replacements, without having to define a separate rule for the expansion.

[This answer by me](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106533/60043) and [this answer by @ngenisis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106649/60043) are examples.

**Usage**

```
... /. {p___, a_: 0, b_, q___} /; cond[b] :> ...
```

The above replacement first uses the pattern `{p___, a_, b_, q___}` and finds a match such that `b` meets a certain condition.

When no such match is find, it omits `a_` and instead searches for `{p___, b_, q___}`. `a` is not included in the search and is assumed to have the value `0`.

Note that the second pattern search would only work for `b` that occurs at the beginning of the list; if a `b` value satisfying a condition is in the middle, then `{p___, a_, b_, q___}` (which has a higher precedence) would match it instead.

The replacement is equivalent to prepending a `0` when a `b` satisfying a condition occurs at the beginning of the list. (i.e. there is no need to define a separate rule, `{b_, q___} /; cond[b] :> ...`)

Answer (score 3):

### Know when (and when not) to use named pure function arguments

For code golf, pure `Function` arguments are most commonly referenced using `Slot`s; e.g. `#` for the first argument, `#2` for the second, etc. (see [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/45188/61980) for more details).

In many cases, you will want to nest `Function`s. For example, `1##&@@#&` is a `Function` which takes a list as its first argument and outputs the product of its elements. Here is that function in `TreeForm`:

[image]

Arguments passed to the top level `Function` can only fill `Slot`s and `SlotSequence`s present at the top level, which in this case means that the `SlotSequence` in the inner `Function` will not have any way of accessing arguments to the top level `Function`.

In some cases, though, you may want a `Function` nested within another `Function` to be able to reference arguments to the outer `Function`. For example, you may want something like `Array[fun,...]&`, where the function `fun` depends on an argument to the top level `Function`. For concreteness, let's say that `fun` should give the remainder of the square of its input modulo the input to the top level `Function`. One way to accomplish this is to assign the top level argument to a variable:

```
(x=#;Array[Mod[#^2,x]&,...])&
```

Wherever `x` appears in the inner `Function` `Mod[#^2,x]&`, it will refer to the first argument to the outer `Function`, whereas `#` will refer to the first argument to the inner `Function`. A better approach is to use the fact that `Function` has a two argument form where the first argument is a symbol or list of symbols that will represent named arguments to the `Function` (as opposed to unnamed `Slot`s). This ends up saving us three bytes in this case:

```
xArray[Mod[#^2,x]&,...]
```

`` is the three byte private use character `U+F4A1` representing the binary infix operator `\[Function]`. You may also use the binary form of `Function` within another `Function`:

```
Array[xMod[x^2,#],...]&
```

This is equivalent to the above. The reason is that, if you are using named arguments, then `Slot`s and `SlotSequences` are assumed to belong to next `Function` above which does not use named arguments.

Now just because we can nest `Function`s in this way, doesn't mean we always should. For example, if we wanted to pick out those elements of a list that are less than the input, we might be tempted to do something like the following:

```
Select[...,xx<#]&
```

It would actually be shorter to use `Cases` and avoid the need for a nested `Function` entirely:

```
Cases[...,x_/;x<#]&
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save a byte by working around `Prepend` or `PrependTo`:

```
l~Prepend~x
{x}~Join~l
{x,##}&@@l
```

or

```
l~PrependTo~x
l={x}~Join~l
l={x,##}&@@l
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't help for the more common `Append`, which seems to be the shortest equivalent of an `Array.push()` in other languages.

Answer (score 2):

## To achieve an ascending key-value list, use `Sort` instead of `SortBy`

For lists such as `list = {{1, "world"}, {0, "universe"}, {2, "country"}}`, the following three statements are almost equivalent.

```
SortBy[list,#[[1]]&]
list~SortBy~First
Sort@list
```

## Combine `Select` and `SortBy`

Sometimes we need to pick entries out of a larger set and sort them to find a minimum / maximum. **Under some circumstances**, two operations could be combined into one.

For example, for a minimum, the following two statements are almost equivalent.

```
SortBy[Select[l,SomeFormula==SomeConstant&],SortValue&]
SortBy[l,SortValue+99!(SomeFormula-SomeConstant)^2&]
```

and

```
SortBy[Select[l,SomeFormula!=SomeConstant&],SortValue&]
SortBy[l,SortValue+1/(SomeFormula-SomeConstant)&]
```

`1/0` is `ComplexInfinity`, which is "larger" than all real numbers.

For a key-value list, for example:

```
{SortValue,#}&/@SortBy[Select[l,SomeFormula==SomeConstant],SortValue&]
Sort[{SortValue+99!(SomeFormula-SomeConstant)^2,#})&/@l]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Flattening an `Array`

When using a multidimensional Array to compute a list of results that needs to be flattened, use a function with the attribute [`Flat`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat.html) as the fourth argument. The final result will be flattened with the specified head.

There are [23 such built-in functions](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/98vMTe12CE@Xl8/ODUnNbkk2rGkpCgzqbQEKKpc55uam5RaFFjnlpNYohYLVJNfVOJUGR0MVJKX7pOal16SARQNAPJK/v8HAA) at the time of this writing, [13 of which](https://tio.run/##DcuxCoMwFIXhhxEyuPgK1sFJq@IoRW7SgwqJhZvToUtePc34f/AH4YkgvJzk/JSA2O5706zwcNyqNCJY6JJ6LzSmSr0CS5r0DfWI0bT1g9TLfon4Kt9H2f22tdB9DLgPnkXnUsz5Dw) are also not `Orderless`. Some of the more generally applicable of those might be:

- `Or`, if there are no booleans,
- `Dot`, if there are no consecutive vectors with matching dimensions,
- `Join`, if not all elements have the same head.

In addition, `##&` will also flatten the array's elements; however, [`Sequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html)s have special behavior when used in most functions, so the Array may often need to be wrapped in `{ }`.

For comparison,

```
Array[f,dims,origin,Or]
{Array[f,dims,origin,##&]}
Join@@Array[f,dims,origin]  (*2d array only*)
Flatten@Array[f,dims,origin]

(* origin = 1 *)
Array[f,dims,1,Or]
{Array[f,dims,1,##&]}
Join@@Array[f,dims]         (*2d array only*)
Flatten[f~Array~dims]
```

Comment: If the head is not important, and the values are not Booleans, you can even use `Or`. `Array[f,dims,1,Or]` is one byte shorter than `Join@@Array[f,dims]`.

Comment: Here is an example: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119173/9288

Comment: @alephalpha I completely overlooked `Flat`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Default values

[Default values](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionalAndDefaultArguments.html) deal with missing pattern arguments in an efficient way. For example, if we want to pattern match `Exp[c_*x]` in a rule for any value of `c`, the naïve

```
Exp[x] + Exp[2x] /. {Exp[c_*x] -> f[c], Exp[x] -> f[1]}
(*    f[1] + f[2]    *)
```

uses many more bytes than if we use the default value for `c` whenever it is missing:

```
Exp[x] + Exp[2 x] /. Exp[c_.*x] -> f[c]
(*    f[1] + f[2]    *)
```

The use of a default is indicated with a dot after the pattern: `c_.`.

Default values are associated with operations: in the above example, the operation is `Times` in `c_.*x`, and a missing value for `c_` is thus taken from the default value associated with `Times`, which is 1. For `Plus`, the default value is 0:

```
Exp[x] + Exp[x + 2] /. Exp[x + c_.] -> f[c]
(*    f[0] + f[2]    *)
```

For `Power` exponents, the default is 1:

```
x + x^2 /. x^n_. -> p[n]
(*    p[1] + p[2]    *)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Solve and Reduce: automatic list of variables

When the list of variables for `Solve` and `Reduce` is omitted, they solve for all free variables in the expression(s). Examples:

```
Solve[x^4==1]
(*    {{x -> -1}, {x -> -I}, {x -> I}, {x -> 1}}    *)
(*    two bytes saved on Solve[x^4==1,x]            *)

Solve[x^2+y^2==25,Integers]
(*    {{x -> -5, y -> 0}, {x -> -4, y -> -3}, {x -> -4, y -> 3}, {x -> -3, y -> -4},
       {x -> -3, y -> 4}, {x -> 0, y -> -5}, {x -> 0, y -> 5}, {x -> 3, y -> -4},
       {x -> 3, y -> 4}, {x -> 4, y -> -3}, {x -> 4, y -> 3}, {x -> 5, y -> 0}}    *)
(*    six bytes saved on Solve[x^2+y^2==25,{x,y},Integers]                         *)

Reduce[x^2+y^2<25,Reals]
(*    -5 < y < 5 && -Sqrt[25 - y^2] < x < Sqrt[25 - y^2]    *)
(*    six bytes saved on Reduce[x^2+y^2<25,{x,y},Reals]     *)
```

Particularly `Solve` over the [`Integers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integers.html), [`NonNegativeIntegers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonNegativeIntegers.html), and [`PositiveIntegers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositiveIntegers.html) is extremely powerful for enumeration problems.

Answer (score 2):

## Use `Alphabet[]` instead of `FromLetterNumber`

The function [`Alphabet`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alphabet.html) was introduced in version 10.1, and it can reduce byte counts when you need to output lower-case/case-insensitive alphabetic strings.

```
FromLetterNumber@{8,5,12,12,15}<>"" (* 35 bytes *)
Alphabet[][[{8,5,12,12,15}]]<>""    (* 32 bytes *)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Use anonymous `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) instead of defining a single-argument function `f@n_:=...`

Sometimes an answer cannot be given as an anonymous function `...#...&` but must be defined as a regular function `f@n_:=...` because of slot collisions. Such a definition, for example

```
f@n_:=Select[Range@n,#~CoprimeQ~n&]
```

can be shortened by two bytes to an anonymous [delayed rule](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html)

```
n_:>Select[Range@n,#~CoprimeQ~n&]
```

that can be [applied](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html) to a single argument.

Comment: Is this valid? I'd consider the expression to be scored here to be `#/. pattern &`. Also, [`\[Function]`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141021/81203) does the same thing while having lower precedence and the same byte count (counting the blank).

Comment: @att I don't see why the application of an anonymous function `%[7]` (which is usually not part of the scoring) should be treated differently from the application of an anonymous delayed rule `7/.%`.

Comment: @att yes you're right about `\[Function]` (`&#xF4A1;`) having the same byte count.

Answer (score 2):

### Consider `Set` instead of `##&[]` and `##2&`

`Set` is equivalent to `(#=##2)&` - that is, `Set[a, ...]` is interpreted as `a=Sequence[...]`. This returns a `Sequence` of all arguments after the first. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z84tcSxpKQoM6m0JLU4OkMnOLWwNDUvOdUjPycllosroCgzr8QhwwGoLDoxFpWrk4QhoJOMRUgnJfb/fwA)

As a result, `Set@a` can be used like `##&[]`, but without the precedence issues.

```
a/.b_->Set@c
a/.b_->(##&[])
a/.b_->Nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

## Short forms for function-option combinations

In addition to its extensive list of operator short forms, like `/@` for `Map`, Mathematica also has at least a couple of system-defined short forms for function-option combinations

- `Log[2, n]`=> `Log2@n`
- `Log[10, n]` => `Log10@n`

I don't know of any others, so feel free to either mention them in the comments, or edit this post to add more.

Comment: `/@` for `Map`?

Comment: @att Thanks, I corrected the typo.

Answer (score 2):

## Use vector inequalities

Vector inequalities `VectorLess`, `VectorLessEqual`, `VectorGreater`, and `VectorGreaterEqual` were introduced in 12.0.

Importantly for golfing, they all have 3-byte private-use characters assigned, making them more efficient than, say, threading a comparison or using a difference.
Their respective characters are:

- ``\$\prec\$[`VectorLess`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorLess.html)
- ``\$\preceq\$[`VectorLessEqual`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorLessEqual.html)
- ``\$\succ\$[`VectorGreater`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorGreater.html)
- ``\$\succeq\$[`VectorGreaterEqual`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorGreaterEqual.html)

Note that these operators look similar to, but are distinct from the previously-existing `\[Precedes]`, `\[PrecedesEqual]`, `\[Succeeds]`, `\[SucceedsEqual]`.

---

Like scalar inequalities, the vector inequalities can take any number of arguments and can be chained (into a `` Developer`VectorInequality ``). They also thread over scalar arguments, including being able to take only scalar inputs. For the most part, they can be thought of as scalar inequalities that thread over lists and return results with `And` applied.

Some edge cases: they return unevaluated if there are non-list non-numeric elements (including e.g. \$\{0,a\}\succ\{1,0\}\$), and as far as I can tell, they always return `False` when the inputs are of different (non-scalar) dimensions.

As a small caveat, the calling syntax is different from that of regular inequalities: \$a\prec b\$ is `VectorLess[{a, b}]`, not `VectorLess[a, b]`.

Answer (score 2):

## Change the head when pattern matching subsequences

When pattern matching and replacing a short subsequence in a long list, we usually do something like:

```
{x___,a_,b_,y___}/;someCond:>{x,someExpr,y}
```

Sometimes we can change the head before pattern matching to something with the attribute [`Flat`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat.html), like `Or` or `Dot`.

For example, this simple bubble sort (38 bytes)

```
#//.{x___,a_,b_,y___}/;a>b:>{x,b,a,y}&
```

can be written as (34 bytes)

```
List@@(Or@@#//.a_||b_/;a>b:>b||a)&
```

or (also 34 bytes)

```
List@@(Dot@@#//.a_ .b_/;a>b:>b.a)&
```

Don't forget to add a space between `_` and `.` when you are using `Dot`, otherwise Mathematica would parse it as an [Optional pattern](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html).

But this only works when the input and output both have at least 2 elements.

Answer (score 2):

### Finding the product of a list post-processing

A typical golfy way to find the product of a list of values is by applying `1##&`:

```
1##&@@expr
```

Sometimes, we may need to apply a pure function on all of the values first. In such cases, it's often shorter to wrap the result of that preprocessing in a `List` and use `Dot` instead:

```
Product[bodi,{i,expr}]
1##&@@(body&/@expr)
{body}&/@Dot@@expr
```

If the list has known arguments:

```
1##&@@(body&/@{a,b,c})
{body}&/@Dot[a,b,c]
{body}&/@(a.b.c)

(g=body&)[a]g[b]g@c
#@a#@b#@c&[body&]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Localizing temporary expressions

Some function submissions may involve defining a local expression which should not persist between different calls.
For example, [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241622) uses expressions with head `g` to build paths, (re-)defining `g[#]` for each value in the input list. These paths should be reset on each new input.

The canonical way to do this is with `Module[{g},...]`/`Block[{g},...]`, control structures which localize variables so that definitions made inside them will not propagate outside. For golfing, most of the time we can save a few bytes over these by using `Clear@g` instead, though it may not play nicely with recursion.

In some cases, we can do even better by setting `g=h@#` (or `g=h@##`). However, as subsequent definitions will not be cleared on repeated function calls, care needs to be taken to ensure that the function handles such repeated calls on the same input properly (for example, [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/240467/4) would fail to do so). Where applicable, though, it not only saves bytes, but also has no issues with recursion.

Comparing these strategies for the linked example:

```
{g}~Module~Depth[i=0;(g@i=g[++i+#]!)&/@#]-3&
{g}~Block~Depth[i=0;(g@i=g[++i+#]!)&/@#]-3&
Depth[i=0Clear@g;(g@i=g[++i+#]!)&/@#]-3&
Depth[g=h@#;i=0;(g@i=g[++i+#]!)&/@#]-3&
```

When using two or more such local expressions, `Block` or `Clear` are the best bet:

```
Module[{a,b},...]
Block[{a,b},...]
(a~Clear~b;...)
(a=p@#;b=q@#;...)
```

Answer (score 2):

### `PreIncrement`/`PreDecrement` can save parentheses

When called on a non-atomic, non-list argument, `PreIncrement`/`PreDecrement` return the incremented/decremented value, albeit with an error message. This can save bytes on increments/decrements that would otherwise require parentheses.

For example, to generate the golden ratio:

```
(√5+1)/2
√5/2+1/2
++√5/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/1/jUccsU21DTX0jBX39gKLMvBIukIi@kbYhkpC2NkRQQQEm9P8/AA)

Prepending `+` to an atom or list allows `++`/`--` to be used on them as well, thanks to the `HoldFirst` attribute. `-` works as well if the target is not a literal number. In my experience, this is most often useful when used with `#`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/19bW9uAk5NTXz@gKDOvhEtbW7faUMegFiGiq4suoqxrZxSnq6utrFbnWFSUWFlnaACT@/8fAA)

This is also only possible because, for whatever reason, `+++x` is interpreted as `++ +x` instead of `+ ++x`.

Answer (score 1):

## Golfing nested pure functions

This is my first post here, would be grateful for comments and corrections!

Let there is some pure function as criterion in `Select`, `MaximalBy` etc.:

```
Select[list, crit[#]&]
```

And inside this criterion we need some calculations with `Map`, `Table` etc which may also be presented as pure function:

```
crit[arr_, x_] := Table[f[x, e], {e, arr}]
```

eq to

```
crit[arr_, x_] := f[x, #]&/@arr
```

Sometimes the whole construction may be effectively golfed with `Fold`, `Outer` etc.
But sometimes not, and we have troubles with correctly using slots in nested pure functions:

```
Select[ list, (f[#!!wrong!!, #]&/@arr)& ]
```

Possible golfing solution (without Table or Map) may be like this (thanks to @att):

```
Select[list, (x=#;f[x,#]&/@arr)&]
```

or

```
Select[list, x|->f[x,#]&/@arr]
```

or sometimes

```
(f[x,#]&/@arr)/.x->#&
```

Comment: usually better `(x=#;f[x,#]&/@arr)&` or `x|->f[x,#]&/@arr`

Answer (score 1):

## Check for duplicates

`UnsameQ@@` is 6 bytes shorter than `DuplicateFreeQ@`.
But if performance matters, `UnsameQ` is over 1000 times slower.