# Decompose binary into alternating subsequences

Tags: code-golf, sequence, base-conversion, binary, subsequence

**This was inspired by *Problem 13 - Non-Repeating Binary* of [HP CodeWars' recent competition.](http://www.hpcodewars.org/past/cw18/problems/HPCodeWars2015ProblemSet.pdf)**

Let's take a random decimal number, say

```
727429805944311
```

and look at its binary representation:

```
10100101011001011111110011001011101010110111110111
```

Now split that binary representation into subsequences where the digits `0` and `1` alternate.

```
1010 010101 10 0101 1 1 1 1 1 10 01 10 0101 1 1010101 101 1 1 1 101 1 1
```

And convert each subsequence back into decimal.

```
10 21 2 5 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 5 1 85 5 1 1 1 5 1 1
```

### The Task

Take a single, positive integer as input and output the sequence of positive integers obtained by the above process.

### Details

- Input and output must be in decimal or unary.
- Numbers in the output must be separated in a sensible, human-readable fashion, and they must be in decimal or unary. No restriction on white space. Valid output styles: `[1,2,3]`, `1 2 3`, `1\n2\n3` where `\n` are literal newlines, etc.

### Test cases

```
 Input | Output
     0 | 0
     1 | 1
     2 | 2
     3 | 1 1
     4 | 2 0
     5 | 5
     6 | 1 2
     7 | 1 1 1
     8 | 2 0 0
     9 | 2 1
    10 | 10
    50 | 1 2 2
   100 | 1 2 2 0
  1000 | 1 1 1 1 10 0 0
 10000 | 2 1 1 2 0 2 0 0 0
 12914 | 1 2 2 1 1 2 2
371017 | 5 42 10 2 1
```

Additional note: all numbers in the output should be of the form `(2^k-1)/3` or `2*(2^k-1)/3`. That is, `0 1 2 5 10 21, 42, 85, 170, ...`, which is [A000975](http://oeis.org/A000975) in the OEIS.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: Hmmm......no, I don't think that's within the spirit of the challenge.

Comment: Ok.  `|tac` will remain in my answer then :)

Comment: is it reversible ? I think so ...

Answer (score 11):

## Pyth, <s>17</s> 16 bytes

*1 byte thanks to Jakube*

```
iR2cJ.BQx1qVJ+dJ
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=iR2cJ.BQx1qVJ%2BdJ&input=727429805944311&debug=0)

A nice, clever solution. Uses some lesser known features of Pyth, like `x<int><list>` and `c<str><list>`.

```
iR2cJ.BQx1qVJ+dJ
                    Q = eval(input())
    J.BQ            Store in J the input in binary.
          qV        Vectorize equality function over
            J+dJ    J and J with a leading dummy char, to get the offset right.
                    This calculates whether each element matches its successor.
        x1          Find all of the indexes of 1 (True) in this list.
   cJ                Chop J at those locations.
iR2                  Convert from binary back to base ten and output.
```

Comment: If you replace `tJ` by `+dJ` you can remove `hM`.

Comment: @Jakube Nice one!

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, 47 bytes

```
#+##&~Fold~#&/@#~IntegerDigits~2~Split~Unequal&
```

Ungolfed:

```
FromDigits[#,2]&/@Split[IntegerDigits[#,2],Unequal]&
```

`Split[list,f]` splits a list into multiple lists, breaking at the position between `a` and `b` iff `f[a,b]` does not return `True`.

`FromDigits[n,2] => Fold[#+##&,n]` is a neat [tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12922/30688) from alephalpha.

Answer (score 7):

## Python, 86 bytes

Since I got horribly outgolfed in Pyth, lets just do it in Python again.

```python
import re
lambda n:[int(s,2)for s in re.sub("(?<=(.))(?=\\1)"," ",bin(n)[2:]).split()]
```

[Try it here!](https://repl.it/BvJY)

### Explanation

We start with converting the input number `n` into a binary string. `bin(n)[2:]` takes care of that. We need to discard the first 2 chars of this string since `bin()` returns the string in the format `0b10101`.
Next we need to identify the borders of the subsequences. This can be done with the regex `(?<=(.))(?=\1)` which matches the zero-length positions in the string which have the same number to the left and right.
The obvious way to get a list of all subsequences would be to use `re.split()` which splits a string on a certain regex. Unfortunately this function does not work for zero-length matches. But luckily `re.sub()` does, so we just replace those zero-length matches with spaces and split the string on those after that.
Then we just have to parse each of those subsequences back into a decimal number with `int(s,2)` and are done.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6) 58 <s>62 63</s>

**Edit** 1 byte saved thx @ETHproductions

**Edit** 4 bytes saved thx @Neil

```js
x=>x.toString(2).replace(/((.)(?!\2))*./g,x=>'0b'+x-0+' ')
```

```js
f=x=>x.toString(2).replace(/((.)(?!\2))*./g,x=>'0b'+x-0+' ')

 
console.log=x=>O.textContent+=x+'\n'

;[
[     0,'0'],
[     1,'1'],
[     2,'2'],
[     3,'1 1'],
[     4,'2 0'],
[     5,'5'],
[     6,'1 2'],
[     7,'1 1 1'],
[     8,'2 0 0'],
[     9,'2 1'],
[    10,'10'],
[    50,'1 2 2'],
[   100,'1 2 2 0'],
[  1000,'1 1 1 1 10 0 0'],
[ 10000,'2 1 1 2 0 2 0 0 0'],
[ 12914,'1 2 2 1 1 2 2'],
[371017,'5 42 10 2 1']
].forEach(t=>{
  var i=t[0],k=t[1],r=f(i)
  console.log(i+' -> '+r+(r.trim()==k.trim() ? ' ok':'ko (should be '+k+')'))
})
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: Could you save two bytes with the regex `/(01)*0?|(10)*1?/g`, or would that mess something up??

Comment: Also, I think you could do `x=>'0b'+x-0+' '` to save a byte.

Comment: @ETHproductions I tried the shorter regexp, no good :(. Thx for the other hint

Comment: The Leadboard says you have a 1 byte answer. I assume it's because you have the corrected number (62) before the old number (63) instead of after.

Comment: I think the regex `/((.)(?!\2))*./g` saves you a cool 4 bytes.

Comment: @KyleKanos The leadboard (uh what leadbord?) is wrong, it's a pity but not my problem. We have tons of questions with leadboard scripts that do works correctly. http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8428/21348

Comment: @Neil wow! I'll use that regex when I will able to understand it (give me a couple years) (just kidding)

Comment: There's not much to understand; all it does is use negative lookahead to ensure that it never matches a double character.

Comment: @Neil thanks I was wondering about "why the 3rd capture group" but I found it's not a capture group at all, it's part of the sintax for negative look ahead

Comment: please @shaggy I like the best score at left position

Comment: That's causing it to show up on the leaderboard as just 1 byte, though.

Comment: @Shaggy the leaderboard is poorly coded then, see my previous comment (and again: what leaderboard? is it a site extension? we have many challenges that include a leaderboard that has not this problem) (see also https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8428/avoid-useless-edit-about-byte-count)

Answer (score 4):

## Jelly, 12 bytes

```
BI¬-ẋż@BFṣ-Ḅ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=QknCrC3huovFvEBCRuG5oy3huIQ&input=&args=NzI3NDI5ODA1OTQ0MzEx) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=QknCrC3huovFvEBCRuG5oy3huIQKw4figqzFkuG5mOKCrGrigbc&input=&args=MCwgMSwgMiwgMywgNCwgNSwgNiwgNywgOCwgOSwgMTAsIDUwLCAxMDAsIDEwMDAsIDEwMDAwLCAxMjkxNCwgMzcxMDE3).

#### How it works

```
BI¬-ẋż@BFṣ-Ḅ  Main link. Argument: n

B             Convert n to base 2.
 I            Compute the increments, i.e., the differences of consecutive digits.
  ¬           Apply logical NOT.
   -ẋ         Repeat -1 that many times, for the logical NOT of each difference.
              [0, 0] / [1, 1] ->   0    -> 1 -> [-1]
              [0, 1] / [1, 0] -> 1 / -1 -> 0 -> []
       B      Yield n in base 2.
     ż@       Zip the result to the right with the result to the left.
        F     Flatten the resulting list of pairs.
         ṣ-   Split at occurrences of -1.
           Ḅ  Convert each chunk from base 2 to integer.
```

Comment: Surely 12 characters but 20 bytes.   Or are you using a system with CHAR_BIT >> 8?

Comment: @JamesYoungman Jelly doesn't use UTF-8 by default. In fact, it has [its own code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/blob/master/docs/code-page.md) that encodes each of the 256 characters it understands as a single byte each.

Answer (score 4):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 51

```bash
dc -e2o?p|sed -r ':;s/(.)\1/\1 \1/;t'|dc -e2i?f|tac
```

Input taken from STDIN.

- `dc -e2o?p` reads input integer from STDIN and outputs a base 2 string
- `sed -r ':;s/(.)\1/\1 \1/;t'` splits the base 2 string with a space everywhere there are same consecutive digits
- `dc -e2i?f` reads the split binary in one go, putting the each part on the stack, then `f` dumps the whole `dc` stack (output numbers in reverse order) ...
- ... which is corrected by `tac`.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
&Qu?q%G2H&
GH+yGHjQ2Z
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%26Qu%3Fq%25G2H%26%0AGH%2ByGHjQ2Z&input=371017&debug=0)

Really a tedious task in Pyth.

#### Explanation:

```
&Qu?q%G2H&\nGH+yGHjQ2Z   implicit: Q = input number
                  jQ2    convert Q to base 2
  u               jQ2Z   reduce ^: for each digit H update the variable G=0:
   ?q%G2H                   if G%2 == H:
          \nG                  print G
         &   H                 then update G with H
              +yGH           else: update G with 2*G+H
  u                      print the last G also
&Q                       handle Q=0 special: only print 0 once
```

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 26 bytes

```
iR2c:.BQ"(?<=(.))(?=\\1)"d
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=iR2c%3A.BQ%22%28%3F%3C%3D%28.%29%29%28%3F%3D%5C%5C1%29%22d&input=727429805944311&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A50%0A100%0A1000%0A10000%0A12914%0A371017&debug=0)

### Explanation

```
iR2c:.BQ"(?<=(.))(?=\\1)"d   # Q = input number

     .BQ                     # Convert input to binary
    :   "(?<=(.))(?=\\1)"d   # insert a whitespace between the subsequences
   c                         # split string on whitespaces
iR2                          # convert each subsequence into decimal
```

Since Python's split() function doesn't split on zero-length matches, I have to replace those matches with a space and split the result on that.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

Code:

```
b2FNð«N«Dð-s:}ð¡)C
```

Explanation:

```
b                   # Convert input to binary
 2F          }      # Do the following twice ( with N as range variable)
   Nð«N«            #    N + space + N
        D           #    Duplicate this
         ð-         #    Delete spaces from the duplicate string
           s        #    Swap the top two elements
            :       #    Replace the first string with the second
              ð¡    # Split on spaces
                )   # Wrap into an array
                 C  # Convert all element back to decimal
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=YjJGTsOwwqtOwqtEw7Atczp9w7DCoSlD&input=MzcxMDE3)

Uses **CP-1252** encoding.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
YBTyd~Thhfd1wY{ZB
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=WUJUeWR-VGhoZmQxd1l7WkI&input=MzcxMDE3)

```
YB      % input number. Convert to binary string
T       % push true value
y       % duplicate binary string and push it at the top of the stack
d~      % true for each value that equals the previous one
T       % push true value
hh      % concatenate: true, indices, true
f       % find indices of true values
d       % consecutive differences: lenghts of alternating sequences
1wY{    % split binary string according to those lengths
ZB      % convert each substring into decimal number
```

Answer (score 3):

### zsh, <s>67</s> <s>63</s> 55 bytes

```
for i in `grep -oP '1?(01)*0?'<<<$[[##2]$1]`;<<<$[2#$i]
```

I don't know why, but this doesn't work in Bash.

Thanks to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) for 8 bytes!

Comment: It's the `for` syntax. ...Wait, no `for`s?

Comment: Bash's arithmetic expansion doesn't let you specify an output base. To get rid of the xargs, you could use ``for i in `grep -oP '1?(01)*0?'<<<$[[##2]$1]`;<<<$[2#$i]``.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (APL)](https://dyalog.com), <s>21</s> 25 bytes

Now handles 0 as well.

```
{0::0⋄2⊥¨⍵⊂⍨1,2=/⍵}2⊥⍣¯1⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3yU1OT@3IL849VHbhGoDKyuDR90tRo@6lh5a8ah366Oupke9Kwx1jGz1gbxakPij3sWH1hs@6lqEpFUBBAy4UPmGaHwjNL4xGt8EjW@KxjdD45uj8S3Q@JaofEM095mi8g0NUPhALjIfxEXhG1kamgAA)

`2⊥⍣¯1⊢` convert to base-2, using as many bits as needed (lit. inverse from-base-2 conversion)

`{`…`}` apply the following anonymous function

`0::` if any error happens:

`0` return 0

`⋄` now try:

`2=/⍵` pairwise equality of the argument (will fail one 0's length-0 binary representation)

`1,` prepend 1

`⍵⊂⍨` use that to partition the argument (begins new section on each 1)

`2⊥¨` convert each from base-2

Comment: `⊂` is really useful here. I should add that to Jelly.

Comment: @Dennis Be aware of the two versions of `R←X⊂Y`: With `⎕ML<3` (i.e. Dyalog style), a new partition is started in the result corresponding to each 1 in X up to the position before the next 1 in X (or the last element of X) become the successive items of R. With `⎕ML=3` (i.e. IBM style), a new partition is started in the result whenever the corresponding element in X is greater than the previous one. Items in Y corresponding to 0s in X are not included in the result. So `⎕ML←1 ⋄ 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 ⊂ ⍳7` is equivalent to `⎕ML←3` ⋄ 4 3 2 4 4 5 7 ⊂ ⍳7`

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, <s>171</s> <s>168</s> <s>162</s> <s>160</s> <s>158</s> <s>121</s> <s>120</s> <s>131</s> <s>124</s> <s>118</s> <s>116</s> <s>113</s> 112 bytes

```
function d($i){for(;$d<$l=strlen($b=decbin($i));){$c.=$u=$b[$d];echo$u==$b[++$d]||$d==$l?bindec($c).$c=" ":"";}}
```

**Exploded view**

```
function d($i) {
  for ( ; $d < $l = strlen($b = decbin($i)); ) {
    $c .= $u = $b[$d];
    echo $u == $b[++$d] || $d == $l ? bindec($c) . $c = " "
                                    : "";
  }
}
```

Use `d(int)` and you're off, output is an `echo`ed string of `int`s separated by a space.

**Edits:**
**-3:** Moved `$b` definition into `strlen()` call.
**-6:** Removed `$c` instantiation.
**-2:** **Finally** fixed the concatenation issue.
**-2:** No brackets for single-line `for()`.
**-37:** **Total overhaul.**  Going with `Array` chunklets instead of repeated `Array`->`String`->`Array` calls.
**-1:** Sneaky `$c` reset.
**+11:** **Bugfix.** Was missing final chunk. No more.
**-7:** Don't need to instantiate `$d` at all? Nice.
**-6:** `return`->`echo`.
**-2:** Crunching `$c`.
**-3:** Ternary, my first love.
**-1:** Sneaky sneaky `$u`.

Comment: I think you can save 2 bytes: `function d($i){for(;$d<$l=strlen($b=decbin($i));print$u==$b[++$d]||$d==$l?bindec($c).$c=" ":"")$c.=$u=$b[$d];}`.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>127</s> 119 bytes

```java
l->new java.util.ArrayList<Long>(){{for(String s:l.toBinaryString(l).split("(?<=(.))(?=\\1)"))add(l.parseLong(s,2));}};
```

There's probably a better regular expression out there to split the string on. I'm not proficient at regex, but I'll keep experimenting.

-8 bytes thanks to @FryAmTheEggman

Answer (score 2):

### Convex 0.2+, 25 bytes

Convex is a new language that I am developing that is heavily based on CJam and Golfscript. The interpreter and IDE can be found [here](https://github.com/GamrCorps/Convex). Input is an integer into the command line arguments. This uses the **CP-1252** encoding.

```
2bs®(?<=(.))(?=\\1)"ö2fbp
```

Explanation:

```
2bs                         Convert to binary string
   ®(?<=(.))(?=\\1)"        Regex literal
                    ö       Split string on regex
                     2fb    Convert each split string into decimal integer
                        p   Print resulting array
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 7 bytes

```
¤ò¥ mn2
```

[Test it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=pPKlIG1uMg==&input=NzI3NDI5ODA1OTQ0MzEx)

---

### Explanation

```
¤ò¥ mn2
           :Implicit input of integer U.
¤          :Convert to binary string.
 ò¥        :Split to an array by checking for equality.
    m      :Map over array.
     n2    :Convert to base-10 integer.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <s>147</s>, 145 bytes

```
x%[]=[x]
x%(y:z)|or.(zipWith(==)<*>tail)$y:x=x:[]%(y:z)|1<2=(y:x)%z
b x|x<2=[x]|1<2=b(div x 2)++[mod x 2]
map(sum.zipWith((*).(2^))[0..]).([]%).b
```

`map(sum.zipWith((*).(2^))[0..]).([]%).b` is an unnamed function that computes the list.

Less golfed:

```
alternating :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
alternating = or . (zipWith (==) <*> tail)

-- (%) is the partitioning function
(%) :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
x % [] = [x]

x % (y:z) | alternating (y : x) = x : [] % (y:z)
          | otherwise = (y : x) % z

bits :: Integral t => t -> [t]
bits x | x < 2     = [x] 
       | otherwise = bits (div x 2) ++ [mod x 2]

unBits :: Num c => [c] -> c
unBits = sum . zipWith ((*) . (2^)) [0..]

f :: Integer -> [Integer]
f = map unBits . ([]%) . bits
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 115 bytes

```
def f(s):
 s=bin(s);r=[s[2]]
 for i in s[3:]:
  if i==r[-1][-1]:r+=[i]
  else:r[-1]+=i
 return[int(x,2)for x in r]
```

### Explanation

```
def f(s):
 s=bin(s)                   # convert input in binary
 r=[s[2]]                   # initialize the result with the first char after the 'b' in binary string
 for i in s[3:]:            # loop on other element
  if i==r[-1][-1]:          # if the last element of the last string equal the current element 
   r+=[i]                   # we add the current element in a new string
  else:
   r[-1]+=i                 # we add the current element to the last sting
 return[int(x,2)for x in r] # convert binary string in integer
```

### Results

```
>>> [print(i,f(i)) for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 50, 100, 1000, 10000, 12914, 371017]]
0 [0]
1 [1]
2 [2]
3 [1, 1]
4 [2, 0]
5 [5]
6 [1, 2]
7 [1, 1, 1]
8 [2, 0, 0]
9 [2, 1]
10 [10]
50 [1, 2, 2]
100 [1, 2, 2, 0]
1000 [1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0]
10000 [2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
12914 [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]
371017 [5, 42, 10, 2, 1]
```

**previous solution (118 bytes)**

```
def f(s):
 s=bin(s);r=s[2]
 for i in s[3:]:
  if i==r[-1]:r+='a'+i
  else:r+=i
 return[int(x,2)for x in r.split('a')]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 53 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Run with the number on STDIN

```
perl -p alterbits.pl <<< 371017
```

`alterbits.pl`:

```
$_=sprintf"0b%b",$_;s/(.)\K(?=\1)/ 0b/g;s/\S+/$&/eeg
```

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell, 103 bytes

```
[regex]::Matches([convert]::ToString($args[0],2),"(01)+0?|(10)+1?|.").Value|%{[convert]::toint32($_,2)}
```

Since I'm horrible at regex, I'm using the same expression as [edc65's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75344/42963).

Absolutely destroyed by the lengthy .NET calls to do conversion to/from binary, and the .NET call to get the regex matches. Otherwise pretty straightforward. Takes the input `$args[0]`, `convert`s it to binary, feeds it into `Matches`, takes the resultant `.Value`s, pipes them through a loop `|%{...}` and `convert`s those values back to `int`. Output is left on the pipeline and implicitly printed with newlines.

---

#### For extra credit - a (mostly) non-regex version at 126 bytes

```
$l,$r=[char[]][convert]::ToString($args[0],2);$l+-join($r|%{(" $_",$_)[$l-bxor$_];$l=$_})-split' '|%{[convert]::toint32($_,2)}
```

We again take input `$args[0]` and `convert` it to binary. We re-cast as a char-array, storing the first character in `$l` and the remaining characters in `$r`. We then send `$r` through a loop `|%{...}` where every iteration we select from either the character prepended with a space or just the character, depending upon the result of a binary xor with `$l`, and then set `$l` equal to the character. This effectively ensures that if we have the same character twice in a row, we prepend a space between them.

The output of the loop is `-join`ed together and appended to the first character `$l`, then `-split` on spaces (which is technically a regex, but I'm not going to count it). We then do the same loop as the regex answer to `convert` and output integers.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 345 bytes

```
package com.ji.golf;
import java.util.regex.*;
public class Decompose {
  public static String decompose(long l) {
    String o="";
    String s=Long.toBinaryString(l);
    Matcher m=Pattern.compile("(01)+(0)?|(10)+(1)?|(1)|(0)").matcher(s);
    while(m.find()){String c=s.substring(m.start(),m.end());o+=Integer.parseInt(c, 2)+" ";}
    return o;
  }
}
```

### Test

```
package com.ji.golf;
public class DecompseTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] inOut = new String[]{
        "0,0",
        "1,1",
        "2,2",
        "3,1 1",
        "4,2 0",
        "5,5",
        "6,1 2",
        "7,1 1 1",
        "8,2 0 0",
        "9,2 1",
        "10,10",
        "50,1 2 2",
        "100,1 2 2 0",
        "1000,1 1 1 1 10 0 0",
        "10000,2 1 1 2 0 2 0 0 0",
        "12914,1 2 2 1 1 2 2",
        "371017,5 42 10 2 1"
    };
    for (String s : inOut) {
      String[] io = s.split(",");
      String result = Decompose.decompose(Long.parseLong(io[0]));
      System.out.println("in: " + io[0] + ", reusult: [" +  result.trim() + "], validates? " + result.trim().equals(io[1].trim()));
    }
  }
}
```

### Output

```
in: 0, reusult: [0], validates? true
in: 1, reusult: [1], validates? true
in: 2, reusult: [2], validates? true
in: 3, reusult: [1 1], validates? true
in: 4, reusult: [2 0], validates? true
in: 5, reusult: [5], validates? true
in: 6, reusult: [1 2], validates? true
in: 7, reusult: [1 1 1], validates? true
in: 8, reusult: [2 0 0], validates? true
in: 9, reusult: [2 1], validates? true
in: 10, reusult: [10], validates? true
in: 50, reusult: [1 2 2], validates? true
in: 100, reusult: [1 2 2 0], validates? true
in: 1000, reusult: [1 1 1 1 10 0 0], validates? true
in: 10000, reusult: [2 1 1 2 0 2 0 0 0], validates? true
in: 12914, reusult: [1 2 2 1 1 2 2], validates? true
in: 371017, reusult: [5 42 10 2 1], validates? true
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! Since this is a [tag:code-golf] competition, you should make your code as short as possible. [Here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6671/20469) are some tips for golfing in Java. You can start by defining your function without the boilerplate `package` and `class`, and removing unnecessary whitespace. Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, <s>70</s> 57 bytes

```
n->map(i->parse(Int,i,2),split(bin(n),r"(?<=(.))(?=\1)"))
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts an integer and returns an integer array. To call it, assign it to a variable.

The approach here is similar to DenkerAffe's nice Python [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75342/20469). We get the binary representation of `n` using `bin(n)`, and split the resulting string at all matches of the regular expression `(?<=(.))(?=\1)`. It's actually a zero-length match; `(?<=(.))` is a positive lookbehind that finds any single character, and `(?=\1)` is a positive lookahead that finds the matched character in the lookbehind. This locates the places where a number is followed by itself in the binary representation. Just `parse` each as an integer in base 2 using `map` and voila!

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>137</s> 129 bytes

```
main(){unsigned long a,b=scanf("%lu",&a),c=!!a;while(a>=b*2)b*=2;while(b)b/=2,c=c*(~(a^a/2)&b|!b?!printf("%lu\n",c):2)+!!(a&b);}
```

Input and output are on the standard streams.

Comment: I don't think you need the `puts`, even though it would be unpleasant to use, the spec doesn't require a trailing newline.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I'd rather not generate an incomplete last line. But for the cost of one byte (still a net reduction) I can change the separator from space to newline.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 16 bytes

```
#:#.;.1~1,2=/\#:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JchLCoAgFEbhuav4QYiCMK@PTMVW0iySaNIO2vpNanC@wbmYK0qCTFJlRQ@NpkybTEIc@3mjz3XoVmgQDCwcPGYELIggDd@@/vppmkgONpCmwPwC)

### Explanation

```
#:#.;.1~1,2=/\#:  Input: integer n
              #:  Convert from decimal to list of binary digits
          2  \    For each overlapping sublist of size 2
           =/       Reduce using equals
        1,        Prepend 1
#:                Binary digits
    ;.1~          Partition those binary digits at the 1s in the previous list
  #.                Convert each partition from a list of binary digits to decimal
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
BI¬0;œṗBḄ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS8A0P9qZWxsef//QknCrDA7xZPhuZdC4biE/8OHxZLhuZj//zcyNzQyOTgwNTk0NDMxMQ)

Answer (score 1):

## q/kdb+, 52 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{2 sv'cut[0,(&)(~)differ a]a:(63^(*)(&)a)_a:0b vs x}
```

**Examples:**

```
q){2 sv'cut[0,(&)(~)differ a]a:(63^(*)(&)a)_a:0b vs x}0
,0
q){2 sv'cut[0,(&)(~)differ a]a:(63^(*)(&)a)_a:0b vs x}1
,1
q){2 sv'cut[0,(&)(~)differ a]a:(63^(*)(&)a)_a:0b vs x}3
1 1
q){2 sv'cut[0,(&)(~)differ a]a:(63^(*)(&)a)_a:0b vs x}8
2 0 0
q){2 sv'cut[0,(&)(~)differ a]a:(63^(*)(&)a)_a:0b vs x}10000
2 1 1 2 0 2 0 0 0
q){2 sv'cut[0,(&)(~)differ a]a:(63^(*)(&)a)_a:0b vs x}12914
1 2 2 1 1 2 2
q){2 sv'cut[0,(&)(~)differ a]a:(63^(*)(&)a)_a:0b vs x}371017
5 42 10 2 1
q){2 sv'cut[0,(&)(~)differ a]a:(63^(*)(&)a)_a:0b vs x}727429805944311
10 21 2 5 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 5 1 85 5 1 1 1 5 1 1
```

**Explanation:**

`q` is interpreted right-to-left.

Cast input to binary, trim off leading zeros, find indices where different, invert to get indices where the same, split list on these indices, convert back to base-10. Looks a little heavy compared to the APL solution though...

```
{2 sv'cut[0,where not differ a]a:(63^first where a)_a:0b vs x} / ungolfed solution
{                                                            } / lambda function
      cut[                    ]                                / cut a list at indices, cut[indices]list
                                                      0b vs x  / converts to 64bit binary representation
                                                    a:         / save as a
                                                   _           / drop 'n' elements from a
                                 (                )            / evaluate this
                                     first where a             / returns first occurance of true in list a
                                  63^                          / fill result with 63 if null (to handle input of 0)
                               a:                              / save as a, we've stripped off all the left-most 0s
                      differ a                                 / whether or not item in list a is different to previous
                  not                                          / the inversion of this result
            where                                              / these are the points where we have 00 or 11
          0,                                                   / add the first index too!
  2 sv'                                                        / 2 sv converts binary back to base-10, ' for each list
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 98 bytes

```php
function($x){foreach(str_split(decbin($x))as$c)$o[$p+=$c==$d].=$d=$c;return array_map(bindec,$o);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVFPa4MwFD@bT/EoOSiTNUl1VpzsNNhhsN67Is7G6dhMSFLYKP3sLkZTSiB57/cvj0R2cnx8kp1EiCslVKW4FMr0w2dIogIhbLg2GkrYoyBjWcLyLUnzJNlQGsN6DZQAo8AgBXpdDDyyTa@EO1FAnIugYLGjgLmCoWAzIxOWzNikS12ZouBhoa0y88pJu/XaSZ0vjcUpWQa0GcR7JzclN60bhVyRZZE5bSKIT3R6Ml/kSJbT5CaI@vxNRgmdR0whYe6J7ECH6TXbcmxPQ2N6MYT4Nzq3QvG66UJtVKXld2/CI28@ekdGtcZNhMUey7sSN2WJj4d7u9m6UNyc1AC1UvVf9VPL0HqsM8YiKi5jgXwuLP9Xa1tBBGcEwJtO2C6G1btZxfClxVDxoRFHbuVtOAujGHYvu@r57bVAl/Ef)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
mḋġ≠ḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/fhju4jCx91LgDS////NzcyNzGytDAwtTQxMTY0BAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>49</s> 48 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Sʨɠɠan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/s%ca%a8%c9%a0%c9%a0an)

Uses the regexp from [edc65’s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75344/11261).

```ruby
->n{("%b"%n).scan(/((.)(?!\2))*./){p $&.to_i 2}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3DXTt8qo1lFSTlFTzNPWKkxPzNPQ1NPQ0NewVY4w0NbX09DWrCxRU1PRK8uMzFYxqayH6thQouEWbG5mbGFlaGJhampgYGxrGQqQWLIDQAA)

Comment: `n.to_s(2)` => `("%b"%n)` for -1

Comment: @Sʨɠɠan Of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 147

```
$b=decbin($argv[1]);$a=[$t=$b[0]];$k=0;for($i=1;$i<strlen($b);$i++){$v=$b[$i];if($v==$t)$k++;$t=$v;$a[$k].=$v;}foreach($a as$c)echo bindec($c).' ';
```

Need to put extra space at last of output as their are no restriction. Notices are displayed for short coding.

Ungolfed version

```
$n=$argv[1];
$b=decbin($n);
$l=strlen($b);
$t=$b[0];
$a=[0=>$t];$k=0;
for($i=1;$i<$l;$i++){
    $v=$b[$i];
    if($v==$t){
        $k++;
    }
    $t=$v;$a[$k].=$v;    
}
foreach($a as $c){
    echo bindec($c).' ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Retina, 60

```
+`(1+)\1
$1a
a1
1
(?<=(.))(?=\1)
¶
+`1(a*)\b
a$.1$*1;
a

;
1
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=K2AoMSspXDEKJDFhCmExCjEKKD88PSguKSkoPz1cMSkKwrYKK2AxKGEqKVxiCmEkLjEkKjE7CmEKCjsKMQ&input=MTExMTExMTE) Or try a slightly modified version for [all test cases](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XGQrCiQqCitgKDErKVwxCiQxYQphMQoxCig_PD0oLikpKD89XDEpCsK2CitgMShhKilcYgphJC4xJCoxOwphCgptYF47KiQKJC4w&input=MAotKy0rLSstKy0KMQotKy0rLSstKy0KMgotKy0rLSstKy0KMwotKy0rLSstKy0KNAotKy0rLSstKy0KNQotKy0rLSstKy0KNgotKy0rLSstKy0KNwotKy0rLSstKy0KOAotKy0rLSstKy0KOQotKy0rLSstKy0KMTAKLSstKy0rLSstCjUwCi0rLSstKy0rLQoxMDAKLSstKy0rLSstCjEwMDAKLSstKy0rLSstCjEwMDAwCi0rLSstKy0rLQoxMjkxNAotKy0rLSstKy0KMzcxMDE3) (with decimal I/O).

Unfortunately, zero length matches seem to have two "sides", causing duplication when used with the regex from the third stage. Only costs one byte though.

Takes input as unary, outputs as unary. Not really sure about using different in/out unary values, but that would save 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 45 bytes

```factor
[ >bin [ ≠ ] monotonic-split [ bin> ] map ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVBBTgMxDLzvK8wDWDnbXUpB6hX1wgVxqnoIS4AImqSJe6gqHsAveBsfWeK42USKxjOesZU3PZKP0/PT5vHhDvaaPtqgYzJR8NHZ0b8aSOHLEln33u698@QzDckcjsaNJkGIhugUonUE901zboAPwhWgQJWhEthl2AlcMFv5nvnaP@RiEHhTmi6OpTiq51Y81bUqpWiKpysRBpQMSVE4l8WYa6yxfFECmUYJLM0ok4rUrVQ/Z6hL9GKpUPGCA/Qdx/Aq39MW1i/WwRb@fn5hB/P3XZcvzXxW1yzoALuJ30R6/Gynfw)