# Calculate the relativistic velocity

Tags: code-golf, physics

In [special relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity), the velocity of a moving object relative to another object that is moving in the opposite direction is given by the formula:

\begin{align}s = \frac{v+u}{1+vu/c^2}.\end{align}

```
s = ( v + u ) / ( 1 + v * u / c ^ 2)
```

In this formula, \$v\$ and \$u\$ are the magnitudes of the velocities of the objects, and \$c\$ is the speed of light (which is approximately \$3.0 \times 10^8 \,\mathrm m/\mathrm s\$, a close enough approximation for this challenge).

For example, if one object was moving at `v = 50,000 m/s`, and another object was moving at `u = 60,000 m/s`, the velocity of each object relative to the other would be approximately `s = 110,000 m/s`. This is what you would expect under Galilean relativity (where velocities simply add). However, if `v = 50,000,000 m/s` and `u = 60,000,000 m/s`, the relative velocity would be approximately `106,451,613 m/s`, which is significantly different than the `110,000,000 m/s` predicted by Galilean relativity.

### The Challenge

Given two integers `v` and `u` such that `0 <= v,u < c`, calculate the relativistic additive velocity, using the above formula, with `c = 300000000`. Output must be either a decimal value or a reduced fraction. The output must be within `0.001` of the actual value for a decimal value, or exact for a fraction.

### Test Cases

Format: `v, u -> exact fraction (float approximation)`

```
50000, 60000 -> 3300000000000/30000001 (109999.99633333346)
50000000, 60000000 -> 3300000000/31 (106451612.90322581)
20, 30 -> 7500000000000000/150000000000001 (49.999999999999666)
0, 20051 -> 20051 (20051.0)
299999999, 299999999 -> 53999999820000000000000000/179999999400000001 (300000000.0)
20000, 2000000 -> 4545000000000/2250001 (2019999.1022226212)
2000000, 2000000 -> 90000000000/22501 (3999822.2301231055)
1, 500000 -> 90000180000000000/180000000001 (500000.9999972222)
1, 50000000 -> 90000001800000000/1800000001 (50000000.972222224)
200000000, 100000000 -> 2700000000/11 (245454545.45454547)
```

Comment: `s/velocity/Velocity of an Unladen Swallow/g`

Comment: "Gallilean relativity"?  Gaillilean mechanics, perhaps, but I'd call your phrase an oxymoron (possibly an anachronistic retronym, too).  Good PPCG question, though!

Comment: @TobySpeight https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_invariance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
sG3e8/pQ/
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=c0czZTgvcFEv&input=WzIwMDAwMDAwMCwgMTAwMDAwMDAwXQ)

```
s      % Take array [u, v] implicitly. Compute its sum: u+v
G      % Push [u, v] again
3e8    % Push 3e8
/      % Divide. Gives [u/c, v/c]
p      % Product of array. Gives u*v/c^2
Q      % Add 1
/      % Divide. Display implicitly
```

Answer (score 12):

### Mathematica, 17 bytes

```
+##/(1+##/9*^16)&
```

An unnamed function taking two integers and returning an exact fraction.

#### Explanation

This uses two nice tricks [with the argument sequence `##`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/45188/8478), which allows me to avoid referencing the individual arguments `u` and `v` separately. `##` expands to a *sequence* of all arguments, which is sort of an "unwrapped list". Here is a simple example:

```
{x, ##, y}&[u, v]
```

gives

```
{x, u, v, y}
```

The same works inside arbitrary functions (since `{...}` is just shorthand for `List[...]`):

```
f[x, ##, y]&[u, v]
```

gives

```
f[x, u, v, y]
```

Now we can also hand `##` to operators which will first treat them as a single operand as far as the operator is concerned. Then the operator will be expanded to its full form `f[...]`, and only then is the sequence expanded. In this case `+##` is `Plus[##]` which is `Plus[u, v]`, i.e. the numerator we want.

In the denominator on the other hand, `##` appears as the left-hand operator of `/`. The reason this multiplies `u` and `v` is rather subtle. `/` is implemented in terms of `Times`:

```
FullForm[a/b]
(* Times[a, Power[b, -1]] *)
```

So when `a` is `##`, it gets expanded afterwards and we end up with

```
Times[u, v, Power[9*^16, -1]]
```

Here, `*^` is just Mathematica's operator for scientific notation.

Answer (score 4):

## Jelly, 9 bytes

```
÷3ȷ8P‘÷@S
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w7czyLc4UOKAmMO3QFM&input=&args=NTAwMDAwMDAsIDYwMDAwMDAw) Alternatively, if you prefer fractions, you can [execute the same code with M](http://m.tryitonline.net/#code=w7czyLc4UOKAmMO3QFM&input=&args=NTAwMDAwMDAsIDYwMDAwMDAw).

#### How it works

```
÷3ȷ8P‘÷@S  Main link. Argument: [u, v]

÷3ȷ8       Divide u and v by 3e8.
    P      Take the product of the quotients, yielding uv ÷ 9e16.
     ‘     Increment, yielding 1 + uv ÷ 9e16.
        S  Sum; yield u + v.
      ÷@   Divide the result to the right by the result to the left.
```

Answer (score 3):

**Python3, <strike>55 31</strike> 29 bytes**

Python is awful for getting inputs as each input needs `int(input())`
but here is my solution anyway:

<strike>v,u=int(input()),int(input());print((v+u)/(1+v*u/9e16))</strike>

Thanks to @Jakube I don't actually need the whole prgrame, just the function. Hence:

```
lambda u,v:(v+u)/(1+v*u/9e16)
```

Rather self explanatory, <strike>get inputs,</strike> computes. I've used c^2 and simplified that as 9e16 is shorter than (3e8**2).

**Python2, 42 bytes**

```
v,u=input(),input();print(v+u)/(1+v*u/9e16)
```

Thanks to @muddyfish

Comment: If you use python2, you can drop the `int(input())` and replace it with `input()`, you can also drop the brackets round the print statement

Comment: @Jakube How would you get the inputs though? OP says "Given two integers v and u"

Comment: @Jakube Yes that would be how I would use lambda in it, but OP is asking implicitly for the whole program not just a function. i.e it has an input and an output

Comment: @Jakube well in that case I golf it down a bit. Cheers!

Comment: You can have `lambda u,v:(v+u)/(1+v*u/9e16)`, and this works for both Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2):

## J, <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
+%1+9e16%~*
```

### Usage

```
>> f =: +%1+9e16%~*
>> 5e7 f 6e7
<< 1.06452e8
```

Where `>>` is STDIN and `<<` is STDOUT.

Answer (score 2):

### Matlab, 24 bytes

```
@(u,v)(u+v)/(1+v*u/9e16)
```

Anonymous function that takes two inputs. Nothing fancy, just submitted for completeness.

Comment: I suggest you remove "regular" from the title. If a toolbox were used it would have to be mentioned; so you can safely just say "Matlab". Oh and welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 16 Bytes

```
q~_:+\:*9.e16/)/
```

I'm still sure there are bytes to be saved here

Comment: Here's two of those bytes: `q~d]_:+\:*9e16/)/`

Comment: @MartinEnder Thanks, didn't know about `d` working like that but can't believe i missed the increment operator....

Comment: 1 byte fewer with array input: [`q~_:+\:*9.e16/)/`](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cX5fOitcOio5LmUxNi8pLw&input=WzIwMDAwMDAwMCAxMDAwMDAwMDBd)

Answer (score 2):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 11 bytes

```
+÷1+9E16÷⍨×
```

The fraction of the sum and [the increment of the divides of ninety quadrillion and the product]:

```
┌─┼───┐         
+ ÷ ┌─┼──────┐  
    1 + ┌────┼──┐
        9E16 ÷⍨ ×
```

`÷⍨` is "divides", as in "ninety quadrillion divides *n*" i.e equivalent to *n* divided by ninety quadrillion.

Comment: Surely that's 11 characters, not bytes, as I'm pretty sure some of those symbols aren't in ASCII?

Comment: @Jules In UTF-8, certainly, but APL has its own code pages, which predate Unicode by a few decades.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 24 bytes

As a single function that can provide either a floating point or fractional number, depending on the context in which it's used...

```
r u v=(u+v)/(1+v*u/9e16)
```

Example usage in REPL:

```
*Main> r 20 30
49.999999999999666
*Main> default (Rational)
*Main> r 20 30 
7500000000000000 % 150000000000001
```

Comment: Save two bytes by defining `u#v` instead of `r u v`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Noether](https://github.com/beta-decay/Noether), 24 bytes

***Non-competing***

```
I~vI~u+1vu*10 8^3*2^/+/P
```

[**Try it here!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/noether?code=SX52SX51KzF2dSoxMCA4XjMqMl4vKy9Q&input=NTAwMDAKNjAwMDA)

Noether seems to be an appropriate language for the challenge given that [Emmy Noether](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmy_Noether) pioneered the ideas of symmetry which lead to Einstein's equations (this, `E = mc^2` etc.)

Anyway, this is basically a translation of the given equation to reverse polish notation.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 14 bytes

```
csQhc*FQ*9^T16
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=csQhc%2aFQ%2a9%5ET16&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=50000%2C+60000%0A50000000%2C+60000000%0A20%2C+30%0A0%2C+20051%0A299999999%2C+299999999%0A20000%2C+2000000%0A2000000%2C+2000000%0A1%2C+500000%0A1%2C+50000000%0A200000000%2C+100000000&debug=0)

Formula: `sum(input) / (1 + (product(input) / 9e16))`

Bonus: [click here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=K%2C%2asQJ%2a9%5ET16%2B%2aFQJ%25%22%25s+-%3E+%25s+%28%25s%29%22%5BPt%60Qj%5C%2F%2FRiFKKcFK&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=50000%2C+60000%0A50000000%2C+60000000%0A20%2C+30%0A0%2C+20051%0A299999999%2C+299999999%0A20000%2C+2000000%0A2000000%2C+2000000%0A1%2C+500000%0A1%2C+50000000%0A200000000%2C+100000000&debug=0)

Comment: It's really unnecessary to include "FGITW" on every solution that is the first on a challenge.

Comment: Sorry, I have deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript 24 bytes

Shaved off 4 bytes thanks to @LeakyNun

```
v=>u=>(v+u)/(1+v*u/9e16)
```

Pretty straightforward

Comment: Would `v=>u=>(v+u)/(1+v*u/9e16)` be ok?

Comment: @LeakyNun yes it would according to this [meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8427/42091)

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 12 bytes

```
sQB9T16^*/h/
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=sQB9T16%5E%2a%2Fh%2F&input=50000%2C+60000&warnings=0)

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 22 bytes

```julia
u\v=(u+v)/(1+u*v/9e16)
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=dVx2PSh1K3YpLygxK3Uqdi85ZTE2KQoKQHByaW50ZigiJWYiLCA1MDAwMDAwMFw2MDAwMDAwMCk&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 21 bytes

```
Prompt U,V:(U+V)/(1+UV/9ᴇ16
```

Comment: Isn't the `E` worth 2 bytes?

Comment: Please check for yourself first... http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/e-ten

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 12 bytes

```
:sum(Ans/(1+prod(Ans/3ᴇ8
```

Takes input as a list of `{U,V}` on `Ans`.

Answer (score 1):

## Microscript II, 28 bytes

```
1s16Es9*s>Fs>Fs<d*</+s<o<+</
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, <strike>44</strike> 45 bytes

Anonymous function, pretty straightforward.

```
function($v,$u){echo ($v+$u)/(1+$v*$u/9e16);}
```

Comment: You need `c^2` in the denominator ... i.e., `9e16` or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell, 34 bytes

```
param($u,$v)($u+$v)/(1+$v*$u/9e16)
```

Extremely straightforward implementation. No hope of catching up with anyone, though, thanks to the 6 `$` required.

Answer (score 0):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 39 bytes

```sql
SELECT (:v+:u)/(1+:v*:u/9e16)FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 38 bytes

```sql
DECLARE @U REAL=2000000, @ REAL=2000000;
PRINT FORMAT((@U+@)/(1+@*@U/9E16),'g')
```

[Try it online!](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/499940/calculate-the-relativistic-velocity)

Straightforward formula implementation.

Answer (score 0):

## ForceLang, 116 bytes

```
def r io.readnum()
set s set
s u r
s v r
s w u+v
s c 3e8
s u u.mult v.mult c.pow -2
s u 1+u
io.write w.mult u.pow -1
```

Answer (score 0):

## dc, 21 bytes

```
svddlv+rlv*9/I16^/1+/
```

This assumes that the precision has already been set, e.g. with `20k`.  Add 3 bytes if you can't make that assumption.

A more accurate version is

```
svdlv+9I16^*dsc*rlv*lc+/
```

at 24 bytes.

Both of them are reasonably faithful transcriptions of the formula, with the only notable golfing being the use of `9I16^*` for c².

Answer (score 0):

### Actually, 12 bytes

```
;8╤3*ì*πu@Σ/
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=OzjilaQzKsOsKs-AdUDOoy8&input=MjAwMDAwMCwgMjAwMDAwMA)

Explanation:

```
;8╤3*ì*πu@Σ/
;             dupe input
 8╤3*ì*       multiply each element by 1/(3e8)
       πu     product, increment
         @Σ/  sum input, divide sum by product
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 24 bytes

```java
u->v->(u+v)/(1+u*v/9e16)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDJbsIwEIbvPMUICSkGY2JKwlZyqnrriSPKwQ02Mg1JFNuREMqzp87SNqE@zPLN2DO/r6xg8@v5q5K3LM01XG1OjJYxESaJtEwTMt2PopgpBR9MJvAYAWTmM5YRKM20dUUqz3CzNeeoc5lcTiGw/KJQ0wrw3r3z@pbaaxw/560LAhBwqMw8KOaBY2YFWjh0ZqbFYsupj6p989a56T2FdoTmSis4dEMAHuDxFQafr6DEPbau2brPli6GF7dPLFi6rkcHXdvu4L9wUK@nLbk/ZP4/RrFdwnsGw4X4BgPlGygbVLZaRZo7P3obtbtWM/qVfLwrzW8kNZpk9uO1cMYT4goMtd1Z64lJMsbNtZMbdgG1gSAsy@K701VQP6UhQu0G9TrlqKy@AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 39 bytes

```forth
: f 2dup + s>f * s>f 9e16 f/ 1e f+ f/ ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKRillBYoaCsU26UpaIFJy1RDM4U0fQXDVIU0bRDD@r@RJRQoIFhpCml6XEYGUKBgCGeBJP4DAA)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f            \ start a new work definition
  2dup +       \ get the sum of u and v
  s>f          \ move to top of floating point stack
  * s>f        \ get the product of u and v and move to top of floating point stack
  9e16 f/      \ divide product by 9e16 (c^2)
  1e f+        \ add 1
  f/           \ divide the sum of u and v by the result
;              \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 0):

## Math++, 26 bytes

```
?>u
?>v
(v+u)/(1+v*u/9e16)
```