# ASCII Odd/Even Cipher

Tags: code-golf, string, cipher

We'll define the **ASCII Odd/Even Cipher** via the below pseudocode:

```
Define 'neighbor' as the characters adjacent to the current letter in the string

If the one of the neighbors is out of bounds of the string, treat it as \0 or null

Take an input string

For each letter in the string, do
  If the 0-based index of the current letter is even, then
    Use the binary-or of the ASCII codes of both its neighbors
  Else
    If the ASCII code of the current letter is odd, then
      Use the binary-or of itself plus the left neighbor
    Else
      Use the binary-or of itself plus the right neighbor
  In all cases,
    Convert the result back to ASCII and return it
  If this would result in a code point 127 or greater to be converted, then
    Instead return a space

Join the results of the For loop back into one string and output it
```

For example, for input `Hello`, the output is `emmol`, since

- The `H` turns to `\0 | 'e'` which is `e`
- The `e` turns to `'e' | 'l'`, or `101 | 108`, which is `109` or `m`
- The first `l` also turns to `101 | 108` or `m`
- The second `l` turns to `108 | 111`, which is `111` or `o`
- The `o` turns to `108 | \0`, or `l`

#### Input

- A sentence composed solely of printable ASCII characters, in [any suitable format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- The sentence may have periods, spaces, and other punctuation, but will only ever be one line.
- The sentence will be at least three characters in length.

#### Output

- The resulting cipher, based on the rules described above, returned as a string or output.

#### The Rules

- Either a full program or a function are acceptable.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

#### Examples

Input on one line, output on the following. Blank lines separate examples.

```
Hello
emmol

Hello, World!
emmol, ww~ved

PPCG
PSWG

Programming Puzzles and Code Golf
r wogsmmoonpuu ~ meannncoooeggonl

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
bcfefgnijknmno~qrsvuvw~yzz

!abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
aaccgeggoikkomoo qsswuww yy

Test 123 with odd characters. R@*SKA0z8d862
euutu133www|todddchizsscguwssr`jS{SK{z~|v66
```

Comment: Is this really a cipher? Doesn't seem to be a way to decipher it.

Comment: Given that the `o` changes to `l` in the first example, I'm pretty sure your specs ensure that the first `o` does not change to `l` in the second example. It should change to `'l' | ','`, whatever that is, right?

Comment: @pipe Yeah. Not really a "cipher" but, not really sure what to call it. It's not really a hash, either. Of the tags we've got, "cipher" seemed closest, so that's what I went with.

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, it goes to `'l' | ','`, which is `108 | 44 --> 1101111 | 0101100`, which becomes `108`, which is `l`. The `,` happens to line up with the `l`, so there's no change when the binary-or takes place.

Comment: Oh, it's really the binary-OR ... I was thinking the binary-XOR. Thank you for the clarification. On the other hand, this speaks even more to pipe's observation that this "cipher"can't really be deciphered, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```
2ịḂị|2\
|ṚḢ,Ç
O0,0jṡ3µÇ€⁸JḂ¤ị"Ọ
```

A straight-forward approach that can surely be made shorter.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=MuG7i-G4guG7i3wyXAp84bma4biiLMOHCk8wLDBq4bmhM8K1w4figqzigbhK4biCwqThu4si4buM&input=&args=J1Byb2dyYW1taW5nIFB1enpsZXMgYW5kIENvZGUgR29sZic)

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, <s>63</s> 62 bytes

Includes +4 for `-lp`

Give input on STDIN

`oddeven.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -lp
s%.%(--$|?$n|$':$&|(ord$&&1?$n:$'))&($n=$&,~v0)%eg;y;\x7f-\xff; ;
```

This works as shown, but to get the claimed score this must be put in a file ***without*** final `;` and newline and the `\xhh` escapes must be replaced by their literal values. You can do this by putting the code above in the file and running:

```
perl -0pi -e 's/\\x(..)/chr hex $1/eg;s/;\n$//' oddeven.pl
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>138</s> 131 bytes

```python
s="\0%s\0"%input();r=''
for i in range(len(s)-2):L,M,R=map(ord,s[i:i+3]);a=i%2and[R,L][M%2]|M or L|R;r+=chr(a*(a<127)or 32)
print r
```

[**Try it online**](http://ideone.com/nuL9ew) (contains all test cases)

Less golfed:

```python
def f(s):
    s="\0%s\0"%s
    r=''
    for i in range(1,len(s)-1):
        if i%2: # even (parity is changed by adding \x00 to the front)
            a=ord(s[i-1]) | ord(s[i+1])
        else:   # odd
            a=ord(s[i])
            if a%2: # odd
                a|=ord(s[i-1])
            else:   # even
                a|=ord(s[i+1])
        r+=chr(a if a<127 else 32)
    print r
```

[**Try it online**](http://ideone.com/UqNMgo) (ungolfed)

I add `\x00` to both sides of the string so that I don't have to worry about that during bitwise or-ing. I loop along the string's original characters, doing bitwise operations and adding them to the result, following the rules for parity.

Comment: Dang, I'm jealous of that `|=` ... equivalent in PowerShell would be `$a=$a-bor$b`

Comment: @TimmyD I didn't actually end up using it, but yeah. It's nice. If only Python had `a?b:c` like JS.

Comment: You can replace
    if a%2: # odd
            a|=ord(s[i-1])
    else:   # even
             a|=ord(s[i+1])
with
    a|=ord(s[i+1-2*(a%2)])

Comment: @NoSeatbelts That's my ungolfed code, which will be left as-is for readability purposes. The golfed submission is the top program.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 152 bytes

```
FromCharacterCode[BitOr@@Which[OddQ@Max@#2,#~Drop~{2},OddQ@#[[2]],Most@#,True,Rest@#]/._?(#>126&)->32&~MapIndexed~Partition[ToCharacterCode@#,3,1,2,0]]&
```

## Explanation

```
ToCharacterCode@#
```

Converts string to ASCII codes

```
Partition[...,3,1,2,0]
```

Partitions the ASCII codes to length 3, offset 1 partitions, with padded 0s.

```
...~MapIndexed~...
```

Applys a function for each partition.

```
Which[...]
```

`If...else if... else` in *Mathematica*.

```
OddQ@Max@#2
```

Checks whether the index (#2) is odd. (`Max` is for flattening); since *Mathematica* index starts at 1, I used `OddQ` here, not `EvenQ`

```
Drop[#,{2}]
```

Takes the ASCII codes of the left and right neighbors.

```
OddQ@#[[2]]
```

Checks whether the ASCII code of the corresponding character is odd.

```
Most@#
```

Takes the ASCII codes of the character and the left neighbor.

```
Rest@#
```

Takes the ASCII codes of the character and the right neighbor.

```
BitOr
```

Applys or-operation.

```
/._?(#>126&)->32
```

Replaces all numbers greater than 126 with 32 (space).

```
FromCharacterCode
```

Converts ASCII code back to characters and join them.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Could you add a bit of explanation for people (like me) who aren't well versed in Mathematica? Also be sure to check out [Tips for golfing in Mathematica](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12900/42963) for some suggestions. Enjoy your stay!

Comment: A few improvements: Accepting and returning [a list of characters instead of an actual string object is completely fine](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2216/8478) and saves a lot on those `From/ToCharacterCode` functions. Then it looks like your `Drop` can use infix notation: `#~Drop~{2}`. And it seems that you're applying `BitOr` to every possible output of the `Which` so why not apply it afterwards and only once?

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby <s>133</s> <s>128</s> <s>108</s> 106 bytes

Jordan helped me save 20 bytes and cia_rana helped me save 2 bytes :)

```ruby
->s{p s[-i=-1]+s.bytes.each_cons(3).map{|x,y,z|i+=1;a=i%2>0?x|z :y%2>0?y|x :y|z;a>126?' ':a.chr}*""+s[-2]}
```

`s` is taken as the input string.

Example output with `s="Test 123 with odd characters. R@*SKA0z8d862"`:

```ruby
"euutu133www|todddchizsscguwssr`jS{SK{z~|v66"
```

---

**Explanation**

The above code is very unreadable so here is an explanation. The code is kind of hacky, I'm quit new to ruby so I bet there is a shorter way to do this :)

```ruby
b=s[1] # for the first character we always use the right neighbour
       # because `\0 | x` will always return x any way. 0 is the
       # left neighbour and x is the right neigbour
s.bytes.each_cons(3).with_index{|c,i| # oh boy, first we convert the string to ascii with each_byte
                                          # we then traverse the resulting array with three elements at
                                          # a time (so for example if s equals "Hello", c will be equal
                                          # to [72, 101, 108])
  if (i+1) % 2 < 1 # if the middle letter (which is considered our current letter) is even
    a = c[0] | c[2] # we use the result of binary-or of its neighbours
  else
    if c[1] % 2 > 0 # if the code of the current letter is odd
      a = c[1] | c[0] # we use the result of binary-or of itself and its left neighbour
    else
      a = c[1] | c[2] # we use the result of binary-or of itself and its right neighbour
    end
  end
  if a>126
    b<<' ' # if the result we use is greater or equal to 127 we use a space
  else
    b<<a.chr # convert the a ascii value back to a character
  end
}
p b+s[-2] # same as the first comment but now we know that x | \0 will always be x
          # this time x is the last characters left neighbour
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain the output needs to be on one line, since the input is also.

Comment: @mbomb007 bummer, then I have to use `print` instead of `p` :p

Comment: @TimmyD oh, so I can't print it to the output at different times?

Comment: @TimmyD ok, so the above is allowed? It now prints everything on one line.

Comment: @Linus Yeah, that's fine. Welcome to PPCG, by the way!

Comment: You can use `bytes` instead of `each_byte` here, and you'll save bytes by initializing `i=0` before enumerating and incrementing with `i+=1` inside the block instead of using `with_index`.

Comment: @Jordan do you mean like [this](https://gist.github.com/Linkaan/79c35c2d24e08a1d6885129d27401af8)?

Comment: Yep, but you need to take an argument (`s`). Also, you can use semicolons or newlines instead of both `and`s. Also: `i%2>0` instead of `(i+1)%2<1`, and destructure `c` into the separate variables (e.g. `each_cons(3){|x,y,z|...`) so you can use e.g. `x` instead of `c[0]`.

Comment: @Jordan thanks, for the help. For some reason when I substitute the c variable for x, y, z I get a syntax error. [Here](https://gist.github.com/Linkaan/79c35c2d24e08a1d6885129d27401af8) is what it looks like now.

Comment: Ruby ternaries get hairy without whitespace. Try this: `a=i%2>0?x|z :y%2>0?y|x :y|z`.

Comment: @Jordan great, that last tip was really useful. I updated my answer.

Comment: Looks good! Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: You can write as shown below: `->s{p s[-i=-1]+s.bytes.each_cons(3).map{|x,y,z|i+=1;a=i%2>0?x|z :y%2>0?y|x :y|z;a>126?' ':a.chr}*""+s[-2]}`

Comment: @cia_rana thanks, that\s really clever, I updated my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

## C - 101 bytes

```
i,k;f(char*p){for(i=0;*p;++p,++i)putchar((k=i&1?*p&1?*p|p[-1]:*p|p[1]:i?p[-1]|p[1]:p[1])<127?k:' ');}
```

We don't even have to check if it's the last item in the string because strings in C are null-terminated.

## Explanation

Rather simple:

Use &1 to test for odd/evenness and ternary expressions to replace if/elses. Increment the char *p to reduce the number of brackets required.

Comment: Nice answer -- welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 1):

## J, 42 bytes

```
4:u:3({.OR{:)`((2|1&{){2:OR/\|.)\0,~0,3&u:
```

Uses the property that verbs in J can be applied in an alternating fashion using a gerund `` ` `` for certain adverbs such as infix `\`.

### Usage

```
   f =: 4:u:3({.OR{:)`((2|1&{){2:OR/\|.)\0,~0,3&u:
   f 'Hello'
emmol
   f 'Hello, World!'
emmol,ww~ved
   f 'PPCG'
PSWG
   f 'Programming Puzzles and Code Golf'
rwogsmmoonpuu~meannncoooeggonl
   f 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
bcfefgnijknmno~qrsvuvw~yzz
   f '!abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
aaccgeggoikkomooqsswuwwyy
   f 'Test 123 with odd characters. R@*SKA0z8d862'
euutu133www|todddchizsscguwssr`jS{SK{z~|v66
```

### Explanation

```
4:u:3({.OR{:)`((2|1&{){2:OR/\|.)\0,~0,3&u:  Input: string S
                                      3&u:  Convert each char to an ordinal
                                    0,      Prepend 0
                                 0,~        Append 0
    3                           \           For each slice of size 3
     (      )`                                For the first slice (even-index)
          {:                                    Get the tail
      {.                                        Get the head
        OR                                      Bitwise OR the head and tail
             `(                )              For the second slice (odd-index)
                             |.                 Reverse the slice
                       2:   \                   For each pair
                         OR/                      Reduce using bitwise OR
                  1&{                           Get the middle value of the slice
                2|                              Take it modulo 2
                      {                         Index into the bitwise OR pairs and select
                                              Repeat cyclically for the remaining slices
4:u:                                        Convert each ordinal back to a char and return
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>125</s> <s>118</s> 114 bytes

Embarrassingly long, but `charCodeAt` and `String.fromCharCode` alone are 29 bytes. :-/

```js
s=>[...s].map((_,i)=>String.fromCharCode((x=(C=i=>s.charCodeAt(i))((i-1)|1)|C(i+1-2*(C(i)&i&1)))>126?32:x)).join``
```

#### How it works

Each character at position `i` is translated with the following formula, which covers all rules at once:

```
C((i - 1) | 1) | C(i + 1 - 2 * (C(i) & i & 1))
```

where `C(n)` returns the ASCII code of the n-th character of the input string.

#### Demo

```js
let f =
    
s=>[...s].map((_,i)=>String.fromCharCode((x=(C=i=>s.charCodeAt(i))((i-1)|1)|C(i+1-2*(C(i)&i&1)))>126?32:x)).join``

console.log(f("Hello"));
console.log(f("Hello, World!"));
console.log(f("PPCG"));
console.log(f("Programming Puzzles and Code Golf"));
console.log(f("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"));
console.log(f("!abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"));
console.log(f("Test 123 with odd characters. R@*SKA0z8d862"));
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>107</s> 97 bytes

probably golfable.

```
for(;$i<strlen($s=$argv[1]);$i++)echo chr(ord($s[$i-1+$i%2])|ord($s[$i+1-2*($i&ord($s[$i])&1)]));
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 145 bytes

```
s=>{var r=s[1]+"";int i=1,l=s.Length,c;for(;i<l;i++){c=i>l-2?0:s[i+1];c=i%2<1?s[i-1]|c:s[i]|(s[i]%2>0?s[i-1]:c);r+=c>'~'?' ':(char)c;}return r;};
```

Full program with ungolfed method and test cases:

```
using System;

namespace ASCIIOddEvenCipher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<string,string>f= s=>
            {
                var r = s[1] + "";
                int i = 1, l = s.Length, c;
                for(;i < l; i++)
                {
                    c = i>l-2 ? 0 : s[i+1];
                    c = i%2<1 ? s[i-1]|c : s[i]|(s[i]%2>0 ? s[i-1] : c);
                    r += c > '~' ? ' ' : (char)c;
                }
                return r;
            };
            
            //test cases:
            Console.WriteLine(f("Hello"));  //emmol
            Console.WriteLine(f("Hello, World!"));  //emmol, ww~ved
            Console.WriteLine(f("PPCG"));   //PSWG
            Console.WriteLine(f("Programming Puzzles and Code Golf"));  //r wogsmmoonpuu ~ meannncoooeggonl
            Console.WriteLine(f("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")); //bcfefgnijknmno~qrsvuvw~yzz
            Console.WriteLine(f("!abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"));    //aaccgeggoikkomoo qsswuww yy
            Console.WriteLine(f("Test 123 with odd characters. R@*SKA0z8d862"));    //euutu133www|todddchizsscguwssr`jS{SK{z~|v66
        }
    }
}
```

This turned out to be longer than I thought...