# Monotone sequence beatitude

Tags: code-golf, sequence, integer

Provided that the input is a **monotone** sequence of three or more integers:

- Output -2 if the sequence strictly decreases. Example: `[7,4,3,2]`
- Output -1 if the sequence monotone decreases but is neither strict nor constant. Example: `[6,5,5]`
- Output 0 if the sequence is constant. Example: `[0,0,0]`
- Output +1 if the sequence monotone increases but is neither strict nor constant. Example: `[-1,2,2,2,4]`
- Output +2 if the sequence strictly increases. Example: `[0,1,2]`

I/O format is flexible. Standard loopholes apply.

Comment: Please add at least 1 worked example and some test cases.

Comment: If the sequence is [-1,2,3,2,4], is it considered increasing ?

Comment: @gobes It is not [monotone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function).

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/101036/36398)

Comment: The addition of the word "constant" in the description confuses me.  As an example, what should the return for `[1,2,5]` be?  It is strictly increasing, but it is a constant interval.

Comment: @Xcali Judging by that a sequence is defined as a function over a discrete set, it shouldn't be too confusing. "Constant" refers to a constant function.

Comment: @DannyuNDos Not everyone here is well versed in the vocabulary and nuances of set theory or even high level mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `g`, 29 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 3.625 bytes

```
¯±:G+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJnPSIsIiIsIsKvwrE6RysiLCIiLCJbMyw0LDUsNV0iXQ==)

Bitstring:

```
11001100111100010001111111001
```

Port of the 05ab1e answer

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>8 7</s> 6 bytes

```
¥.±Z+W
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m73MwDQxyTB1weqySnslBV07BSX7yqWlJWm6FisOLdU7tDFKO3xJcVJy8UIdiOiCm5rR0YY6RjrGsTpg2ghIGyHRhkDaGEzHQnQAAA)

```
¥      deltas
.±     sign
Z      maximum without popping
+      add (vectorized)
W      minimum
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
IṠQ.ịS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/z4c4FgXoPd3cH/3@4c5/1o4Y5Crp2Co8a5lofbuc63P6oaU3k///R0YY6RjrGsTpg2ghIGyHRhkDaGEzHAgA)

Port of Command Master's [05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266708/97916). A monadic link taking a list of integers and returning an integer.

### Explanation

```
I      | Increments
 Ṡ     | Signs
  Q    | Uniquify
   .ị  | Last and first
     S | Sum
```

Comment: I think uniquify is not necessary [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/z4c4Feg93dwf/f7hzn/WjhjkKunYKjxrmWh9u5zrc/qhpTeT//9HRhjpGOsaxOmDaCEgbIdGGQNoYTMcCAA "Jelly – Try It Online")

Comment: @pajonk it is if the input is something like `[1,2,2,3]`

Comment: Ah, I get it now. It's "Last and first" (as described) not min and max.

Answer (score 6):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 11 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⊢+⇌.⊝±≡/-◫2
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_2_0__ZiDihpAg4oqiK-KHjC7iip3CseKJoS8t4perMgoKZiBbMSAyIDNdCmYgWzEgMiAyXQpmIFsyIDIgMl0KZiBbMiAyIDFdCmYgWzMgMiAxXQo=)

Port of Command Master's [05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266708/97916).

```
⊢+⇌.⊝±≡/-◫2
      ≡/-◫2  # deltas
     ±       # sign
    ⊝        # deduplicate
   .         # duplicate
  ⇌          # reverse
 +           # add
⊢            # first
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>71</del> 63 bytes

Saved 8 bytes thanks to the comment of @corvus_192

---

```scala
x=>x zip x.tail map{case(a,b)=>b compare a}pipe(x=>x.min+x.max)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fY7BSgMxFEX38xWXrhJMArYUVJgRl4KuXJYib2JGI5lMmEk1WPolbrrRjUu_pn9j2gqCaOFxH9x3uPe9vg-aHE0-ZiPpu2fq_Wi-ubFt6PqI3UktonVKP5D11t-r26KrH42OuM4GTIrG3w24CAHLosATOTRnYFd2iLNLH-dllZWjxNsiNvJkc57KKuHFBiQVyTq0FJaaBsNI1LysauiuDdQb0CrYYNiWV631R1kp8e-YTyD01kfnWbMrY8cCY4GJwFTglHNeHCSm_xE_c4CQOUTmFPl3kdwi49_Yav_6er3fXw)

Comment: 63 bytes: `x=>x zip x.tail map{case(a,b)=>b compare a}pipe(x=>x.min+x.max)`

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 47 bytes

```javascript
a=>(a.reduce((p,v)=>(a|=p<v?5:p>v?-2:3,v)),a%3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1k4jUa8oNaU0OVVDo0CnTBMkUGNbYFNmb2pVYFdmr2tkZQwU1tRJVDXW/J@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrpGmEW2uo2Cio2Cso2AUq6nJhSZppqNgCkRYZAx0FEAIi4yuIdAsGDLBrtUQYt1/AA)

#### Method

Because the input array `a` contains at least 3 elements, it is guaranteed to be evaluated  to \$0\$ when coerced to an integer. So we can safely re-use it as a signed 32-bit mask.

For each pair of consecutive elements \$(p,\:v)\$ in the input array, we apply to `a` a bitwise OR with:

- \$5\$ if \$p<v\$
- \$-2\$ if \$p>v\$
- \$3\$ if \$p=v\$

These values were chosen such that the expected output in \$[-2\dots2]\$ is obtained by reducing the final bitmask modulo \$3\$.

#### List of cases

Because the sequence is monotone, there are only 5 possible cases:

| \$p<v\$ | \$p>v\$ | \$p=v\$ | operations | final bitmask | modulo 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| no | no | yes | 0 | 3 | 3 | **0** |
| no | yes | no | 0 | -2 | -2 | **-2** |
| no | yes | yes | 0 | -2 | 3 | -1 | **-1** |
| yes | no | no | 0 | 5 | 5 | **2** |
| yes | no | yes | 0 | 5 | 3 | 7 | **1** |

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 55 bytes

```python
lambda S,*s:min(x:={(S<t)-(S>(S:=t))for t in s})+max(x)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3zXMSc5NSEhWCdbSKrXIz8zQqrGyrNYJtSjR1NYLtNIKtbEs0NdPyixRKFDLzFIprNbVzEys0KjSh2rMLijLzSjTSNAx1jHSMdUx1LDU1udDFTFHEoBBNTNdYR9dURxdZuy5Q1AhJAmLlggUQGgA)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 53 bytes

```
def f(s):t=map(cmp,s[1:],s[:-1]);return min(t)+max(t)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMGCpaUlaboWN01TUtMU0jSKNa1KbHMTCzSScwt0iqMNrWKBpJWuYaymdVFqSWlRnkJuZp5GiaZ2bmIFkIJqLi0oyswr0UjTiDbUMdIx1jHVsYzV1OTCEDVFE4VCDFFdYx1dUx1dVEN0geJGyFIQy2E-AAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 43 bytes

```
lambda s:cmp(s[::-1],s)<<len(set(s))/len(s)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMHiNNuYpaUlaboWN7VzEnOTUhIViq2Scws0iqOtrHQNY3WKNW1sclLzNIpTSzSKNTX1wWxNqJaagqLMvBKNNI1oQx0jHWMdEx3TWE1NLjRRbOJQiCKqa6ija6SjawxGJjq6pjhkoVIQNyxYAKEB)

Logs:

- My original answer (49 bytes):

```
lambda s:cmp(s[-1],s[0])*(2-(len(set(s))<len(s)))
```

- Neil's suggestion: `*(2-(len(set(s))<len(s)))` -> `-~(len(set(s))==len(s))`
- xnor's suggestion: `*(2-(len(set(s))<len(s)))` -> `<<(len(set(s))==len(s))` ; `cmp(s[-1],s[0])` -> `cmp(s[::-1],s)`
- Albert.Lang's suggestion: `*(2-(len(set(s))<len(s)))` -> `<<len(set(s))/len(s)`

Thank for amazing suggestions!

Comment: `-~(len(set(s))==len(s))` is a byte shorter than `(2-(len(set(s))<len(s)))`.

Comment: Better yet, `<<(len(set(s))==len(s))` without `*`. Also, `cmp(s[::-1],s)` saves a byte

Comment: Even more betterer: `lambda s:cmp(s[::-1],s)<<len(set(s))/len(s)`

Comment: Thanks for y'all amazing suggestions. Was busy so just checked cg now.

Answer (score 5):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 5 bytes

```
∆±uÄµ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FqsedbQd2lh6uOXQ1iXFScnFUOEFN_WizXVMdIx1jGK5os10THVMgbSBDhACaV1DHSMwNAELAnmxEG0A)

```
∆±uÄµ
∆       Delta
 ±      Sign
  u     Uniquify
   Ä    Multiply by 2
    µ   Mean
```

Answer (score 5):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 14 bytes

```
+/2#?0 1'1_-':
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs9LWN1K2N1AwVDeM11W34uJKU9cwVDBSMLYGkUbWRnDS0NoYRGpyAQAGowlp)

A slight variation on [Nick Kennedy's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266711/78410). `0 1'` is from coltim's comment on another K answer.

```
+/2#?0 1'1_-':
         1_-':    differences
     0 1'         binary search into 0 1; negative -> -1, 0 -> 0, positive -> 1
    ?             keep unique elements
  2#              cycle the elements to length 2
+/                sum
```

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>32</s> 29 bytes

```r
\(x)sum(range(sign(diff(x))))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhZ7YzQqNItLczWKEvPSUzWKM9PzNFIy09KAokAAUXPTME3D0MpYkytNI1nDUMdQx0gTwjbSMUJiA2XAbGMrQ6jGBQsgNAA)

A function taking a vector and returning the relevant result. Based on [Command Master's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266708/97916).

*Thanks to @pajonk for saving three bytes!*

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhZ7YzQqNItLczWKEvPSUzWKM9PzNFIy09KAokAAUXPTME3D0MpYkytNI1nDUMdQx0gTwjbSMUJiA2XAbGMrQ6jGBQsgNAA) by porting your own Jelly answer :)

Comment: I don't know R, but it doesn't look like you need the `range`.

Comment: Thanks @Shaggy. You don’t for the examples used but would if the sequences were longer than 3 integers.

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>21</s> 16 bytes

Port of 05AB1E answer

-5 thanks to @coltim

```
&/+/|/\0 1'1_-':
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs1LT19av0Y8xUDBUN4zXVbfi4kpT1zBUMFIwtgaRRtZGcNLQ2hhEanIBAC5ECjE=)

```
           1_-': deltas
       0 1'      sign
  +/|/\          add maximum
&/               minimum
```

Comment: I think you can use `|/\ ` rather than `1|/\ `, since the input is going to be a list (so the max-reduce-converges will end after a single iteration). There's also the golfy `0 1'intList` sign version that saves several bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>57</s> 51 bytes

```
\d+
*
Lv`\b_+,_+
+`_,_
,
O^`
,,G`
^_
-_
/[^-]+/_`_+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcmxCoNAEIThft5DkOyInN6Bb2Aj@AAxt6uYIk2KIL7@uTZhmo/5f@/j811DqerRyrILHphOWzYVqkBMqSDmbCBHQ1Y0ivaZm5e0aiqlBHaMHBB4q2dyD/zPnfztvAZ3vHUB) Link includes test cases. Only accepts positive integer lists, but will output `-2` to `2` as required. Explanation:

```
\d+
*
```

Convert to unary.

```
Lv`\b_+,_+
+`_,_
,
```

For each overlapping pair of integers, get a substring representing the delta: `_+,` for negative, `,` for `0` and `,_+` for positive.

```
O^`
```

Group identical substrings together and sort `_,` first.

```
,,G`
```

Keep only one of each group, but if there is only one group, keep two of it.

```
^_
-_
```

If there was a `_,` then prefix a `-` sign.

```
/[^-]+/_`_+
```

Count the runs of `_`s.

Edit: Saved 6 bytes by porting my answer to [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d) for 61 bytes and then backporting the golfs:

```
\d+
$*
M!&`\b1+,1+
+`1,1
,
O^`
+`¶.+¶
¶
^1
-1
((1+)|,|¶)+
$#2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyZFm0tFi8tXUS0hJslQW8dQm0s7wVDHkEuHyz8uAcg@tE1P@9A2LiCKM@TSNeTS0DDU1qzRqTm0TROoU9no/39DHSMdEx0LLqAuIMtYxxTIttCBQyDbFChqpAMy1QKoEsgCAA) Link includes test cases. Only accepts positive integer lists, but will output `-2` to `2` as required. Explanation: Retina 0.8.2 uses `$*` (which produces `1`s) instead of `*` (which produces `_`s) for unary, needs to use `M!&` instead of `Lv`, and doesn't have an equivalent of `,,G` or `_` (as a command), so I had to emulate those.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 50 bytes

```javascript
a=>~!a.some(p=x=>p==(p=x))*Math.sign(a[0]-a.pop())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1q5OMVGvOD83VaPAtsLWrsDWFsTQ1NTyTSzJ0CvOTM/TSIw2iNVN1CvIL9DQ1PyfnJ9XnJ@TqpeTn66RphFtqGOkYxyrqcmFRdwIqzgQYhE3xqEeJA5S/x8A)

Use begin and end to detect direction

Answer (score 3):

## [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 23 bytes

```
_"-"2%map0<=>"|/"Q + &/
```

[Try it on scline!](https://scline.fly.dev/#H4sIAKvoUmUCA4uONlQwUjBWMFWwjNXjUoDzTKE8KITzjOMVTOMVLOMVICLxCkbxSGJAwRhrhdzEAgA7e7IoVwAAAA#H4sIAKvoUmUCA4tX0lUyUs1NLDCwsbVTqtFXClTQVlDTBwBmzrqDFwAAAA#) Port of [Command Master's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266708/41247).

### Explanation

Prettified:

```
_ \- 2%map 0<=> \|/ Q + &/
```

- `_ \- 2%map` negated delta (via pairwise difference)
- `0<=>` sign (i.e. compare to 0)
- `\|/ Q` dup and get max
- `+ &/` vectorized-add and get min

Answer (score 3):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 33 bytes

```
f(L)=D.max+D.min
D=sgn(L[2...]-L)
```

Port of 05AB1E.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vv4pgpmhg1)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rxbl6uy6cw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 23 bytes

```
≔ＥΦθκ⁻›ι§θκ‹ι§θκθＩ⁺⌊θ⌈θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU/DN7FAwy0zpyS1SKNQRyFbU0fBNzOvtFjDvSg1ESSYqaPgWOKZl5JaAZEHKvBJLS7GFAfJFGpacwUUZeaVaDgnFpdoBOQADQIal5lbmqtRCDI6sQLKBgLr//@jow11FIx0FEx0FCxiY//rluUAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Port of @Albert.Lang's Python answer.

```
≔ＥΦθκ⁻›ι§θκ‹ι§θκθ
```

Get the signs of the deltas.

```
Ｉ⁺⌊θ⌈θ
```

Add the minimum and maximum of them.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 54 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(n=p=o=v=>[n|=a>v,p|=a<v,o|=a==v,a=v])|p-n<<!o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcrBCoMwEIThe9@itwRWoXrN5EXEw2JVLDa71LIn3z2N95Q5/PAxLzY@ps@m3ybJc84LMiNy@2Z1CQqBIQ7pBEcjLQlGUgIYMWz0pzYphLvkSdIh@9zusrrFDQ/qqB@9v1W8q3pZxfs//8uvf/4B)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 63 bytes

Port of [my JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266729/58563).

```c
m,p;f(a,n)int*a;{for(m=0;p=*a++,--n;)m|=p<*a?5:p>*a?-2:3;m%=3;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc9LCsIwEAbgvacYBKGpE@hToTF6EHWRpq0UTAxVdFF7dWOUSDcWfpjFx7wkPUlprULDmkCgJq2@hYL1zaULFI@Y4aFYLpFSzYh6crMJxS4vzNYVmhQpUwuessHeL20FSrQ6INDPANwUEPsjcOhhjZAhpAgJDMxb6W2FkLuMID1E@M0IlQcau0G/ZKPXY2PsVzkxnbMmmC@qg54jfF6EjBD2j0p35ATJaarc@RNU@67BvmRzFqerpY83)

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 52 bytes

Prompts for vector:

```
+/2 1 0×(×n)×(s=⍴v),((s<⍴v)^s>0),0=s←1+|n←+/×-2-/v←⎕
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tv7a@kYKhgsHh6RqHp@dpAqli20e9W8o0dTQ0im3ArLhiOwNNHQPbYpAm7Zo8IKWtf3i6rpGufhmQDTTvP9Akrv9pXOYKJgrGCkZcaVxmCqYKpkDaQAEIgfSh9YYKRmBoAhYF8gA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <del>193</del> 183 bytes

---

Saved 10 bytes thanks to the comment of @corvus_192

---

Golfed version. [Attempt this online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hU_LSsQwFF1PvuLSjQlNhunoiPYxexeC60qFTGnG4DQdQgrS0C9xUwS_wS9xMX9jUusIgg7k5l4O59xz7svrthkOZ3tePvFtBTWXCiFZ7xttAKNZIGoTuFZz8xgg8tYawa4O76JVJZSY0w1IZYgrKwXwdGN1ZVqtIOoTD6yPAHPINC56NOoFVvfFt7yLM-8xv-XPN8pcXiR5nD10iWg0yDhbJDLdVQorwqJEhqHVcVY6uSyo-8KoIN5Op53tMj1a63VuczcfXbsw76f4H6O9PxUTsGjmbpzfaZdip7DAYyYbUVhSOKewonDdE3KatfqP9fNOsJhbxtw29rcp87Tlb-p03DB89U8)

```go
func c(a,b int)int{if a<b{return 1};if a>b{return -1};return 0}
func f(n[]int)int{z:=math.MaxInt64;Z:=^z;for i:=0;i<len(n)-1;i++{r:=c(n[i],n[i+1]);if r<z{z=r};if r>Z{Z=r}};return z+Z}
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZJLasMwEIahO-sUg1cWlkKcNqUPJ_suCl10F7xQjZWKWrJxZAgEn6SbUOilepqObCWpC23AWPP4NPpnmPePdbXff7ZW8puvi-da5G9iXYAWyhCidF01FiIShFLbEA8t7GtIKCGyNTnkla5FU0SCwQsoY6n7wY4ESoKAFINoB01h28ZAQoLOZ5bjDB9S3puSzpeXkWn1BlbZz9JaGYbytnC3AKdm8ii2D8ZeXzHvKtO7JJBVA8ph03s8UygL0xekPMFAHHsJm7a0jjo045CVyhgMRpxkFDnU7dEUUEJ_12mBhY-j3424Za9y4NAYc6d2XY3Yoce23ewj6m7i0CdPDTZemkhG_Rx2CYMZg0sGcwa3HaXnqfl_1Ok7Q3EsxrEa__tR7rDZb7Qblsvv2GHXvgE)

```go
package main

import (
	"fmt"
	"math"
)

func compare(a, b int) int {
	if a < b {
		return 1
	}
	if a > b {
		return -1
	}
	return 0
}

func f(nums []int) int {
	min, max := math.MaxInt64, math.MinInt64
	for i := 0; i < len(nums)-1; i++ {
		result := compare(nums[i], nums[i+1])
		if result < min {
			min = result
		}
		if result > max {
			max = result
		}
	}
	return min + max
}

func main() {
	fmt.Println(f([]int{1, 2, 3, 5, 9}))
	fmt.Println(f([]int{1, 2, 3, 5, 5}))
	fmt.Println(f([]int{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}))
	fmt.Println(f([]int{1, 1, -3, -5, -9}))
	fmt.Println(f([]int{-1, -2, -3, -5, -9}))
}
```

Comment: -9 bytes: `z:=math.MaxInt64;Z:=-~z;`

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 175 bytes

Short version:

```
func m(_ n:[Int])->Int{var r=0,s=0>1;for i in 0..<n.count-1{let(y,x)=(n[i+1],n[i]);if y>x{r=r>0 && !s ?2:1}else if y<x{r=r<0 && !s ? -2:-1}else{r=r.signum();s=0<1}};return r}
```

Verbose version:

Basically update the return value to be 2 or -2 as long as the elements differ from each other and "clamp" it to -1,0,+1 as soon as two same elements are found.

```
func m(_ n:[Int])->Int{
    var r=0,
        s=0>1
    for i in 0..<n.count-1{
        let(y,x)=(n[i+1],n[i]);
        if y>x{
            r=r>0 && !s ?2:1
        }else if y<x{
            r=r<0 && !s ? -2:-1
        }else{
            r=r.signum();
            s=0<1
        }
    };
    return r
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 53 bytes

```perl
s/\S+/$'&&$'-$&/ge;$_=2*(/^(\S+ )\1+$/?$1<=>0:.5-/-/)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YPyZYW19FXU1NRV1XRU0/PdVaJd7WSEtDP04DKKOgGWOoraJvr2JoY2tnYKVnqquvq6/5/7@xgpGCIReINOIyArONwGxDBUMwaQQljf/lF5Rk5ucV/9f1NdUzMDT4r1uQAwA)