# Increment an Array

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic, array, integer

Given a nonempty array of positive integers, "increment" it once as follows:

- If all the array elements are equal, append a `1` to the end of the array. For example:

  ```
  [1] -> [1, 1]
  [2] -> [2, 1]
  [1, 1] -> [1, 1, 1]
  [3, 3, 3, 3, 3] -> [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1]
  ```
- Else, increment the first element in the array that is the array's minimum value. For example:

  ```
  [1, 2] -> [2, 2]
  [2, 1] -> [2, 2]
  [3, 1, 1] -> [3, 2, 1] -> [3, 2, 2] -> [3, 3, 2] -> [3, 3, 3]
  [3, 4, 9, 3] -> [4, 4, 9, 3] -> [4, 4, 9, 4] -> [5, 4, 9, 4] -> [5, 5, 9, 4] -> ...
  ```

(Each `->` represents one increment, which is all your program needs to do.)

Output the resulting incremented array.

**The shortest code in bytes wins.**

Comment: Does 0 count as positive integer

Comment: @Downgoat 0 is not ever positive on PPCG. If 0 was allowed, the term would be "non-negative"

Answer (score 18):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>8</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
‘;ṀỤḢṬ+
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCYO-G5gOG7pOG4ouG5rCs&input=&args=WzMsIDMsIDMsIDMsIDNd) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCYO-G5gOG7pOG4ouG5rCsKxbzDh-KCrEvigqzigqxq4oKs4oCcIC0-IOKAnVk&input=&args=WzFdLCBbMl0sIFsxLCAxXSwgWzMsIDMsIDMsIDMsIDNdLCBbMSwgMl0sIFsyLCAxXSwgWzMsIDEsIDFdLCBbMywgMiwgMV0sIFszLCAyLCAyXSwgWzMsIDMsIDJdLCBbMywgNCwgOSwgM10sIFs0LCA0LCA5LCAzXSwgWzQsIDQsIDksIDRdLCBbNSwgNCwgOSwgNF0).

#### How it works

```
‘;ṀỤḢṬ+  Main link. Argument: A

‘        Increment all elements of A.
  Ṁ      Yield the maximum of A.
 ;       Concatenate both results. Note that the appended maximum will be the 
         minimum of the resulting array if and only if all elements of A are equal.
   Ụ     Grade up; yield the indices of the resulting array, sorted by their
         corresponding values in that array.
    Ḣ    Head; extract the first index, which is the index of the first occurrence
         of the minimum. For an array of equal elements, this will be the index
         of the appended maximum.
     Ṭ   Untruth; for index i, yield an array of i-1 zeroes, followed by a 1.
      +  Add this array to A, incrementing the minimum or appending a 1.
```

Answer (score 13):

## Python 3, <s>62</s> <s>53</s> <s>51</s> 50 bytes

Function which modifies the list passed to it ([allowed by meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/4942#4942)).

```py
def F(a):a+=1//len({*a})*[0];a[a.index(min(a))]+=1
```

[**Try on repl.it!**](https://repl.it/E9oy/2)

-9 bytes thanks to Lynn for spotting that, because the array will be of positive integers, I can append '0' to the end of the array and have that incremented.

Special thanks to mbomb007 for golfing `len(set(a))` to `len({*a})`, and Dennis for the floordiv trick!

Comment: Hmm. "Output the resulting incremented array". Does this qualify?

Comment: I can't quite remember where, but I remember seeing a meta post that modifying a given list in place is allowed by default. I'll have a look for it @TuukkaX

Comment: @TuukkaX I'm not entirely sure. It seems ok but I'll defer to the meta concensus about modifying arrays in place, if there is one.

Comment: you can replace `a+=[0]` with `a+=0,`

Comment: [Found it!](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/4942#4942) @TuukkaX

Comment: Good! Nice golf by the way :) I was thinking of a shorter way to check whether the list has only one distinct element, but `a[1:]==a[:-1]` is also 13 bytes...

Comment: In Python 3, you can use `len({*L})<2` to find if all elements of a list are equal.

Comment: @mbomb007 That's a neat trick! It didn't work in the version I have installed, but worked online with 3.5 :)

Comment: `a+=1//len({*a})*[0]` should save a byte.

Comment: Good spot! @Dennis

Answer (score 9):

## Mathematica, <s>70</s> <s>57</s> 55 bytes

*Virtually all of the improvement is due to Martin Ender, who kicks my ass at pattern matching approaches! Also JHM came up with essentially the same solution at essentially the same time.* (byte count uses ASCII encoding)

```
±{p:x_ ..}:={p,1};±{x___,y_,z___}/;y≤x~Min~z:={x,y+1,z}
```

Defines a function `±` taking one list argument. If that list argument contains some number of copies of the same element (detected by `x_..` and named `p`), then output the list with a `1` appended. Otherwise, if that list argument has a special element `y` (with `x` being the zero or more elements before `y`, and `z` being the zero or more elements after `y`) which is at most the minimum of the other elements, then output the list with that `y` incremented. Any instance of the minimum element of the list will be matched by `y`, but fortunately Mathematica chooses the first one to act upon.

Comment: Because `±` is a 2-byte character, your code is 59 bytes long. Also, there must be a space between `x_` and `..` because *Mathematica* interprets `x_..` as `x_. .` (which throws errors). Plus, the infix form of `Min` (`x~Min~z`) would make this 2 bytes shorter (which makes this solution identical to one of mine :p ...) Welp you can take the credit because my edit was later than yours....

Comment: Nah, Martin Ender gets most of my credit anyway. Why is ± two bytes?

Comment: @GregMartin `±` in UTF-8 (*Mathematica* uses UTF-8 by default; try `$CharacterEncoding`) is a two-byte character (U+00B1).

Comment: @JHM UTF-8 is *not* the default character encoding on Windows. Mathematica can read source files in a single-byte code page that includes `±`.

Comment: @MartinEnder It seems that [answers are assumed to use UTF-8 unless specified elsewhere](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5879/60043), so I believe `±` should count as two bytes.

Comment: @JHM this answer could be more explicit about it, but the meta post says that the language's default takes precedence over UTF-8 and the default encoding of Mathematica on Windows is the Windows code page, not UTF-8.

Comment: @MartinEnder Welp, I don't think *Mathematica* has a default encoding at all, so it should be assumed to use UTF-8. For instance, my default encoding is CP-949 (because I'm using Korean Windows), so `±` is two bytes, but on English Windows (using CP-1252), it is one byte.

Comment: @MartinEnder what's the reference for the mentioned single-byte code page?

Comment: @ASimmons My fresh Mathematica installation on Windows, which has `$CharacterEncoding` set to `WindowsANSI` which is CP1252 (which is sufficiently compatible with ISO 8859-1 for `±` and `·` to be usable for a single byte).

Comment: @MartinEnder That's awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), 61 bytes

```js
a=>new Set(a).size>1?++a[a.indexOf(Math.min(...a))]:a.push(1)
```

Outputs by [modifying its argument](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4942/42545). I can't find a way to determine whether an array has only one unique item in less that 17 bytes, but suggestions are welcome.

#### Test snippet

```js
f=a=>new Set(a).size>1?++a[a.indexOf(Math.min(...a))]:a.push(1)
g=a=>0 in a?console.log("Input:",`[${a}]`,"Output:",`[${f(a),a}]`):console.log("Invalid input")

g([1])
g([2])
g([1,1])
g([1,2,2,3])
g([2,2,2,3])
g([3,2,2,3])
g([3,3,2,3])
g([3,3,3,3])
g([3,3,3,3,1])
```

```html
<input id=I value="1,2,2,3"><button  onclick="g(I.value.match(/\d+/g)||[])">Run</button>
```

#### Other attempts

Here are a few alternate ways of deciding whether the array has more than one unique input:

```js
a=>a.some(x=>x-a[0])?++a[a.indexOf(Math.min(...a))]:a.push(1)
a=>a.some(x=>x-m,m=Math.min(...a))?++a[a.indexOf(m)]:a.push(1)
```

Both of the `some`s can be replaced with `find` as well. `.sort` would be shorter for finding the minimum, if the default sort wasn't lexicographical (why, JS, why?):

```js
a=>new Set(a).size>1?++a[a.indexOf(a.sort()[0])]:a.push(1)
// Instead we have to do:
a=>new Set(a).size>1?++a[a.indexOf(a.sort((x,y)=>x-y)[0])]:a.push(1)
```

I tried recursion to find the minimum, but it turned out way longer:

```js
f=(a,n=1,q=a.indexOf(n))=>~q?a.some(x=>x-n)?++a[q]:a.push(1):f(a,n+1)
```

And here's a string-based solution which seemed like a good idea at first: (input is given in array format in a string, e.g. `"[1,2,3]"`)

```js
a=>a.replace(m=/(\d+),(?!\1)/.test(a)?Math.min(...eval(a)):']',+m+1||",1]")
```

Comment: Is using a.find(n=>n==Math.min(...a)) shorter?

Comment: @Downgoat I'm not sure how I'd use that, as it returns the item rather than the index

Comment: yeah >_> whoops, I missed your ++ and didn't realize you needed a reference

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>21</s> <s>20</s> 16 bytes

Saved 4 bytes thanks to *Adnan*.

```
DÙgi0¸«}ÐWksgÝQ+
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=RMOZZ2kwwrjCq33DkFdrc2fDnVEr&input=WzQsMyw5LDNd)

**Explanation**

```
                      # input = [3,2,1] used as example
D                     # duplicate input
 Ùgi                  # if all elements are equal
    0¸«}              # append 0
        Ð             # triplicate list
                      # STACK: [3,2,1], [3,2,1], [3,2,1]
         Wk           # index of minimum element
                      # STACK: [3,2,1], [3,2,1], 2
           s          # swap top 2 elements of stack
                      # STACK: [3,2,1], 2, [3,2,1]
            g         # length of list
                      # STACK: [3,2,1], 2, 3
             Ý        # range [0 ... length]
                      # STACK: [3,2,1], 2, [0,1,2,3]
              Q       # equal
                      # STACK: [3,2,1], [0,0,1,0]
               +      # add
                      # OUTPUT: [3,2,2]
```

Comment: I think that `DÙgi0¸«}ÐWksgÝQ+` also works.

Comment: @Adnan: Aah, nice idea using `ÝQ` with `k`. Thanks!

Comment: [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cHem4aFVh1fHq4RnH5@r/f9/tLGOoY5hLAA)

Answer (score 7):

## C++14, <s>178 176 174 155 142</s> 135 bytes

## submission

```
#include<list>
#include<algorithm>
[](auto&l){auto e=end(l),b=begin(l);l.size()^count(b,e,*b)?++*min_element(b,e):(l.push_back(1),0);};
```

## invocation

```
std::list<int> s = {4, 4, 9, 4};

//invoke like this
auto i = [](auto&l){auto e=end(l),b=begin(l);l.size()^count(b,e,*b)?++*min_element(b,e):(l.push_back(1),0);};
i(s);

//or like that
[](auto&l){auto e=end(l),b=begin(l);l.size()^count(b,e,*b)?++*min_element(b,e):(l.push_back(1),0);}(s);
```

### ungolfed

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void i(list<int>& l) {
    auto e = l.end(), b = l.begin();
    
    if (l.size() == count(b, e, l.front())) {
        l.push_back(1);
    } else {
        ++*min_element(b, e);
    }
}

int main() {
    list<int> s = {4, 4, 9, 4};

    //invoke like this
    i(s);
    
    for (auto o:s)
        std::cout << o << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

This is my first time playing golf, help is appreciated.

EDIT: forgot to mention you have to compile it with at least <s>`-std=c++11`</s> `-std=c++14`

EDIT2: I realized i can leave out the space in the includes `#include <list>`

EDIT3: saved two more bytes by replacing `l.begin()` by `begin(l)`

EDIT4: saved another 19(!) bytes thanks to @Quentin (see his comment)

EDIT5: Quentin shaved off 13 more bytes, thanks!

EDIT6: as TuukkaX pointed out, unnamed lambdas/functions suffice so i removed the `auto i=` in the bytecount

Comment: I can't help you with C++, but I can say: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: I think you don't need the spaces in the `#include` lines.

Comment: Oh thank you I just realized it myself :)

Comment: Replacing the function with a lambda (`auto i=[](auto&l){...};`) saves one byte (more if we count the return type you forgot ;) ), using `^`  instead of `==` and swapping the operands saves another. `std::list`'s iterators are certainly `std::` classes, so you can drop `std::` from both `std::count` and `std::min_element` thanks to ADL (-10). `l.front()` is also `*b` (-7). I end up with a 120-byte `auto i=[](auto&l){auto e=end(l),b=begin(l);l.size()^count(b,e,*b)?void(++*find(b,e,*min_element(b,e))):l.push_back(1);};` :)

Comment: Woops, forgot to count the headers. That didn't sound right. 155 bytes it is.

Comment: Wow thank you so much @Quentin! Tbh I never messed with lambdas before so I don't quite understand it but I'll definitely look into it now. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: While we're at it, [the documentation for `std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) states that it returns the *first* smallest element, so the `find()` is superfluous, that's 11 bytes. In the conditional, using a pair of parentheses and the comma operator to coerce the right expression to `int` is shorter than casting the left one to `void` by 2 bytes. This leads to `auto i=[](auto&l){auto e=end(l),b=begin(l);l.size()^count(b,e,*b)?++*min_element(b,e):(l.push_back(1),0);};`, 142 bytes :)

Comment: Oops the find thing was pretty stupid of me.

Comment: Can't you just use a pure lambda and drop the `auto i=`?

Comment: You can drop the `#include<list>` in your golfed version and should change the title to `C++14`

Comment: I don't understand why I can drop the include in the bytecount as it is required by the lambda, can you please explain it or post a link? I changed the Title. @TuukkaX, I also don't think this would be allowed as you'd have to invoke it with the entire body, or I don't understand your proposal.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9032/41754), it states that: "Unnamed functions/lambdas are acceptable, ex. `[](int n){ return n+1; }`".

Answer (score 5):

### Scratch, <s>25</s> 34 blocks + <s>7</s> 6 bytes

[image: Program]

Takes input as a predefined array of integers. Note that arrays are 1-indexed in Scratch.

In Python, this would look like: (Note that unlike Scratch, Python is 0-indexed)

```
lowval = 0
hival = 0
n = 1
for i in range(len(input)):
    if(input[i] < input[lowval]):
        lowval = i
    if(input[i] > input[hival]):
        hival = i
    # No increment statement needed because python.
if(lowval == hival):
    input.append(1)
else:
    input[lowval] += 1
print(input)
```

Comment: Golfing comments please?

Comment: why do you declare fval?

Comment: It appears to me that Scratch is just Python in plain text with colors...

Comment: And 1-indexed arrays and no elif statements!

Comment: Good point @Christoph! It was part of an earlier version that got golfed out. Editing.

Comment: I also found a bug I fixed. Inputting `[5,6,5]` would produce `[5,6,5,1]`

Answer (score 4):

## C#, <s>123</s> <s>121</s> <s>120</s> <s>79</s> 77 bytes

```
using System.Linq;l=>{if(l.All(o=>o==l[0]))l.Add(0);l[l.IndexOf(l.Min())]++;}
```

Modifies the argument passed to the function.

Thanks to [Cyoce](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41042/cyoce) for saving 3 bytes! -> `!Any` to `All`, `+=1` to `++`.

Thanks to [TheLethalCoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38550/thelethalcoder) for saving a whopping 43 bytes! -> Removed method signature code.
Removed parenthesis around the parameter list.

Comment: could you replace `!l.Any(o=>o!=l[0]))` with `l.All(o=>o==l[0])`?

Comment: @Cyoce It indeed does. I thought of the same thing, but wrote `Any` instead of `All` and was in the thought, that it doesn't work :D Thanks!

Comment: Does C# not have `++`?

Comment: You can compile to a `Action<List<int>>` to remove all of the method signature code

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Thanks! Now compiles to an `Action<List<int>>`.

Comment: @TuukkaX You can remove the parenthesis around the action argument i.e. `(l)=>` to `l=>` to save another 2 bytes

Comment: I'n not sure, but I think you can drop the `using` and just use the lambda, I've seen (and done) it already quite often. That would lead to 59 bytes ;)

Comment: @Stefan Hmm. I've also seen many people drop the necessary `using`s with C#, so I don't trust that it's legal to drop `using System.Linq` off. Unless I see an explicit statement that says this isn't necessary, I'll stay with this. Thanks for the suggestion though! :)

Answer (score 4):

### J, <s>25</s> 22 bytes

```
(+~:*[=<./)@,0#~1=#@~.
```

Evaluates to an anonymous verb.
[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@mYGuloKFdZ6UVbWujp6/poGOgXGdoq@xQp/c/NTkjXyFNQUfBkAvONIIxDRGixjCIkIMrM0JWhqLHRMESocMEG9cExjWFcP8DAA)

### Explanation

```
(+~:*[=<./)@,0#~1=#@~.  Input is y.
                  #@    Is the length of
                    ~.   deduplicated y
                1=       equal to 1?
            ,0#~        Append that many 0s to y (one or none).
(         )@            Call the result z and apply this verb to it:
      =                  take the bit array of equality
     [                   between z
       <./               and its minimum element,
    *                    multiply that element-wise by
  ~:                     the bit array of first occurrences in z
 +                       and add the result to z.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>72 66</s> 65 bytes

```r
"if"(any((x=scan())-x[1]),"[<-"(x,u<-which.min(x),1+x[u]),c(x,1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/XykzTUkjMa9SQ6PCtjg5MU9DU1O3ItowVlNHKdpGV0mjQqfURrc8IzM5Qy83M0@jQlPHULsiuhQonwyUM9TU/G@kYKRg/B8A)

Increment is done using `which.min` which returns the first match. `"[<-"` allows to replace the value and returns the modified vector in one function call.

-7 bytes thanks to Giuseppe!

Comment: https://tio.run/##K/r/XykzTUmjuDRXQ6PCtjg5MU9DU7PGUNPOUK04RaNCU0cp2kZXSaNCp9RGtzwjMzlDLzczDyRuqF0RXRqrqZMMlDPU1Pxv9B8A

Comment: @Giuseppe I tried isTRUE and isFALSE with sd it isn’t golfier :(

Comment: heh, [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/XykzTUkjMa9SQ6PCtjg5MU9DU1O3ItowVlNHKdpGV0mjQqfURrc8IzM5Qy83M0@jQlPHULsiuhQonwyUM9TU/G@kYKRg/B8A) replacing `!=` with `-`!

Comment: @Giuseppe of course!

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 48 bytes

```apl
f←{1≥≢∪⍵:⍵,1⋄1+@(⊃⍋⍵)⊢⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24Rqw0edSx91LnrUsepR71YrINYxfNTdYqjtoPGoq/lRbzdQRPNR1yIgVQvUoWDIBcRQ0ghIGikYQ9gKxgomYD6MZQyWAZIKhgA)

Alternate versions of `1+@(⊃⍋⍵)⊢⍵`: `⍵+(⍳≢⍵)=⊃⍋⍵`, `⊢+⍳∘≢=⊃∘⍋`. -2 thanks to @Adam and @Razetime.

Explanation:

```apl
{1≥≢∪⍵:⍵,1⋄1+@(⊃⍋⍵)⊢⍵}
 1≥≢∪⍵                   ⍝ if all elements are identical
       ⍵,1               ⍝ then yield ⍵ with 1 appended to the end.
          ⋄              ⍝ ... else,
              (⊃⍋⍵)      ⍝ index of the smallest value
           1+@     ⊢⍵    ⍝ increment the value from ⍵
```

Comment: `=/1 2 2` gives `1`.

Comment: `⍵+(⍳≢⍵)=⊃⍋⍵` → `1+@(⊃⍋⍵)⊢⍵`

Comment: @Adám fixed; thanks

Comment: you don't need the `∘`

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 16 bytes

```
t&=?1h}t2#X<wQw(
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dCY9PzFofXQyI1g8d1F3KA&input=WzMsMSwxXQ) Or [verify all test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=IkBnCnQmPT8xaH10MiNYPHdRdyg&input=e1sxXSBbMl0gWzEsIDFdIFszLCAzLCAzLCAzLCAzXSBbMSwyXSBbMiwxXSBbMywxLDFdIFszLCA0LCA5LCAzXX0)

#### How it works

```
t         % Take input implicitly. Duplicate
&=        % Matrix of all pairwise equality comparisons
?         % If all comparisons were true
  1h      %   Append 1 to the original copy ofthe array
}         % Else
  t       %   Duplicate array
  2#X<    %   Push minimum and index of its first occurrence
  wQw     %   Swap, increment, swap (adds 1 to the minimum)
  (       %   Assign the incremented minimum to that position
          % End if implicitly. Display implicitly
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 46 bytes

```perl6
{.[[==]($_)??.elems!!.first(*==.min,:k)]++;$_}
```

(modifies the input Array, and returns it)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{     # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  .[      # use the following as an index into the array

      [==]( $_ )    # reduce the array with ｢&infix:<==>｣

    ??              # if they are equal

      .elems        # the value past the end ( ｢.end+1｣ would also work )

    !!              # else

      .first(       # find the first value
        * == .min,  # where the element is equal to the minimum
        :k          # return the key rather than the value
      )

  ]++;              # increment it ( auto vivifies if it doesn't exist )

  $_                # return the modified array
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 56 bytes

```
±{b:a_ ..}:={b,1};±a_:=a/.{p___,b:Min@a,q___}:>{p,b+1,q}
```

Uses named function `±`. Uses ISO8859-1 encoding

**Alternative solutions (58 bytes)**

```
±{b:a_ ..}:={b,1};±{p___,b_,q___}/;b<=p~Min~q:={p,b+1,q}
(* @GregMartin and I both independently came up with this above solution *)

±{b:a_ ..}:={b,1};±a:{p___,b_,q___}/;b==Min@a:={p,b+1,q}
```

**Usage**

```
±{1, 1}
```

> `{1, 1, 1}`

```
±{3, 4, 5}
```

> `{4, 4, 5}`

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>71 70</s> 62 bytes

```
f(a:b)|(x,y:z)<-span=<<(<).minimum$a:b++[0|all(a==)b]=x++y+1‌​:z
```

@Zgarb saved 8 bytes, thanks!

When I started I hoped for some elegant tying-the-knot trickery, but @Zgarb's way is just as amazing.

Comment: Some restructuring, 62 bytes: `f(a:b)|(x,y:z)<-span=<<(<).minimum$a:b++[0|all(a==)b]=x++y+1:z`

Comment: @Zgarb Just wow!

Comment: Ugh, my brain fails to infer the type for the monad instance of functions

Comment: @Angs The Monad is `(->)r`, which applied to a type is `(->)r a = r->a`. Then from the types `return:: a->r->a` and `(>>=)::(r->a)->(a->r->b)->(r->b)` their implementation is (dare I say it?) obvious: `return=const` and `m>>=f = \r->f(m r)r`. The latter is exactly what is needed to express something like `span(predicate_depending_on l)l` while mentioning `l` only once. Now I only need to remember it when I need it.

Comment: @Angs You can find this trick, and many more, in our [Haskell golf tips collection](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/tips-for-golfing-in-haskell).

Answer (score 3):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 63 bytes

```
a=b=1{for(;$++a;d=$b==$a&&c==$a?a+1:b)b=(c=$b)>$a?a:b;$d++}++NF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v8/0TbJ1rA6Lb9Iw1pFWzvROsVWJcnWViVRTS0ZRNknahtaJWkm2WokAyU07UAiVknWKina2rXa2n5u//9bKpgAoTEA)

The code scans all the numbers presented on the input line and sets variable, `d`, to the position of the smallest number, or to the number of fields plus one if all values are equal.  Then it increments the number at that position and prints everything.  As a result it either adds a new field with a value of 1 or increments the smallest number in the given set of numbers.

The first condition/test is always true, and just does some initialization.

```
a=b=1
```

The code block is a `for` loop, which applies one statement to each number from the input line.

```
for(;$++a;d=$b==$a&&c==$a?a+1:b)b=(c=$b)>$a?a:b
```

The check to continue iterating just increments the `a` "current field" variable and stops when it's gets a 0 (by running off the end of the list).

```
    $++a
```

The body of the loop updates `b` such that it's always pointing to the position of the smallest number in the input.  The code also has to save the previous position of the smallest number, stored in `c`, to deal with cases where the minimum is the last number on the line.

```
    b=(c=$b)>$a?a:b
```

The "end of loop" statement sets variable `d` to the current field "plus one" if the current value matches the current minimum as well as the previous minimum, or to the position of the current minimum otherwise.

```
    d=$b==$a&&c==$a?a+1:b
```

One the loop completes, the code increments whichever field `d` points to.  If all the fields are the same, it will increment an uninitialized field, which in AWK will default to 0.  Otherwise it will increment the first field with the smallest value.

```
$d++
```

The second condition/test just increments the number of fields in the input line, which will always evaluate to true.  If all the fields were the same numeric value, that change in `NF` will cause a `1` to be appended to the list.  And if it changed one of the presented fields the additional field printed as a result of incrementing `NF` will be an empty string.

```
++NF
```

Answer (score 2):

## Jelly, 9 bytes

```
;1µ‘i¦E?Ṃ
```

Thanks to Dennis for the -2 bytes.

Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered ... .

Comment: If you have extra characters to enter in the body, it's always worth explaining the code, which helps everyone to understand it and makes the answer more interesting :)

Answer (score 2):

**Mathematica, <strike>53 bytes</strike> <strike>57 bytes</strike> 59 bytes**

```
If[Equal@@#,#~Join~{1},x=#;x[[#~FirstPosition~Min@#]]++;x]&
```

Comment: That's 57 bytes. `〚` and `〛` are a 3-byte characters. Also, your code does not work because `{##,1}` part implies that the input is separate integers (i.e. `f[1, 2, 3]`) but the `x=#` part implies that the input is a `List` (i.e. `f[{1, 2, 3}]`). A quick fix would be to change `x=#` to `x={#}` and accept raw integers as input, making your code 59 bytes long.

Comment: Good catch! I didn't realize the distinction between bytes and character count, I just saw  [this suggestion](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12930/61980) and figured it was valid. It seems there are a lot of answers that give the character count but if I save them in Notepad++ I get a higher byte count (for example the Jelly answer). I see your answer specifies an encoding, is there somewhere you'd recommend for me to learn about this?

Comment: I think you mean `Equal@#`, although `#==##` is shorter.

Comment: You're right. I made a change per @JHM to accept multiple arguments rather than a list but didn't propagate the change everywhere. I've gone back to accepting a list since that is more in line with the prompt.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 85 + 38 = 123 bytes

Void lambda taking a `List<Integer>` (output is mutated input). Byte count includes lambda and required import.

```java
import static java.util.Collections.*;
```

```java
l->{if(min(l)==max(l))l.add(0);int i=0,n;while((n=l.get(i))>min(l))i++;l.set(i,n+1);}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##hVFda8IwFH1uf8VFEJIZg@7jYastDJ8G25OPw4esRnddmpYk1Yn0t7vYdtSJ2yAk5NxzT87JXYuNGOaF1OvFxwGzIjcOrBMOU1j7Ei8dKj7NlZKpw1xbfhWFYVG@KU9IlbAWXgRq2IdBC7bNS9RCnUgsS10LeC1ty0yaSVd7RusmT9rJlTRJAqhTIzPp7wbigxome1ySDDVRNI4z8elPqrhYLMiIRqgdYDxiOtq@o5KE6FjxlXQEKU2aJoqDQaS4PYJMD8Y0qg6BT3HmeJPjAjIfhsycQb16nYMwK0uP2YLW3evco6mw0kIMWm7hFD/ygh8g7McVu4DeMOjWRcY1g8utdwxuGdz7vS5Xkd@WuQHSccTUG4SHxmdjP/jls/1fF6Vrs3ScR2PEriYm5Ay1XNhjhdSvUBr9pZ6X7j/52kCjcjJ3LtJUFo40Ak15trNOZtxDvPDzcep7UNznz4Qjvb6FYQJ922NNLtYaaFxWoV9VePgC)

This almost looks like Python with those method imports...

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 63 bytes

```r
`if`(any((v=scan())-v[1]),{v[m]=v[m<-which.min(v)]+1;v},c(v,1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY5BCoMwFET3OUWwm/@pFkQ3rc1JRDDEiIH6LRpTRDx7mlJKF8VFGZjFGxje6H1t2hokLQBOTEoSICauTCuMV1f2lQh1TR6dUd2pNwQOq2NauC1W4OIU0Wc8hLEDH3WjW0Oay4m3MylrBuJ24ONMYbtraXVzWy7MkBKfHSyu7MfACvufBNuYpEmEZ4hePmeeRVgE9MX5Hs73cf7G/gk)

Had a shot at this without peeking at the [previous R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166251/95126) first.

Although the overall approaches are pretty similar, this pleasingly comes-out 2 bytes shorter.

Here we use a code block (enclosed in curly brackets `{}`) as an expression, which allows us to adjust a chosen element of the input vector `v`, and let the expression evaluate to the new value of `v`.
Shorter, but less fancy than the [previous approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166251/95126) of abusing the indexing operator `[<-` as a function (which definitely deserves an upvote anyway).

Comment: I believe the `sd` trick will fail with length-one input since `sd(1)` returns `NA`, which R complains can't be interpreted as a `logical`.

Comment: Thanks @Giuseppe - I didn't think of that.  Rolled-back.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `aW`, <s><sup>21</sup></s> 18 bytes

*-3 bytes by using the register instead of variables.*

```
:≈[1J|:g£(nn¥=[›0£
```

[Try it Online With Equal Elements!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=aW&code=%3A%E2%89%88%5B1J%7C%3Ag%C2%A3%28nn%C2%A5%3D%5B%E2%80%BA0%C2%A3&inputs=2%0A2%0A2%0A2%0A2%0A2&header=&footer=)

[Try it Online With Unequal Elements!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=aW&code=%3A%E2%89%88%5B1J%7C%3Ag%C2%A3%28nn%C2%A5%3D%5B%E2%80%BA0%C2%A3&inputs=5%0A6%0A1%0A2%0A4%0A3&header=&footer=)

Explanation:

```
                    # Implicit input; a flag takes input as list
:                   # Duplicate input
 ≈[1J               # If all elements are equal: append 1
     |:g£           # Else: save minimum value to the register
         (          # For every element in the input:
          n         # Duplicate current element n
           n¥=[     # If current element n == register value:
               ›0£  # Increment current element and clear the register
                    # Implicit output; W flag outputs full stack
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%89%88%5B1J%7Cg%E2%82%8C%E1%B8%9F%E2%80%BA%C8%A6&inputs=%5B5%2C%202%2C%203%5D&header=&footer=) in 10 bytes. I came up with my answer independently, but they are very similar. For the case of unequal numbers, finds the index and increment of the min, and then sets that position of the input to that.

Comment: @Underslash You should post that as your own answer! This is a much better method than I came up with at the time.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>20</s> 17 bytes

```
=,1|iᶠo{+₁ʰ}ʰtᵒhᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATQAy/9icmFjaHlsb2cy//89LDF8aeG2oG97K@KCgcqwfcqwdOG1kmjhtZD//1syLDEsMywxXf9Y)

#### Explanation

The first case is easy. The second is less so.

```
=,1|iᶠo{+₁ʰ}ʰtᵒhᵐ
=                  Assert that all elements are equal
 ,1                Append 1
   |               If that failed, try the following instead:
    iᶠ             Get a list of [value, index] pairs for every item in the array
      o            Sort: put smallest value first, and smallest index for equal values
       {   }ʰ      Apply this predicate to the first element of the resulting list:
        +₁ʰ          Add 1 to its first element (first occurrence of min value)
             tᵒ    Sort by the second element of each sublist (index)
               hᵐ  Head of each sublist (value)
```

Here's a worked example of the second branch:

```
               Input: [2,3,1,5,1]
iᶠ             [[2,0], [3,1], [1,2], [5,3], [1,4]]
  o            [[1,2], [1,4], [2,0], [3,1], [5,3]]
   {+₁ʰ}ʰ      [[2,2], [1,4], [2,0], [3,1], [5,3]]
         tᵒ    [[2,0], [3,1], [2,2], [5,3], [1,4]]
           hᵐ  [2,3,2,5,1]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
{⍵+<\⍵=⌊/⍵}⊢,0~⍬≡⊢~⊃
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pR71Ztmxggafuop0sfSNc@6lqkY1D3qHfNo86FQHbdo67m/2mP2iY86u171DfV0x/IP7Te@FHbRCAvOMgZSIZ4eAb/1wDpU3/UNkld59CKtEMrNB/1rtJ41LnoUe8WoIzmo44ZQAMOrVC3VgeKLnjU1QYSVTe0NrI2VDC0NlaAQiDPyNoILAIRN1GwVDBWBwA)

First we append a zero if the input is unique, then increment the first minimum (which will be the trailing zero in the unique case, as the numbers in the input are positive)

`⊢~⊃` Input without all occurences of the first element.
`⍬≡` Is this the empty vector? (are values in the input the same)
`0~` 0 without the result of that (a single 0 if all values are the same, empty vector otherwise)
`⊢,` Append this to the input

`{⍵+<\⍵=⌊/⍵}` Increment the first minimum.
`⌊/⍵` Minimum value
`⍵=` Boolean vector with 1's at all minima
`<\` Less-than scan; only leaves the first 1
`⍵+` Add this boolean vector to the previous vector

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ạ?1a:MçȮ⁺Ẹȧ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWWx7uWmhvmGjle3j5iXWPGnc93LXjxPIlxUnJxVAFC5aa6hjpGEM4AA)

##### Explanation

```python
ạ?1a:MçȮ⁺Ẹȧ  # Implicit input
ạ            # Is it all equal?
 ?           # If it is:
  1a         #  Append a 1
    :        # Otherwise:
     M       #  Take the minimum
      ç  Ẹ   #  Parallely apply:
       Ȯ     #   Index of the minimum
        ⁺    #   Increment the minimum
          ȧ  #  Assign the new value
             # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 45 bytes

```r
\(x)`if`(sd(c(x,x)),x+!rank(x,,"f")-1,c(x,1))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3dWM0KjQTMtMSNIpTNJI1KnQqNDV1KrQVixLzsoE8HaU0JU1dQx2QjKGmJlRTeZqGoSZXmoYRiEjWMARJQVlGUJYRXMwILmasA4ZwnomOJZxngoVnAuWZwngQ6xcsgNAA)

This would be 4 bytes longer as a full program, which is a fairer comparison to [earlier](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223872/78274) [answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166251/78274) that had been posted when backslash functions were not yet a thing, and full program was a golfier approach:

### [R](https://www.r-project.org), 49 bytes

```r
`if`(sd(c(x<-scan(),x)),x+!rank(x,,"f")-1,c(x,1))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMHGNNsYjUyd4uTEPCBDM1OzemlpSZquxU3DhMy0BI3iFI1kjQobXZC8hqZOhSYQaysWJeZla1To6CilKWnqGuoAVegYampCNVbWcqVpGGoCCSMQkaxhCJKEsoygLCO4mBFczFgHDOE8Ex1LOM8EC88EyjOF8SAOWLAAQgMA)

Comment: `order` appears to be stable so should be equivalent to `rank`

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, <s>69</s> <s>67</s> 64 bytes

It was actually shorter to make this a complete named function than using both `input` and `disp`.

Saved 3 bytes thanks to Luis.

```
function x=f(x)
[a,b]=min(x);if any(x-a),x(b)++;else x=[x,1];end
```

Old answer, not using a function:

```
[a,b]=min(x=input(''));if any(x-a),x(b)++;else x(end+1)=1;end;disp(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 46 bytes

```
->a{a.uniq.size<2?a<<1:a[a.index(a.min)]+=1;a}
```

I feel like there's a better way to check if all elements are the same than `a.uniq.size<2`, but I'm too lazy to find it.

Comment: `a.uniq[1]` will be truthy iff there are distinct values.

Comment: You can save a byte by turning `a[a.index(a.min)]` into `a[a.index a.min]`

Answer (score 1):

### R, 97 bytes

```
if(all((a=scan())==a[1])){a=c(a,1)}else{while(!all(a==a[1])){a[which(a==min(a))][1]=min(a)+1}};a
```

Too bad that the synthax `x=+1` doesn't exist in R !

**Ungolfed :**

```
if(all((a=scan())==a[1]))
{
    a=c(a,1)
}
else
{
    while(!all(a==a[1]))
    {
        a[which(a==min(a))][1]=min(a)+1
    }
a
```

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab, <s>83</s>, <s>77</s>, 71 Bytes

```
function a=x(a)
if~nnz(a-a(1));a=[a,1];else[~,I]=min(a);a(I)=a(I)+1;end
```

I'm relatively new to code golf so please be kind! I tried to use anonymous functions but googling says you can't use if/else statements and matlab doesn't have ternary operators, so this is the best i felt I could do.

Edit: Corrected and shortened (twice!) thanks to stewie-griffin.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! There are some flaws in this code. `sum(a)/length(a)==a(1)` doesn't guarantee that all elements are equal, it only shows that the average is equal to `a(1)`. A simpler way to do this would be `mean(a)==a(1)`. `numel` is one byte shorter than `length`, but since you know all values are positive, you can use `nnz` which is even shorter (it would still not give the correct result in this challenge, but it's shorter at least :P ). If you take the `min(a)` call in front of the loop, you may use both outputs from it and check is `all` elements of `a` are equal to `min(a)`.

Comment: You are right! it fails when the mean is equal the number in the first element. I think my new one is correct though and also shorter. The logic is that if the remaining elements don't equal the first element, a(a~=a(1)) returns the remaining elements which by definition is greater than 0 in a non-same array. Then counting and not should give the correct logic I think. If it's still wrong please let me know, I've only been coding for a few years and I still have a long ways left.

Comment: `~nnz(a(a~=a(1)))` is simply `~nnz(a-a(1))`. Also, you don't need the parentheses. `if ~nnz(a-a(1));a=[a,1];else[~,I]=min(a);a(I)=a(I)+1;end`. This should be 5 bytes shorter (note: I haven't tested it).

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by using `range(a)` instead of `nnz(a-a(1))`

Comment: @boboquack, that code checks if the number of elements in `a` is equal to the lowest value in that vector. A vector `a = [3 4 6]` will result in `true`, and a vector `a = [4 4 6]` will result in `false`. I don't think that will be useful here...?

Comment: @StewieGriffin sorry, misread the comments. Max(a)==min(a)?

Comment: `max(a)==min(a)` will give `true` if all elements have the same value and false if not, so that would work. But it's quite long... :)

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 53 bytes

```
If min(not(ΔList(Ans
Then
Ans->L1
cumSum(1 or Ans
min(Ans+ᴇ9(L1≠min(L1
L1(Ans)+1->L1(Ans
Else
augment(Ans,{1
End
```

Answer (score 1):

## **MATLAB, <s>69</s> 67 bytes**

```
function a=f(a);if~range(a)a=[a 1];else[~,j]=min(a);a(j)=a(j)+1;end
```

`range(a)` is non-zero if not all elements are equal, and `[~,j]=min(a)` assigns the index of the minimum value in a to j, defaulting to the first value it finds. Input is a row vector. Saved 2 bytes by reversing the if/else logic to get rid of some semicolons (`else[~,j]` is legal, but `elsea=[a 1]` is not).

Answer (score 1):

**Clojure, <s>112</s> 100 bytes**

Unfortunately `min-key` returns the last index of the smallest index, not the first one. This works for integer inputs and shorter arrays than 10^9 elements ;)

Edit: Defining an anonymous function, using `(apply = a)` instead of `(= 1(count(set a)))`.

```
(fn[a](if(apply = a)(conj a 1)(update a(apply min-key #(+(nth a %)(* % 1e-9))(range(count a)))inc)))
```

Original:

```
(defn f[a](if(= 1(count(set a)))(conj a 1)(update a(apply min-key #(+(nth a %)(* % 1e-9))(range(count a)))inc)))
```

A less hacky 134-byte solution reverses the vector before updating it and then reverse it back again:

```
(defn f[a](if(= 1(count(set a)))(conj a 1)(let[r #(vec(reverse %))a(r a)](r(update a(apply min-key #(nth a %)(range(count a)))inc)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, <s>66</s> 53 bytes

```
if(range(a))[~,b]=min(a);a(b)=a(b)+1;else;a=[a 1];end
```

Output:

Initialize:

```
a = [3 2]
```

Successive runs:

```
[3 2] -> [3 3] -> [3 3 1] -> [3 3 2] -> [3 3 3] -> [3 3 3 1] ...
```

Comment: You cannot hardcode the inputs, you'd need to do something like `@(x) …`.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC 3, 101 bytes

Defines a statement function `I A` where `A` is our integer array of numbers. Output is achieved by modifying the input (as arrays are references.)

```
DEF I A
M=MIN(A)IF M==MAX(A)THEN PUSH A,1RETURN
FOR C=0TO LEN(A)IF M==A[C]THEN INC A[C]BREAK
NEXT
END
```

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by replacing `BREAK` with `M=0`, because `A` can't contain `0` so `M==A[C]` will never be true.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 77 bytes

```
DEF I A
IF MIN(A)==MAX(A)THEN PUSH A,0
WHILE A[I]>MAX(A)I=I+1WEND
INC A[I]END
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 24 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{(x[x?&/x]+:1;x,1)1=#?x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWqMiusJeTb8iVtvK0LpCx1DT0FbZvqL2f5q6ho6htY6RtaGCobWxAhQCeUbWRmARiLiJgqWCseZ/AA)

**Explanation:**

Nothing too fancy, potentially golfable further:

```
{(x[x?&/x]+:1;x,1)1=#?x} / the solution
{                      } / anonymous lambda taking implicit x argument
                     ?x  / get distinct values in x
                    #    / count length
                  1=     / is it 1?
 (           ;   )       / two item list which is index into
              x,1        / append 1 to input
  x[     ]+:1            / modify x in-place (add 1) at index given in []
      &/x                / minimum of x
    x?                   / lookup index (returns first one)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes

```
≈[1J|g₌ḟ›Ȧ  # main program
```

```
≈           # all elements in input are equal
 [1J|g₌ḟ›Ȧ  # main if statement
  1J        # if true, append 1 to input
     g₌ḟ›Ȧ  # if false...
     g      # get the minimum
      ₌ḟ›   # push the index of the min and the increment of the min
         Ȧ  # set that index to the increment
            # implicit output
```

I came up with this independently but surprisingly it was pretty similar in structure to @AaronMiller's answer.
[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%89%88%5B1J%7Cg%E2%82%8C%E1%B8%9F%E2%80%BA%C8%A6&inputs=%5B5%2C%202%2C%203%5D&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 55 bytes

```js
a=>a.every(e=>e==a[0])?a.push(1):a.fill(Math.max(...a))
```

Modifies the array passed to it, otherwise, it's 3 bytes longer:

```js
a=>a.every(e=>e==a[0])?a.push(1)&&a:a.fill(Math.max(...a))
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##RY9BT8MwDIXPza@wdiGRsoxuMDGklAPiggQc4Fb1YBVnK@qSKskGFeK3lzRCQu/gz7b8nvyBZwyt74a4tO6dJqMn1BUqOpMfOemKtMb6shF3qIZTOPBS3KIyXd/zJ4wHdcQvrpRCIabW2RDhjUK8x0ABNNSsqMtGQirrRs6NXMtNpk2iMtON3Mpdpit5nbT9m25mZd7JpIY1jBnneUwB4Mx/kIBvVsTjkAIfX1@e1YA@EM8You/svjNjvhICVit4sOHkCbp4EQDB0ieg9zhKsC6mgSdDnmxLrDA8uQpWzI@5nlTv9tlHLpbVQubdz/QL)

### Explanation

```js
a=>a.every          // Check that every element "e"...
  (e=>e==a[0])      // ...is equal to the first element.
    ?a.push(1)      // If it's the case push 1 at the end.
      :a.fill       // Else fill the entire array...
        (Math.max   // ...with the biggest...
          (...a))   // ...entry of the array.
```

#### Some notable parts

- Checking the first element of the array is valid because all of the elements needs to be the same anyways
- If the array have different elements, it will end up being an array filled with the largest number anyways, so let's do directly that

Comment: Looks like you're expected to only do one iterate `[3, 4, 9, 3] -> [4, 4, 9, 3]` not to the end

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>76</s> 60 bytes

```powershell
$x,$y=($a=$args)|sort -u
$a[$a.IndexOf(+$x)]+=!!$y
$a+,1*!$y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHfb4IwEMff@1ecpBswyhIrPuyBBbNkiU8uY2/GLBXrfgTFUchw6t/OziIgLmuapv1@7r53zW2Sb5mqdxnHJV2CD7uSFoxufYsKn4r0Tdl7laQZuDmhYkrF7Xi9kMVkaTm0sGeO3@vRLRKH9W/wVh4IIYFFmBVYfZsBngz6tq0FrgXeCprVQa08YNBuzTtKJ7/x5HWR2vNMG5zsT1a8U4p3Ce8Qflaed9o7J4OWeAzu6q699llx7x/uXXJP8@ElH/7hw4bbsIcr2BHAhXNLxZYBlcVGRplc4Fzpa4VSqfI4Q@Eaxx3oQA2mT@FDrrJkNZl/Ys4sqKyOK8yjSCqFOcYp3QBXfuGr9jea2NHRUEdq6xaY43VkIjDde7MRn@tmGmONDuSAv3lM0pXI3BcxjyW4ozxLwo8fWf4C)

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 19 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
(⍜⊡'+1⊢⍏.|⊂∶1)≍↻1..
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAgKOKNnOKKoScrMeKKouKNjy584oqC4oi2MSniiY3ihrsxLi4KCmYgWzFdCmYgWzJdCmYgWzEgMV0KZiBbMyAzIDMgMyAzXQpmIFsxIDJdCmYgWzIgMV0KZiBbMyAxIDFdCmYgWzMgNCA5IDNdCg==)

```
(⍜⊡'+1⊢⍏.|⊂∶1)≍↻1..
                  .  # duplicate
              ≍↻1.   # are all elements equal?
(        |   )       # run the left part if not, or right part if so
          ⊂∶1        # append 1 to end
        .            # duplicate
      ⊢⍏             # index of minimum element
 ⍜⊡'+1               # increment value at that index
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 50 bytes

```
If[Equal@@#,Append@1,1+#&~MapAt~#&@@Ordering@#]@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zMt2rWwNDHHwUFZx7GgIDUvxcFQx1BbWa3ON7HAsaROWc3Bwb8oJbUoMy/dQTnWQVntfwCQXRKtrGuXBhRQqwtOTsyrq@aqNqzV4ao2AhFAA0CUsQ4UQsTAUkYwKbgaEx1LoAqu2v8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 14 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⬚0+⍘⊚?⧻⊢≍,⊃⍖⍏.
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4qyaMCvijZjiipriipfDty_ihqXiiaAsLC_ihqcuLgoKZiDihpAg4qyaMCvijZjiipriiqLijY8u4oqC4oi24oqa4omN4oa7MS4uCmYg4oaQIOKsmjAr4o2Y4oqa4oalw5fiioPiioPiiY3ip7viiqLiioPijY_ijZYuCmYg4oaQIOKsmjAr4o2Y4oqaP-KnuyfiiqLijY_iiY3ihrsxLi4uCmYg4oaQIOKsmjAr4o2Y4oqaP-Knu-KKouKJjSziioPijZbijY8uCgpmLmYuZi5mLmYgNF8zXzlfMwpmIDNfM18zXzNfMwo=)

Finds the 0-based index to increment (or the length if the elements are all equal), and adds 1 at that index. The `⍏` (rise; the indices in the array that would put the values in sorted order) is reused three times:

- "all equal" test can be done with "rise matches fall"
- "the first index of minimum element" is "first of rise"
- "the length of the array" is the same as "the length of rise"

```
⬚0+⍘⊚?⧻⊢≍,⊃⍖⍏.    input: an array of positive integers A
            ⊃⍖⍏.   push fall(A), rise(A), A
          ≍,         keep rise(A) and evaluate "rise(A) == fall(A)"
      ?⧻⊢            if so, call length; otherwise call first on rise(A)
    ⍘⊚              inverse where; create an array B so that B[i] == count of i
                     (3 -> [0, 0, 0, 1])
⬚0+                  elementwise add the result to A, padding with zeros if needed
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 16 bytes

```
?tl{QXxQhSQQ1+Q1
```

A program that takes input of a list and prints the result.

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3Ftl%7BQXxQhSQQ1%2BQ1&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%5D%0A%5B2%5D%0A%5B1%2C+1%5D%0A%5B3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%5D%0A%5B2%2C+1%5D%0A%5B3%2C+1%2C+1%5D%0A%5B3%2C+4%2C+9%2C+3%5D&debug=0)

**How it works**

```
?tl{QXxQhSQQ1+Q1  Program. Input: Q
?                 If:
  l                The length
   {Q              of Q deduplicated
 t                 - 1
                   is non-zero:
     X     Q1       Increment in Q at index:
      xQ             Index in Q of
        h            the first element
         SQ          of Q sorted (minimum)
                  else:
             +     Append
               1   1
              Q    to Q
                   Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 93 bytes

`f z|and$(==)<$>z<*>z=z++[1]|1>0=z#minimum z where(x:z)#m|x==m=x+1:z;(x:z)#m|1>0=x:z#m;[]#_=[]`

**Ungolfed:**

```haskell
incrementArray :: [Int] -> [Int]
incrementArray xs | and [x == y | x <- xs, y <- xs] = xs ++ [1]
                  | otherwise = g xs (minimum xs)
     where g (x:xs) m | x == m = (x + 1):xs
           g (x:xs) m | otherwise = x:g xs m
           g [] _ = []
```

Initial attempt, will try to come up with something more sophisticated later.

Comment: Why not make a separate function instead of using `where`?

Answer (score 0):

## [Wonder](https://github.com/wonderlang/wonder), 44 bytes

```
@[dp1unq#0?:=#[:0(iO f\min#0)#0+1f]#0?++#0 1
```

This is not what I had in mind when I made this language... It's literally worse than Perl in terms of readability!

Usage:

```
(@[dp1unq#0?:=#[:0(iO f\min#0)#0+1f]#0?++#0 1])[3 4 9 3]
```

## Explanation

More readable:

```
@[
  dp 1 unq #0
    ? set #[
            get 0 (iO f\ min #0) #0
            + 1 f
           ] #0
    ? con #0 1
 ]
```

Basically checks if dropping 1 item from the unique subset of the argument makes the list empty. If not, then we increment the minimum of the array. Otherwise, we simply concatenate 1 to the argument.

Answer (score 0):

### Kotlin, 75 bytes

```
fun a(s:MutableList<Int>){if(s.toSet().size<2)s+=0;s[s.indexOf(s.min())]++}
```

Modifies the function argument.

Damn you strong typing! `:MutableList<Int>` accounts for 17 bytes alone. I don't think there is a solution where the type can be inferred, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

## jq, 44 characters

```
if unique[1]then.[index(min)]+=1else.+[1]end
```

Sample run (`-c` (`--compact-output`) option used only here for readability):

```
bash-4.3$ jq -c 'if unique[1]then.[index(min)]+=1else.+[1]end' <<< '[3,1,1]'
[3,2,1]

bash-4.3$ jq -c 'if unique[1]then.[index(min)]+=1else.+[1]end' <<< '[3,2,1]'
[3,2,2]

bash-4.3$ jq -c 'if unique[1]then.[index(min)]+=1else.+[1]end' <<< '[3,2,2]'
[3,3,2]

bash-4.3$ jq -c 'if unique[1]then.[index(min)]+=1else.+[1]end' <<< '[3,3,2]'
[3,3,3]

bash-4.3$ jq -c 'if unique[1]then.[index(min)]+=1else.+[1]end' <<< '[3,3,3]'
[3,3,3,1]
```

On-line test:

- [[3,3,3,3,3]](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=if%20unique%5B1%5Dthen.%5Bindex(min)%5D%2b=1else.%2b%5B1%5Dend&j=%5B3,3,3,3,3%5D)
- [[3,4,9,3]](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=if%20unique%5B1%5Dthen.%5Bindex(min)%5D%2b=1else.%2b%5B1%5Dend&j=%5B3,4,9,3%5D)

Answer (score 0):

### Groovy - 45 bytes

A groovy closure which accepts a list of Integer as input - please note this modifies the input `List`.

`{o->(o-o[0])?o[o.indexOf(o.min())]+=1:o<<1;o}`

Test cases can be seen here:

http://ideone.com/9vRd9e

Alternative of 56 bytes if the code needs to work with `int[]` or `List<Integer>`:

`{o=it.toList();(o-o[0])?o[o.indexOf(o.min())]+=1:o<<1;o}`

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 79 bytes

```
function i($a){max($a)>($n=min($a))?$a[array_search($n,$a)]++:$a[]=1;return$a;}
```

I think this needs no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 18 bytes

The algorithm used in this answer is largely based on [Dennis' Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/101421/47581). Golfing suggestions welcome! [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@29t7etQqlxonetweK2Bw7mNhg6Fh5b@/x9tqmMMgbEA)

```
;;M@u#q;m@í0@α1@q¥
```

**Ungolfing**

```
      Implicit input a.
;;    Duplicate a twice.
M     Get the maximum of a.
@u#   Increment all of a and convert back to a list.
q;    Append max(a) to the end of a_plus_one, and duplicate. Call it b.
m@í   Get index of the minimum of b. Call it min_index.
        If all elements of a were equal, this is the maximum at the end.
        Else, it's somewhere else in the array.
0@α   Push a list of min_index zeroes.
1@q   Append a 1 to the end. Call this array c.
        This will increment at the desired index or otherwise append a 1.
¥     Pairwise add a and c to get our incremented array.
      Implicit return.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 114 bytes

```
proc I a {if [llength [set S [lsort -u $a]]]<2 {lappend a 1} {lset a [lsearch $a [set m [lindex $S 0]]] [incr m]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/BCoMwEETv@Yo5eC3U1B5a@gOePVoPIaZViDFohELIt9td1B5KCJndecNugrbr6qdRo4RC7F@orTXuHTrUswmoqJ7HKeC0IFNN0zwkolXeG9dSIE9UMaeYM2rSHWFbdKBW71rzQVbhTFHUvdMThial1Q7K80AR8ySipJuD1QX7SYJbbEg22DkI@XvlnpAbUODGwVj8qYLU9VCCVvZLmGnP@xN1yd9KYv0C)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=,reduce -pa`, <s>75</s> 68 bytes

```perl
$F[(grep$_-$F[0],@F)?reduce{$F[$a]>$F[$b]?$b:$a}0..$#F:@F]++;$_="@F"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1/FLVojvSi1QCVeF8g0iNVxcNO0L0pNKU1OrQYKqCTG2oGopFh7lSQrlcRaAz09FWU3Kwe3WG1ta5V4WyUHN6X//40VDBWMFUz@5ReUZObnFf/X9fXJLC6xsgotycyxhZj2X7cgMQcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.8](https://julialang.org), 44 bytes

```
!x=allequal(x) ? [x;1] : (x[argmin(x)]+=1;x)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZBBDoIwEEX3PcXAqsS6aIFEJcSDNF00EUxNrQol6V3csOFQbj2JBasEYzf_v5dM0pn7cOq0kn0_dLZebx4kcqXUurp1UmOXwB64K6iAHWDHZXM8K-O1WJW0cEmYedqqtS2UwBGngiDOCLAxaUjPk099zpUtKgs1XdQ01IzANlD2n7KR8l_KvyQQqi8NWFAGpv8i8O_aKGNxHMUEbDIbbXDs9_E28royh_emnyu9AA)

`allequal` requires julia 1.8 or later

Answer (score 0):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org), 49 bytes

```
y$i,<esc>:s/^\(,\d*\)\1*$/&,0
/\<<C-r>=min([<C-r>"])
\>
f0<C-a>|x
```

Takes the array as comma-separated integers in the buffer. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/v1IlU8cmtTjZzqpYPy5GQycmRStGM8ZQS0VfTceASz/GxsZZt8jONjczTyMazFSK1eSKseNKMwDyEu1qKv7/N9IxNtQx1jH8r1sGAA)

#### Explanation

```
y$i,<esc>
```

Yank the original list of integers; then insert an extra comma at the beginning.

```
:s/^\(,\d*\)\1*$/&,0<cr>
```

Using regex, determine if the entire line consists of the same number. If so, append `,0`.

```
/\<...\><cr>
```

Find the first match of `...` as a full word (`\<` and `\>` represent word boundaries, corresponding to `\b` in PCRE), where `...` is:

```
<C-r>=min([<C-r>"])<cr>
```

Using the expression register, calculate the minimum of the original list.

If the original list was heterogeneous, the cursor is now on the number we want to increment. If the original list was all equal, however, we want to increment the 0 at the end, so:

```
f0
```

Move to the next occurrence of `0` on the line. If there is no `0`, this does nothing.

```
<C-a>|x
```

Increment the number under the cursor. Go to the beginning of the line and delete the extra comma.

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 77 bytes

```
[ dup all-eq? [ 1 suffix ] [ dup [ ] infimum-by* 1 + swap pick set-nth ] if ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY65jsJAEERzvqJikJE4gl0ICBEJCSKyHPSaHjNi3B7mEPau@HbvcKulUrXeC0pRGRrX73eb7XqByjXRaqlQsbAjo38p6EY8TuyEDTyfI0vJ/tPG3AZHHjWFI6zjEDrrtAQsB4M/THBNOb3n5PnN3nd9KNOn9MIfcY7vm9bnOEQLMibj8wp54j4qpVsUeKA8NS1K17HOfrphEkbwF7KwujylsSGTNC85CkX/BSFrTYexR2mYXP8P)

Went through a bunch of different iterations of this. `tri` was shorter than stack shufflers, amazingly, when using `change-nth`, but locals were king. However, we can attain even fewer bytes by using `infimum-by*`, which places both the index and value of the smallest element on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>60</s> 56 bytes

```
$->a->([]=a--a\0)?->a++1[i:index a min a a\[i]:a\[i]+1a]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?EFj7yY)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 159 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU9Na4QwEL37Kx57SthdaehNO8IeC20vPZZSphrdtDG6MSwW8bfbaKE7DPPx3mM@hpItL93nly4Dntk46DFoVw049T2mJLmyRZ2dvOeft0cX3qm41aCFqZgqXaMRNnsyQ9hweSvJouVQnqeSB40xyy4wNUYiTlvjqBDjXsmI5v88FTE24iL/oA8qXoydc1MLTqs41rgypFa7JpyJlORsr6BtVDZRELp1s4x5u3JegCt7eBA2QNwfoKLLPAHqzkMYPByhEDqoOxkfRrRVXgsvt6b3xgXrhE/b79cQm0bsDtjJlZ2TZF5@AQ)

```scala
a=>{def g(l:List[Int]):List[Int]=l match{case x::q if x==a.min=>(x+1)::q;case x::q=>x::g(q);case _=>Nil};if(a.distinct.length==1)a:+1 else g(a.toList).toArray}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHLSsQwFN33Kw6zSrAOFnfVCrMU1I3gRlzETtqJpumQBqnIfHs9SQtW8RKS@zj3dTLUyqpp6l/fdB1wr4yDHoN2@wG74xFfWQbsdQPjaq877cLOe/UplPclkvp868KLXBuomAbKh7LojHviU4EZWxopEAu2wpohlLjjndJydCWoyJWPeRGFToX6sFQFajVojChLjANMQ7Wq0KG6gRhxhkLOof/QP0J0crZiHNhartEPxuK3EE1nwpzSzbaRhO2e45GbsLXateEQJ2F/RlBykgTVliXbhA59XC1fWJG0E21ZrJpFwjw8d545vsxR8MgrRpreQxhcn6NA6FFcyIWNCP/zN37e5eiNC9YJ0v7@GGi0YpNjI@Xc7ZRN0zc)

```scala
object Main extends App {

  def incrementArray(arr: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = {
    val minVal = arr.min
    def g(list: List[Int], m: Int): List[Int] = list match {
      case x :: xs if x == m => (x + 1) :: xs
      case x :: xs           => x :: g(xs, m)
      case Nil               => Nil
    }
    if (arr.distinct.length == 1) arr :+ 1
    else g(arr.toList, minVal).toArray
  }

  var r = Array(3, 1, 1);
  for (i <- 1 to 10) {
    r = incrementArray(r)
    println(r.mkString(", "))
  }

}
```