# A twist of a trivial sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence, number-theory

### Introduction

Consider a sequence of integers \$f\$ defined as follows:

1. \$f(2) = 2\$
2. If \$n\$ is an odd prime, then \$f(n) = \frac{f(n-1) + f(n+1)}2\$
3. If \$n = p\cdot q\$ is composite, then \$f(n) = f(p)\cdot f(q)\$

It's not very hard to see that \$f(n) = n\$ for every \$n \ge 2\$, and thus computing \$f\$ wouldn't be a very interesting challenge.
Let's make a twist to the definition: halve the first case and double the second case.
We get a new sequence \$g\$ defined as follows:

1. \$g(2) = 1\$
2. If \$n\$ is an odd prime, then \$g(n) = g(n-1) + g(n+1)\$
3. If \$n = p\cdot q\$ is composite, then \$g(n) = g(p)\cdot g(q)\$

### The task

Your task is to take an integer \$n \ge 2\$ as input, and produce \$g(n)\$ as output.
You don't have to worry about integer overflow, but you should be able to compute \$g(1025) = 81\$ correctly, and your algorithm should theoretically work for arbitrarily large inputs.

You can write a full program or a function.
The lowest byte count wins.

### Example

I claimed above that \$g(1025) = 81\$, so let's compute it by hand.
The prime factorization of **1025** gives

```
1025 = 5*5*41 => g(1025) = g(5)*g(5)*g(41)
```

Since **41** is prime, we get

```
g(41) = g(40) + g(42)
```

Next, we compute the prime factorizations of **40** and **42**:

```
40 = 2*2*2*5 => g(40) = g(2)*g(2)*g(2)*g(5) = g(5)
42 = 2*3*7 => g(42) = g(2)*g(3)*g(7) = g(3)*g(7)
```

For these small primes we get

```
g(3) = g(2) + g(4) = 1 + 1 = 2
g(5) = g(4) + g(6) = 1 + 2 = 3
g(7) = g(6) + g(8) = 2 + 1 = 3
```

This means that

```
g(41) = g(40) + g(42) = g(5) + g(3)*g(7) = 3 + 2*3 = 9
```

and

```
g(1025) = g(5)*g(5)*g(41) = 3*3*9 = 81
```

### Test cases

Here are the values of \$g\$ up to **50**.

```
2 -> 1
3 -> 2
4 -> 1
5 -> 3
6 -> 2
7 -> 3
8 -> 1
9 -> 4
10 -> 3
11 -> 5
12 -> 2
13 -> 5
14 -> 3
15 -> 6
16 -> 1
17 -> 5
18 -> 4
19 -> 7
20 -> 3
21 -> 6
22 -> 5
23 -> 7
24 -> 2
25 -> 9
26 -> 5
27 -> 8
28 -> 3
29 -> 9
30 -> 6
31 -> 7
32 -> 1
33 -> 10
34 -> 5
35 -> 9
36 -> 4
37 -> 11
38 -> 7
39 -> 10
40 -> 3
41 -> 9
42 -> 6
43 -> 11
44 -> 5
45 -> 12
46 -> 7
47 -> 9
48 -> 2
49 -> 9
50 -> 9
```

Comment: Eerily similar to [A002487](http://oeis.org/A002487), and yet not (different at `15, 21, 25, 29, 33, 41`, and a bunch more, but I can't find any real pattern to why.)

Comment: @GabrielBenamy Well, my sequence also satisfies `a(2*n) = a(n)`, and `a(2*n+1) = a(n) + a(n+1)` holds if `2*n+1` is prime. For many other odd numbers the sequences probably agree by coincidence.

Comment: Is returning *True* instead of **1** acceptable?

Comment: @Dennis the challenge is about evaluating a numeric function, not a decision problem, so I would assume not.

Comment: @Pavel There's [heavy support in favor](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9067/12012) though and, at least in Python, *True* acts like **1** for all intents and purposes.

Comment: @Dennis We'll go with the Meta consensus: `True` can be returned in place of `1` if it behaves as `1` in the language.

Answer (score 7):

### Haskell, 69 bytes

```
x#a|x<3=1|a>x=a#2+(x-1)#2|mod x a<1,a<x=a#2*div x a#2|b<-a+1=x#b
(#2)
```

Usage example: `(#2) 1025` -> `81`

The parameter `a` is counted up until it divides `x` or it reaches `x` (i.e. `x` is prime). It it one byte shorter to test for `a > x` and add a further condition (`a < x`) to the modulus test instead of testing for `a == x`, because the former binds `a` to `x+1`, which helps in the recursive call. Compare:

```
|a==x=(x+1)#2+(x-1)#2|mod x a<1=
|a>x=a#2+(x-1)#2|mod x a<1,a<x=
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 bytes

```
‘;’Ñ€Sµ1n2$?
ÆfÇ€P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYYb1o4aZhyc@aloTfGirYZ6Rij3X4ba0w@1AgYD///8bGhiZAgA)

This is basically just a direct translation of the specification. (After thinking about it a bit, I suspect that if there is a closed formula for finding the sequence, it'd be more bytes than the direct approach.)

### Explanation

We have two mutually recursive functions. Here's the helper function (which calculates **g(n)** for prime **n**):

```
‘;’Ñ€Sµ1n2$?
           ?  If
        n2$     the input is not equal to 2 (parsed as a group due to $)
      µ       then do all the following (parsed as a group due to µ):
‘;’             Find the list [n+1, n-1];
   Ñ€           Call the main program on each element (i.e. [g(n+1),g(n-1)]);
     S          and return the sum of the list (i.e. g(n+1)+g(n-1)).
              Otherwise:
       1        Return 1.
```

And here's the main program, which calculates **g(n)** for any **n**:

```
ÆfÇ€P
Æf            Factorize the input into its prime factors;
  Ç€          Call the helper function on each element of that list;
    P         Then take the product.
```

Clearly, if we call the main program on a prime number, everything's a no-op except the `Ç`, so it returns **g(n)** in this case. The rest of the program handles the behaviour for composite **n**.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 59 bytes

```js
f=(n,d=2)=>n-2?d<n?n%d?f(n,d+1):f(n/d)*f(d):f(n-1)+f(n+1):1
```

#### Test

```js
f=(n,d=2)=>n-2?d<n?n%d?f(n,d+1):f(n/d)*f(d):f(n-1)+f(n+1):1

// f(2) to f(50)
for(N = 2, list = []; N <= 50; N++) {
  list.push(N + ' -> ' + f(N));
}
console.log(list.join(', '));

// f(1025)
console.log(f(1025));
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
Æfḟ2µ‘,’ß€€SP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@3@4Le3hjvlGh7Y@apih86hh5uH5j5rWAFFwwH@jIlMDBUMDI1PrQ1uP7jncDhR1//8fJAAA)

#### How it works

```
Æfḟ2µ‘,’ß€€SP  Main link. Argument: n

Æf             Yield the array of prime factors of n.
  ḟ2           Remove all occurrences of 2.
    µ          Begin a new, monadic chain. Argument: A (array of odd prime factors)
     ‘         Increment all elements of A.
       ’       Decrement all elements of A.
      ,        Pair; yield [A+1, A-1].
        ß€€    Map the main link over all elements of A+1 and A-1.
           S   Column-wise reduce by addition.
            P  Reduce by multiplication.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <strike>85</strike> 69 bytes

```py
g=lambda n,k=3:(n&~-n<1)or n%k and g(n,k+2)or(g(k+1)+g(k-1))*g(n/k,k)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Clojure, 126 bytes

```clojure
(defn t[n](if(= n 2)1(let[a(+(.indexOf(for[b(range 2 n)](mod n b)2)0))](if(> a 1)(*(t(/ n a))(t a))(+(t(dec n))(t(inc n)))))))
```

Yay! It's almost twice as long as the Python answer!

Ungolfed and an explanation:

```clojure
(defn trivial [n]
  ; Define the function.
  (if (= n 2) 1
  ; If the number is 2, return 1
    (let [a (+ 2 (.indexOf (for [b (range 2 n)] (mod n b)) 0))]
      ; Let a be the lowest prime factor of n
      (if (> a 1)
        ; The .indexOf function returns -1 if a is a prime, so -1 + 2 = 1.
        ; Checks if a is a prime.
        (* (trivial (/ n a)) (trivial a))
        ; If a is prime, return the trivial(a/n) * trivial(a).
        (+ (trivial (dec n)) (trivial (inc n)))))))
        ; Else, return trivial(n-1) + trivial(n + 1).
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could do `(.indexOf (for [...] ...) x)`!

Comment: The current 118 byte version returns 11 for `(t 1025)`, maybe that `if` was intended to be `:when`? But then `nth` of empty list throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @NikoNyrh Yeah, that shouldn't happen - I tested it too, and the code's invalid. Will revert back to original version.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 83 bytes

```
Which[#<4,#-1,PrimeQ@#,Tr[#0/@({#-1,#+1}/2)],0<1,1##&@@#0/@Divisors@#~Part~{2,-2}]&
```

Unnamed recursive function of one positive integer argument, returning an integer. Not all that short, in the end. `Tr[#0/@({#-1,#+1}/2)]` (in the case where the input is prime) calls the function on both members of the ordered pair `{(#-1)/2,(#+1)/2}` and adds the results; this is fine since the function has the same value at `(#-1)/2` and `#-1`, for example. Similarly, `1##&@@#0/@Divisors@#~Part~{2,-2}` calls the function on the second-smallest divisor `#` and its complememtary divisor (the second-larget divisor) and multiplies the answers together.

Comment: How do unnamed recursive functions work?

Comment: Check out the section about `#0` in [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/45188/56178).

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 62 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=3:k>n or n%k and f(n,k+2)or(f(k-1)+f(k+1))*f(n/k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FYxBCoMwFETX9RSzCeY3ik1aN4JepLiIpCny7VeC90/j6sG84eU4bv63BA9peHwOPAn2BFEMLwFRl9k42pOOmltLpsBYonsxHVOO1xmr4G0frp9hkLx8P9o16C0N1e1Iq5yo1SugnaBcqKFQqleaKP8B)

Answer (score 2):

### Clojure, 120 bytes

```
(defn g[n](if(= n 2)1(if-let[F(first(for[i(range 2 n):when(=(mod n i)0)]i))](*(g F)(g(/ n F)))(+(g(dec n))(g(inc n))))))
```

Uses `:when` to get divisors of `n`, `F` is `nil` if no such divisor is found (`n` is prime).

Comment: Do you wish to quarrel, sir? It's on. (Friendly competition?)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 89 bytes

```r
g=function(n)"if"(n<3,1,"if"(sum(y<-!n%%2:n)<2,g(n-1)+g(n+1),g(k<-1+which(y)[1])*g(n/k)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYlLCoAwEMXOoiDMsy06FTdSTyKuBGsRR/CDePpaXCUhR4y@n2@ZrrALCfIw5ySu0ax/Pe@NXmcyKQrbCZzVnsQwVIJipFqdYfUsYVroxcAjyrSqFUD0xLVtET8)