# The forbidden built-in

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, array

In the [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default), the following is [forbidden](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1071/48934):

> Claiming that your answer is written in "MyOwnLanguage", where the command `x` means "read a sequence of numbers, split them into groups of three, and print the last numbers of those groups where the second number is less than the first"

Here, we are going to do the exact same thing.

## Task

Given a sequence of positive integers, whose length is divisible by 3, split them into groups of three, and print the last numbers of those groups where the second number is less than the first.

## Testcases

```
Input               Output
[]                  []
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] []
[2,1,3,5,4,6,8,7,9] [3,6,9]
[3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5] [4]
[100,99,123]        [123]
[123,123,456]       []
[456,123,789]       [789]
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins.

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply, so remember not to have a built-in command `x` that does this task.

Comment: Hmmm... Now I'm really tempted to create `MyOwnLanguage` and add the `x` command... :P

Comment: *remember not to have a built-in*‽ Well, if we already have it, we can use it, no?

Comment: Is it neccessary to print the Output, or can you just return it as well?

Comment: @MetaColon you can return it as well.

Comment: @Adám According to the standard loopholes, you cannot have a language containing the built-in `x` specifically performing that function.

Comment: @LeakyNun Yes you can, you just cannot make such a language *because* of the challenge. If your language predates the challenge, it is acceptable.

Comment: I'd be surprised if nobody has written a built-in doing exactly this, just in case somebody would post this exact question. A couple of esoteric languages have been created by users from this site after all.

Comment: @theonlygusti the task is the one defined as an example function in the loophole text... what's not to get?

Comment: @Mast Only a couple?

Comment: is the sequence formatting important? (as in would acceptable input be space separated and output be one per line? or should the output be the same format as the input or...)

Comment: @TomTanner Any permissible input/output format is permissible.

Comment: If I call the builtin `p`, can I use it?

Comment: I think so, also if you call the language "MyOwlLanguage".

Comment: Take the question's id as source code in whatever base, and execute the first answer, profit. Predates any upcoming questions :p

Comment: @Caramiriel: https://xkcd.com/1185/

Comment: @Adam: Wasn't meant as a serious answer, but that pretty much sums up why that isnt such a good idea. +1

Comment: Would returning a nested array be allowed? e.g. `[[3],[6],[9]]`

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I did that for you.

Answer (score 16):

## Octave, 32 bytes

```matlab
@(L)L(x=3:3:end)(diff(L)(x-2)<0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@g4aPpo1Fha2xlbJWal6KpkZKZlgYU06jQNdK0MdD8n2arkJhXbM2VphFtpGOoY6xjqmOiY6ZjoWOuYxmryfUfAA)

or

[Verify test cases!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#Zc9RCoMwDADQ/5yiny1kYFtbV52wA3gD6cdAC@LmxnQgiGd3qYMxWCAfeSQh2c68EhWfS53rvB0awZsuBDI@H5Q4JWILJbsMYwFTO06sZEvt2V9ALVGhxhQNWszwiM4TKpSEhtgSZR/UhCmlQUczFk1EmSToHEql/c9OpaNgaqz/IhU7Zkfn1wIg3J@sp7tkzobXrb3yeKeA2Nx044OHHZZ@FQLoP9je)

```matlab
L3 = L(3:3:end)  %extract last elements of groups
d= diff(L)       % first difference of the list
y=d(1:3:end)     %extract first elements of each subgroup of the difference
idx = y<0        %check for negative numbers  
result = L3(idx)
```

Answer (score 14):

## Haskell, <strike>30</strike> 29 bytes

```
x(a:b:c:l)=[c|b<a]++x l
x d=d
```

My first attempt at golfing Haskell, so I may have missed an optimization or two

-1 byte thanks to @JulianWolf

Comment: Nice answer! See https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60884/66904 for a relevant tip; in particular, swapping the two definitions and writing the second (now first) as `x d=d` can save you a byte

Comment: Clever! I browsed that answer beforehand but must have missed the part where the definition reused the variable

Answer (score 13):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
>Ḋm3T×3ị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@2/3cEdXrnHI4enGD3d3/z/c/qhpjfv//9HRsTpcCtGGOkY6xjomOqY6ZjrmOhY6lmBRIx1DoKgpUNwMKGYOFTUGipoAsamOJVCXmY4pxAQDAx1LSx1DI2MI18gYxNYxMTUD84E0mG9uYRkbCwA)

#### How it works

```
>Ḋm3T×3ị  Main link. Argument: A (array)

 Ḋ        Dequeue; yield A without its first element.
>         Compare the elements of A with the elements of the result.
  m3      Select each third element, starting with the first.
    T     Truth; get all indices of truthy elements.
     ×3   Multiply those indices by 3.
       ị  Unindex; retrieve the elements at the redulting indices.
```

Answer (score 11):

## Mathematica, 37 bytes

*Assuming this does satisfy the spec, ngenisis gets credit for this approach leading to a 1-byte saving!*

```
BlockMap[If[#>#2,Print@#3]&@@#&,#,3]&
```

Pure function. `BlockMap[...,#,3]&` splits the input list into sublists of length 3 and then operates on each sublist with the function `If[#>#2,Print@#3]&@@#&`. The result is that each qualifying last number is printed. The function also returns a value (namely a list of `Null`s a third as long as the input list), which seems to be allowed behavior.

### Mathematica, <s>42</s> 38 bytes

*Thanks to Martin Ender for saving 4 bytes!*

```
Cases[#~Partition~3,{a__,b_}/;a>0:>b]&
```

Pure function. `#~Partition~3` does what you think. `Cases[X,P:>Q]` selects all the elements of `X` matching the pattern `P`, and returns the result of the transformation rule `:>Q` applied to each instance. Here, the pattern being matched is `{a__,b_}/;a>0`: `b_` will match the last element of the list and `a__` all the other elements (in this case, the first two); call them `y` and `z` for now. The sneaky `a>0` then expands to `y>z>0`, which is the test we want to apply (valid because the spec says everything will be a positive integer). And the transformation rule is `:>b`, which simply replaces each matching ordered triple with its last element.

Original submission:

```
Last/@Select[#~Partition~3,#.{1,-1,0}>0&]&
```

Pure function; pretty much a straightforward implementation, other than `#.{1,-1,0}` which calculates the difference between the first and second elements of each 3-element sublist.

Comment: The dot product is neat, but `#>#2&@@#&` is shorter. But overall it's *still* shorter to use `Cases` instead of `Select`: `Cases[#~Partition~3,{a__,b_}/;a>0:>b]&`

Comment: `a>0:>` has two kinds of magic in it!

Comment: `BlockMap` is tantalizing here.

Comment: `BlockMap[If[#>#2,#3,Nothing]&@@#&,#,3]&` works and is only 39 bytes ... can we save a couple bytes?

Comment: `BlockMap[If[#>#2,Print@#3]&@@#&,#,3]&` arguably satisfies the spec

Answer (score 9):

## R, 35 bytes

```
(x=matrix(scan(),3))[3,x[2,]<x[1,]]
```

Comment: Is the leading whitespace necessary?

Comment: nice elegant solution

Answer (score 8):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
eMf>FPTcQ3
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=eMf%3EFPTcQ3&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%5D%0A%5B2%2C1%2C3%2C5%2C4%2C6%2C8%2C7%2C9%5D%0A%5B3%2C1%2C4%2C1%2C5%2C9%2C2%2C6%2C5%5D%0A%5B100%2C99%2C123%5D%0A%5B123%2C123%2C456%5D%0A%5B456%2C123%2C789%5D&debug=0)

```
eMf>FPTcQ3
       cQ3    Chop the input into groups of size 3
  f           Filter on
     PT       All but the last element
   >F         Apply the greater than function
eM            Map to the last element
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (2), 14 bytes

```
~c{Ṫ}ᵐ{k>₁&t}ˢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@1@XXP1w56rah1snVGfbPWpqVCupPb3o//9oYx1DHRMgNtWx1DHSMQPSZkBoHvs/CgA)

Brachylog rather struggles with this sort of problem. Note that this program has horrible computational complexity, as it brute-forces splitting the input into groups of 3 (having no "split into groups" builtin); it runs quickly with four groups but very slowly with five.

### Explanation

```
~c{Ṫ}ᵐ{k>₁&t}ˢ
~c              Split into groups
  { }ᵐ          such that each group
   Ṫ            has three elements
      {     }ˢ  then on each element, skipping that element on error:
       k          with the list minus its last element
        >₁        assert that it's strictly decreasing
          &       and with the original list
           t      keep only its last element
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `l÷₃;?ḍ₍` is a faster alternative.

Comment: I had that in an earlier attempt (using `/` not `÷`; they're equivalent here), but it's a byte longer so I discarded it while golfing it down.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>46</s> <s>44</s> <s>42</s> <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```js
a=>a.filter((_,y)=>y%3>1&a[y-1]<a[y-2])
```

- Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil).

---

### Try It

Input a comma separated list of numbers, without any spaces.

```js
f=
a=>a.filter((_,y)=>y%3>1&a[y-1]<a[y-2])
i.oninput=_=>o.innerText=JSON.stringify(f(i.value.split`,`.map(eval)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([])))                  // []
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]))) // []
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([2,1,3,5,4,6,8,7,9]))) // [3,6,9]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5]))) // [4]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([100,99,123])))        // [123]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([123,123,456])))       // []
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([456,123,789])))       // [789]
```

```html
<input id=i><pre id=o>
```

---

### Explanation

```js
a=>              :Anonymous function taking the input array as an argument via parameter a
a.filter((_,y)=> :Filter the array by executing a callback function on each element,
                  with the index of the current element passed through parameter y.
                  If the function returns 0 for any element, remove it from the array.
y%3>1            :Check if the modulo of the current index is greater than 1.
                  (JS uses 0 indexing, therefore the index of the 3rd element is 2; 2%3=2)
&                :Bitwise AND.
a[y-1]<a[y-2]    :Check if the element at index y-1 in array a
                  is less than the element at index y-2
)                :End filtering method
```

Comment: Does `y%3>1&a[y-1]<a[y-2]` work?

Comment: Crossed out 44 is still 44

Comment: What do you mean, @RomanGräf?

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7427/56341

Comment: A bug in "Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif" - well spotted @Roman

Comment: `a=>a.filter(_=>a[y]>a[++y]&y%3,y=-2)`

Answer (score 4):

### [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 14 bytes

```
_3&(>`[/\#]/\)
```

This evaluates to a monadic verb.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@mYGulEG@spmGXEK0foxyrH6P5PzU5I18hTcFYwVDBBIhNFSwVjBTMgLQ5EBv9BwA)

### Explanation

```
_3&(>`[/\#]/\)  Input is y.
_3&(    \    )  For each non-overlapping 3-element chunk of y,
    >`[/        check if first element is greater than second.
                Call the resulting array x.
_3&(        \)  For each non-overlapping 3-element chunk of y,
          ]/    take the last element.
         #      Keep those where the corresponding element of x is 1.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

Code:

```
3ôʒR`‹i,
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@298eMupSUEJjxp2Zur8/x9tpGOoY6xjqmOiY6ZjoWOuYxkLAA)

Answer (score 4):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

*Thanks to Leo for saving 1 byte.*

```
I.h%I-rI~$O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@@@pl6HqqVvkWafi//9/cmJKYmpmUloqAA)

Uses the [code points of a string as the input list](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-the-form-of-byte-values) and outputs the character corresponding to the outputs that should be kept.

#### Explanation

```
I      Read x. Pushes -1 on EOF.
.h%    Compute x%(x+1). This terminates the program due to division by zero at EOF,
       but does nothing for non-negative x.
I      Read y.
-      Compute x-y. We only want to output z is this is positive.
r      Range. Pushes 0 1 ... n for positive n, and -n ... 1 0 for negative n
       (and simply 0 for n = 0). So this results in a positive number on top
       of the stack iff x-y is positive.
I      Read z.
~      Swap it with x-y > 0.
$O     Output z iff x-y > 0.
       Then the IP wraps to the beginning of the program to process the next triplet.
```

Comment: You can golf one byte using `r` instead of `ex`. [TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@@@pl6HqqVvkWafi//9/cmJKYmpmUloqAA)

Comment: @Leo that's brilliant, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

### [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
ṁΓȯΓ↑<C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6vkKtR/KipsUjz0Lb/D3c2npt8Yv25yY/aJto4G////z86livaUMdIx1jHRMdUx0zHXMdCxxIoZqRjCBQzBYqaAUXMwWLGQDETIDbVsQTqMNMxBek1MNCxtNQxNDIGcYyMQSwdE1MzIA9IgnnmFpaxAA)

### Explanation

This program is a bit involved, so bear with me.

```
ṁΓȯΓ↑<C3  Implicit input (list of integers).
      C3  Split into slices of length 3.
ṁ         Map over slices and concatenate results
 ΓȯΓ↑<    of this function, explained below.
```

The function `ΓȯΓ↑<` takes a list of length 3, `x = [a,b,c]`.
The first `Γ` splits `x` into `a` and `[b,c]`, and feeds them as arguments to the function `ȯΓ↑<`.
This should be equivalent to `((Γ↑)<)`, but due to a bug/feature of the interpreter, it's actually equivalent to `(Γ(↑<))`, interpreted as a composition of `Γ` and `↑<`.
Now, `a` is fed to the latter function using partial application, the resulting function `↑<a` is given to `Γ`, which deconstructs `[b,c]` into `b` and `[c]`.
Then `b` is fed to `↑<a`, resulting in a function that takes the first `b<a` elements from a list.
This function is finally applied to `[c]`; the result is `[c]` if `a>b`, and `[]` otherwise.
These lists are concatenated by `ṁ` to form the final result, which is printed implicitly.

Without the "feature", I would have 9 bytes:

```
ṁΓoΓo↑<C3
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
s3µṪWx>/µ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@19sfGjrw52rwivs9A9tfdS05v///8Y6hjomQGyqY6ljpGOmYwoA)

or

[Verify test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#HcuxDYAwDATAhV6CxHGCG9agQJmChpqGXRAtBS1MAouED4Vf/pO@THIdz7kNc99cx7vs5V5rljFjdPAQBCgiEjoYzcPRlBop6TehBZ7CuIjQum1bmMF5qcVL/RA0sjH/ljrLHw)

*-3 bytes thanks to @LeakyNun*

**Explanation**

```
s3µṪWx>/µ€
s3         - split into groups of three
  µ     µ€ - on each group, do:
   ṪW      - return the third element as the only element of a list
     x     - repeat each element in that list the number of times
      >/   - corresponding to 1 if the second element of the group is greater than the first; 0 otherwise.
```

Comment: 11 bytes: [`s3µṪ×>/µ€ḟ0`](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#HcuxDcMwDATAhR6IJIqS2XgRw1N4gzQZwaX7IK2BuJUmcRZRXipI/B/wbZNy3te77vOjnL/n5/4ertUXU2vLisUjQBChSMiYYLQAT1NqouRhQos8hXGRoH3rHMzgg/QSpCdETWz8o@XJ1j8)

Comment: 10 bytes: [`s3µṪWx>/µ€`](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#HcuxDYAwDATAhV6CxHGCG9agQJmChpqGXRAtBS1MAouED4Vf/pO@THIdz7kNc99cx7vs5V5rljFjdPAQBCgiEjoYzcPRlBop6TehBZ7CuIjQum1bmMF5qcVL/RA0sjH/ljrLHw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>43</s> 42 bytes

1 byte thanks to xnor.

```python
f=lambda a,b,c,*l:(b<a)*(c,)+(l and f(*l))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@59mm5OYm5SSqJCok6STrKOVY6WRZJOoqaWRrKOprZGjkJiXopCmoZWjqfk/xzbaSMdQx1jHVMdEx0zHQsdcxzKWq6AoM69EA6oEAA)

Comment: [Using splatted input](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59mm5OYm5SSqJCok6STrKOVY6WRZJOoqaWRrKOprZGjkJiXopCmoZWjqfk/xzbaSMdQx1jHVMdEx0zHQsdcxzKWq6AoM68EouQ/AA) saves a byte.

Answer (score 3):

## [dc](http://enwp.org/dc_(computer_program)), 30 bytes

```
[???sAz1[[lAps.]s.<.dx]s.<.]dx
```

I/O: one number per line.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 31 bytes

30 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```perl
s/\d+ (\d+) (\d+)/$2if$1<$&/ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#JYpLCgIxEET3OUWJYVBEMp2kO9PgUVzOB8HFoPcnlrqo36OOh315PXHd@zvd5wtOtPPfU8yPNcotDmlbehdkFFQoDA0TPGQIiZIZdyMpJJVSON8GDTKOcIfkEqhvoqoFrfbrbfIP)

Replaces each group of 3 numbers (`\d+ (\d+) (\d+)`) by the third (`$2`) if the second (`$1`) is less than the first (`$&`), and nothing otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

### R, 31 bytes

Thanks to @Giuseppe again -1 byte:

```
f=\(x)x[!2:0][x[!-1:1]<x[!0:2]]
```

Thanks to @Giuseppe again -2 bytes:

```
f=\(x)x[!-2:0][x[!-1:1]<x[!0:2]]
```

With the R 4.1 it is a new game play (34 bytes). ;)

```
f=\(x)x[(i<--1:1)>0][x[!i]<x[i<0]]
```

where `\(x)` is a shorthand for the `function(x)`.

37 bytes version with `scan()` which I do not like, but it makes it shorter.

```
x=scan();x[(i<--1:1)>0][x[!i]<x[i<0]]
```

Version with `function()` which is easier to test (41 byte)

```
f=function(x)x[(i<--1:1)>0][x[!i]<x[i<0]]
```

Thanks to the @Giuseppe! Nice idea to use recycling of index.

Test:

```
f(c())
f(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))
f(c(2,1,3,5,4,6,8,7,9))
f(c(3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5))
f(c(100,99,123))
f(c(123,123,456))
f(c(456,123,789))
```

Output:

```
> f(c())
NULL
> f(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))
numeric(0)
> f(c(2,1,3,5,4,6,8,7,9))
[1] 3 6 9
> f(c(3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5))
[1] 4
> f(c(100,99,123))
[1] 123
> f(c(123,123,456))
numeric(0)
> f(c(456,123,789))
[1] 789
```

Comment: you read `x` in from stdin by using `x=scan()` at the beginning instead of defining a function,
You can also simply set `i=c(1,2,0)` since logical indices get recycled
i.e., `x=scan();i=c(1,2,0);x[!i][x[i>1]<x[i==1]]`

Comment: https://tio.run/nexus/r#@19hW5ycmKehaZ1pm6xhqGOkY6BpXRGtmBkbXRGdaWcYawOkbG0NY2P/GysYKpgAsamCpYKRgpmC6X8A

Comment: Thanks @Giuseppe! I do not like this `x=scan()` approach as it makes the input very cumbersome. And I can not make it repeatable then.

Comment: Right, but the goal is to generate as short a code as possible. Unfortunately for both of us, somebody else found a better solution!

Comment: Heh, I had as well idea to use `matrix()` but somehow I did not believed it will be possible to make so short.

Comment: [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8K2ODkxT0PTuiJaUdfIyiA2GsQwtDKMtQEyDKyMYmP/GysYKpgAsamCpYKRgpmC6X8A)

Comment: Actually, use `2:0` instead of `-2:0`! I was clearly hung up on the symmetry.

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 15 bytes

```
{3/{)\:>{;}|}%}
```

Anonymous block which expects argument on the stack, and leaves the result on the stack.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#HcsxDoMwEATAnldsQ5E0YJ/P5oyUJ/ABgsQXqB3n62ZNcavbkfbapvxvRaby@uZPWeuvjrWN@dzebT@G3cFDEKCISFhgNA9HU2qkpMeEFngK4yJC@3aeYQbnpRcv/UPQyMZ8WlrsuAE) (Runs all test cases)

**Explanation**

```
3/             e# Split the list into length-3 chunks.
  {            e# For each chunk:
   )           e#  Remove the last element.
    \:>        e#  Reduce the first 2 elements by greater than.
       {;}|    e#  If the first is not larger than the second, delete the third.
           }%  e# (end for)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 82 bytes

```
{([({}[{}()]<(())>)](<>)){({}())<>}{}{((<{}>))<>{}}{}<>{}{{}((<({}<>)<>>))}{}{}}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#FYrJCQAxDAP/rkR@7pGFBeNGQioRqj2xH0LMSJuYoCYFXwG4py9EuhPtPFIUgaCyiSruYs0INJSurX8q2vuxy97KsN9u@2wc)

```
# Until the stack is empty (input is guaranteed to not contain 0)
{

  # Push 1 for greater than or equal to 0
  ([({}[{}()]<(())>)](<>)){({}())<>}{}{((<{}>))<>{}}{}<>{}
  #  ^------^  This part is Top - (Second + 1)

  # If the second number was less than the first...
  {{}

     # Get ready to push 2 zeros
     ((<

       # Move the next number to the other stack
       ({}<>)<>

     # Push those 2 zeros
     >))}

     # Pop 2 values.
     # This is either 2 zeros, or a 0 and a "last number" that shouldn't be printed
     {}{}

# End loop
}

# Switch to the stack where we stored the numbers to be printed
<>
```

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 126 Bytes

```
using System.Linq;i=>Enumerable.Range(0,i.Length/3).Select(u=>3*u).Where(u=>i[u]>i[u+1]).Select(u=>i[u+2]);
```

If you want a whole program with the method it'd be **175 Bytes**:

```
using System.Linq;namespace S{class P{static System.Collections.IEnumerable X(int[]i)=>Enumerable.Range(0,i.Length/3).Select(u=>3*u).Where(u=>i[u]>i[u+1]).Select(u=>i[u+2]);}}
```

*Saved 7 Bytes with the help of TheLethalCoder*

Comment: You can just print those...

Comment: @LeakyNun of course I could - but why should I? I asked wether it's neccessary, it's not, and it'd be more bytes, I guess.

Comment: `(int[]i)` can just be `i` no need for the type.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Updated it.

Comment: @MetaColon You don't need the braces around `(i)` either.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, <s>86</s> 85 bytes

```
void c(int[]a){for(int i=-1;++i<a.length;)if(a[i++]>a[i++])System.out.println(a[i]);}
```

-1 byte thanks to *@PunPun1000*

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#lY/NDoIwEITvPsUeaVgJfwUJ6ht48mg4VERtgoVI1RjCs@NSOXjw0kOzm3a@mWlZi66DXb8A6LTQsoTx2cgTlI5U@lAI1p@b@7SD3CyD3HXlWnh1pS76mjN5dsRBum6x/Q62f3e6unnNQ3vtnaBaTYKC5cMI0D6ONfnPMSblJqRy9pqkF5NFLYCiVfUCE98PLDd3f4znl191gCFGGCPHBFNcYWaHhxgQzskgITi1xSPCYzocM@qRILcs7/uYZRiEkSUXRhOEMU/sQAIMmK7mjw6LYfwA)

```
void c(int[]a){                  // Method with integer-array parameter and no return
  for(int i=-1;++i<a.length;)    //  Loop over the array in steps of three at a time
    if(a[i++]>a[i++])            //   If the value of the current index is larger than the next:
      System.out.println(a[i]);  //    Print the value on the third index
                                 //  End of loop (implicit / single-line body)
}                                // End of method
```

Comment: @PunPun1000 Now you've only incremented the iteration by 2 instead of 3 though, and therefore giving incorrect results (like `3,9` for the test case `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` instead of `3,6,9`).

Comment: @Kevin_Cruijssen Oops you're right.  You can still save a byte by using the increment operator though.  You just have to start at -1 [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#lY/NDoIwEITvPsUeaVgJfwUJ6ht48mg4VERtgoVI1RjCs@NSOXjw0kOzm3a@mWlZi66DXb8A6LTQsoTx2cgTlI5U@lAI1p@b@7SD3CyD3HXlWnh1pS76mjN5dsRBum6x/Q62f3e6unnNQ3vtnaBaTYKC5cMI0D6ONfnPMSblJqRy9pqkF5NFLYCiVfUCE98PLDd3f4znl191gCFGGCPHBFNcYWaHhxgQzskgITi1xSPCYzocM@qRILcs7/uYZRiEkSUXRhOEMU/sQAIMmK7mjw6LYfwA)

Comment: @PunPun1000 Ah, you're right, nice catch. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 57 bytes

```python
lambda i:[i[c+2]for c in range(0,len(i),3)if i[c+1]<i[c]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#HYvLDsIgEEV/hSWNd1Gg0NLol@AssBZDUtEQF/37OnQxj3tybrrdjy2@H88o8hxyWC6a0qeKReQiaiyvVfbY1iJzB9PlJJqi6MqH6Gjm3swQCEFBw2CAhcOICZ6ZhmJmmTom48kMs4HHwnPDwbZu38N7KG1a0KZ9GKzjxPtM4@SJ5m/N5SeS3LvjDw)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
IeI&Y)d0<)
```

The result is displayed as numbers separated by spaces.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@@@Z6qkWqZliYKP5/3@0sY6hjgkQm@pY6hjpmOmYxgIA)

Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#Xcu9CoAwDATgvU/hJAg39C@tAccu7i5SCg76/o9Qr44GEu4@yNX3Z5/P5bbb0udSjl7b9B9THTwCIgQJGSu0merhaEJNlPxZoEWuQPmRIDRnLVThfBjFh5EQJbHxfi2v2l4). This displays a string representation of the output, so that an empty array is actually seen as `[]`. Note that in MATL a number is the same as a singleton array, so `[4]` is shown as `4`.

#### Explanation

```
Ie    % Implicit input. Reshape as a 3-row matrix (column-major order)
I&Y)  % Split into the third row and a submatrix with the other two rows
d     % Consecutive difference along each column of the submatrix
0<    % True for negative values
)     % Use as logical index into the original third row. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 15 bytes

```
{[_3]if[_2<_1]}
```

Röda is nearly as short as the golfing languages...

This takes three values from the stream, and pushes the third (`_3`) back, if the second (`_2`) is less than the first (`_1`).

The underscores are syntax sugar for `for` loops, so the program could be written as `{{[a]if[b<c]}for a,b,c}` or even `{[a]for a,b,c if[b<c]}`.

No TIO link, because it doesn't work on TIO for some reason (although works with the latest version of Röda that predates the challenge).

Answer (score 2):

## Awk, 27 bytes

```
{a[b=NR%3]=$0}!b&&a[2]<a[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
3ẇR∩÷<Tİ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCIz4bqHUuKIqcO3PFTEsCIsIiIsIlszLDEsNCwxLDUsOSwyLDYsNV0iXQ==)

There are a ton of 8-byters but I haven't been able to find a single 7-byter.

```
3ẇ       # Cut into chunks of length 3
  R      # Reverse each chunk
   ∩÷    # Transpose and push each row to the stack
     <   # For each, check if second > first
      Tİ # Only keep third elements where ^ is truthy
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript, <s>108</s> <s>107</s> 108 bytes

This is a valid JS anonymous (lambda) function. Add `x=` at the beginning and invoke like `x([5,4,9,10,5,13])`. Outputs as function `return`.

```
a=>(y=[],a.map((c,i)=>(i+1)%3?0:y.push(a.slice(i-2,i+1))),y.map(v=>v[1]<v[0]?v[2]:null).filter(c=>c|c==0))
```

The snippet takes in the input as a list of comma separated integers.

```js
x=a=>(y=[],a.map((c,i)=>(i+1)%3?0:y.push(a.slice(i-2,i+1))),y.map(v=>v[1]<v[0]?v[2]:null).filter(c=>c|c==0))
martin.oninput = e => { dennis.innerHTML = x(martin.value.split`,`.map(c=>parseInt(c,10))) }
```

```html
<input type=text id=martin><pre id=dennis>
```

Comment: What is the point at posting a longer solution, and using `martin` and `dennis` as id?

Comment: @LeakyNun Shaggy posted his solution while I was working on mine. But that was no reason for me to not post my solution. As for using the names as id's, I thought it'd be funny.

Comment: This doesn't work for `[5,4,9,10,5,13]`.

Comment: @Shaggy That was a problem with the implementation of the test case snippet; nothing wrong with the solution. Actually, the value of the input element is always a string. So, splitting the string on `,` resulted it into being an array of strings rather than numbers! The solution is perfectly fine. Only the test case snippet was wrong. I have fixed that, now. Thanks for pointing that out! :)

Comment: Oh, yeah, that explains the problem! Thank *you*, @Arjun.

Comment: @Shaggy No, it's I who should be thankful! Thanks, once again! :)

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 16 bytes

```
q~3/{~@@>S{;}?}%
```

The output is shown as numbers separated by spaces.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@19YZ6xfXefgYBdcbV1rX6v6/3@0kYKhgrGCqYKJgpmChYK5gmUsAA)

#### Explanation

```
q~               e# Read input list
  3/             e# List of sublists of length 3
   {         }%  e# Apply this to each sublist
    ~            e# Push sublist contents: 3 numbers
     @@          e# Rotate twice. This moves first two numbers to top
       >         e# Greater than?
        S{;}?    e# If so: push space (used as separator). Else: pop the third number
                 e# Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 89 Bytes

```php
<?print_r(array_filter($_GET,function($v,$k){return $k%3>1&&$_GET[$k-1]<$_GET[$k-2];},1));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUol3dw2xjTbWMdQxAWJTHUsdIx0zHdNY6/8FRZl5JfFFGolFRYmV8WmZOSWpRRpg9TpppXnJJZn5eRoqZToq2ZrVRaklpUV5KtmqxnaGampgNdEq2bqGsTZwtlGsda2Ooaam9f//AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>37</s> 35 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.map{x,y,z,*a=a;z&&x>y&&p(z)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#bY3NCoMwEITvPkVPsS2jmJ9NDKIvIh5y8VYItAWN@Ozp2nMW5jLfx8465mYKR2hfIR4bdiQ8wxiGJMQ27ULEe3qcZ17neVmq@P28b3VzXV1xJaGgYUCwcOjhC46CZIfYsmy4oqPZMRyC548WVNrqOngPqXQJKn0RGLIFyu2fup7H8w8)

### How it works:

```ruby
->a{
    a.map{                          -> Loop [a.size] times
          x,y,z,*a=a;               -> get and remove 3 elements from a
                     z&&x>y&&p(z)   -> print z if not null and x>y
                                 }}
```

Comment: I think you need `each_slice`, not `each_cons`. `each_cons` yields overlapping groups.

Comment: You are right, I'm fixing it

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>42</s> 36 bytes

```
\d+
$*
M!`1+ 1+ 1+
A`^(1+) \1
%r`1\G
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@x@Tos2losXlq5hgqK0ARlyOCXEahtqaCjGGXKpFCYYx7v//GysYKpgAsamCpYKRgpmCKQA) Takes input as a space-separated list of numbers and outputs a newline-separated list of numbers. Edit: Saved 6 bytes thanks to @MartinEnder. Explanation:

```
\d+             Match input numbers
$*              Convert to unary
M!`1+ 1+ 1+     Capture groups of three numbers
A`^(1+) \1      Filter out if the first is less than or equal to the second
%r`1\G          Convert the third to decimal
```

Comment: `M!` saves a byte over `S...(...)`. The second stage needs a `^` otherwise it can yield false positives where the third is less than the second, but then it's shorter to negate the logic with `A\`^(1+) \1`. And the last stage can be shortened to `r\`1\G` (count consecutive ones from the end of the string). Link: https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@x@Tos2losXlq5hgqK0ARlyOCXEahtqaCjGGXEUJhjHu//8bKxgqmACxqYKlgpGCmYIpAA

Comment: @MartinEnder My second stage doesn't need a `^` because there's no space after the third value, but `A` is a better idea anyway, thanks.

Comment: oh, I didn't see that the space was part of the capturing group, that works as well then

Comment: I think the last stage needs a `%` modifier, otherwise this will return only the last value. [TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@x@Tos2losXlq5hgqK0ARlyOCXEahtqaCjGGXEWqCYYx7v//GykYKhgrmCqYKJgpWCiYK1gCAA)

Comment: @Leo Thanks, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 65 bytes

[**Try Online**](http://ideone.com/fuixRx)

```c
i;f(s,l)int*l;{for(;i+2<s;i++)l[i]>l[i+1]&&printf(" %d",l[i+2]);}
```

Comment: This code [doesn't work](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#FY3BCoMwEER/ZbFUkmYpqLVQYv0RyaE0igtrWhpLD5JvT9fDDDNvDnOg8OSvH6GLq6fXee4z2UlFZE1hPbHdfjPxqKiLmgdyvZipXFm@P7JPqjj6AndWO41kjE1ZOCwPCkrDBnvhwcFdcoMVXkQt3rDGK7aQLEyqkS8LKf8B). `s` is supposed to be the number of groups of 3, right? Doesn't work when `s` is number of numbers either.

Comment: @gurka `s` is the size of array `l`, I've fixed the code, check here [**Try Online**](http://ideone.com/fuixRx)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl5.8.9, <s>73</s> 60 bytes

```
while(@F){@b=splice@F,0,3;$b[1]<$b[0]&&print$b[2]}print"-"
```

(58+2 for the 'n' flag to read the whole file and a to autosplit). Assumes the input is lines of space separated numbers

Reduction thanks to Dada. Including the print at the end for visibility, that'd save 8 bytes if not.

Comment: Nice one! Have your well deserved +1!

Comment: The output format being quite flexible, you don't really have to put that `print"\n"` at the end. Also, you can do `$b[1]<$b[0]&&print"$b[2] "while@b=splice@a,0,3` to save 7 bytes. Finally, you can use `-a` flag instead of doing `@a=split` (it will do the same automatically and store the result in `@F` instead of `@a`); with Perl 5.8.9, you'll need `-na` while with recent Perls, `-a` is enough. That should get you to 47-48 bytes.

Comment: oh, i didn't know about -a. I still think I should do one output line per input line, the output is pretty incomprehensbile otherwise

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 43 bytes

```
#(for[[a b c](partition 3 %):when(< b a)]c)
```

Boring :/

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 61 bytes

```
a=($@)
for((t=0;t<$#;t+=3)){((a[t+1]<a[t]))&&echo ${a[t+2]};}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@59oq6HioMmVll@koVFia2BdYqOibF2ibWusqVmtoZEYXaJtGGsDpGI1NdXUUpMz8hVUqkGiRrG11rX///83@m/43/i/6X@T/2b/Lf6b/7cEAA)

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, <strike>42</strike> 39 bytes

*Edit: Saved 3 bytes thanks to Greg Martin*

<strike>`BlockMap[Apply[If[#>#2,#3,Nothing]&],#,3]&`</strike>

```
BlockMap[If[#>#2,#3,Nothing]&@@#&,#,3]&
```

Not shorter than [Greg Martin's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119693/61980), but I couldn't resist the opportunity to finally use [`BlockMap`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/61086/61980). Partitions the input list `#` into sublists of size `3` and `Apply`s the functions `If[#>#2,#3,Nothing]&` to each sublist.

### Questionable solution, 38 bytes

```
BlockMap[If[#>#2,Print@#3]&@@#&,#,3]&
```

Same as above, except it prints the desired elements and returns `{Null,...Null}`.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, <strike>74</strike> 66 bytes

#### Edit: Lost 8 bytes thanks to @AlecZorab

The suggestion was to use `collect()` instead of the equivalent `filter()` followed by `map()` (which my for comprehension is equivalent to) and a pattern match, kind of like:

```
(_:Seq[Int]).grouped(3).collect{case(Seq(a,b,c))if(a>b)=>c}.toList
```

Another suggestion was to drop the parameter name as it was only used once.

The character/byte count can be dropped to 59 bytes if an iterator is an acceptable output. Usage is similar to the old version.

### Old version:

```
(s:Seq[Int])=>(for(l<-s.grouped(3)if l.size>2&l(0)>l(1))yield l(2)).toList
```

Straightforward. The `toList` at the end is to consume the iterator produced - `toSeq` produces a `Stream` in my tests, which shows only the first element. If the iterator itself is legal as output, this version comes in at 64 bytes:

```
(s:Seq[Int])=>for(l<-s.grouped(3)if l.size>2&l(0)>l(1))yield l(2)
```

Scala allows Unicode operators, so I could lower the character count to 62 at the cost of increasing the byte count to 66:

```
(s:Seq[Int])⇒for(l←s.grouped(3)if l.size>2&l(0)>l(1))yield l(2)
```

Lambda, the parameter type is required in the REPL. Enter into the REPL and call the `res0` or whatever function object it shows with the `Seq[Int]` to test with. For ease of testing, you can consider the following function which converts a test case `String` into a proper `Seq[Int]`:

```
def testCaseAsSeq(input: String): Seq[Int] =
    input.drop(1).dropRight(1)
         .split(",")
         .filter(! _.isEmpty)
         .map(_.toInt).toSeq
```

Prettified version with some obfuscations removed to make it more standard Scala:

```
(sequence: Seq[Int]): List[Int] => 
                    (for(group <- s.grouped(3) 
                    if group.size == 3 && group(0) > group(1))
                        yield group.last)
                    .toList
```

Comment: couple of things you can do to tighten that up a little
First up, if you write it without the for comprehension you get
`(s:Seq[Int]) => s.grouped(3).filter(g => g.size==3 && g(0) > g(1)).map(g => g(2))`
since `s` is only used once, you can replace the start with `(_: Seq[Int]).grouped`, saving a couple of characters.
Then we notice that a filter and a map in scala is called collect, so you can merge them into

Comment: ... `collect{ case g if g.size == 3 && g(0) > g(1) => g(2)}`. Then we can replace that with a pattern match, giving `(_:Seq[Int]).grouped(3).collect{case(Seq(a,b,c))if(a>b)=>c}.toList` (66 bytes)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 19 + 3 for -v = 22 bytes

```
rl?!;(?\~r
naaao~ \
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>18</s> 12 bytes

```
ò3 f_v >ZvÃc
```

[Try it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=8jMgZl92ID5adsNj&input=WzMsMSw0LDEsNSw5LDIsNiw1XQotUQ==)

Or 10 bytes if returning a nested array is permitted, e.g. `[[3],[6],[9]]`

```
ò3 f_v >Zv
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 17 bytes

```
~3/{~@@>{}{;}if}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v85Yv7rOwcGuurbaujYzrVb1f8L/aGMFQwUTIDZVsFQwUjBTMI0FAA)

## Explanation

```
~                 # Evaluate the input
 3/               # Split the input into chunks of 3
   {           }% # Map every item in the input
    ~@@>          # Is the 1st item < second item?
        {}{;}if   # If false, discard the current item
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 50 bytes

```python
lambda l:[c for a,b,c in zip(*(iter(l),)*3)if b<a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY4xDoMwDEV3TuExQX8AQgJB5SSUIVBQI1FAkKW9PHUYbPk96ct//4b3tqprbp/X4j7Dy9HSdCPN20EOA0byK/38LlLhw3SIRUKmSvqZhofrrzCd4aSWuh5djgIKJTQMKtSw7Ark7DRbw6a6nWJX8mhYThjomM0yWIu8UBEKFS@U2jDxvqmqbZ8ksVeIne7PTUK0H34NYhZByusP)

Comment: You can save a few bytes by using `s[2]for s in ...` and getting rid of the outer list comprehension. Then `for a,b,c in zip...` saves a couple more: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY4xDoMwDEV3TuExQX8AQgJB5SSUIVBQI1FAkKW9PHUYbPk96ct//4b3tqprbp/X4j7Dy9HSdCPN20EOA0byK/38LlLhw3SIRUKmSvqZhofrrzCd4aSWuh5djgIKJTQMKtSw7Ark7DRbw6a6nWJX8mhYThjomM0yWIu8UBEKFS@U2jDxvqmqbZ8ksVeIne7PTUK0H34NYhZByusP)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 17 bytes

```
0&n[spG[rlr!]pp]p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/99ALS@6uMA9uiinSDG2oCC24P9/Iy5DLmMuUy4TLjMuCy5zLksA)

This is a pretty much a direct mapping of the rules to code...  After reading all the numbers onto the stack, each iteration of the loop processes the top three numbers on the stack.  If the 2nd is less than the 1st, the third is appended to the end of the stack.

Once the `0` delimiter is hit on the stack, the program exits and the default action to print everything on the stack as numeric takes care of the output.

```
0                  - add a "0" delimiter to stop the loop
 &n                - read all the numbers into the stack (expects one per line)
   [         pp]   - loop to process three nums ("pp" pops a work var and the 1at num)
    sp             - save the 3rd number and pop it from the stack
      G            - compare the 1st and 2nd
       [   !]      - true if 2nd is less than 1st
        rlr        - reverse the stack, load 3rd char, reverse again
                p  - pop the "0" delimiter, leaving just the answers
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-xp`, 14 bytes

```lisp
_@2M$>H_FIa<>3
```

Takes the list as a command-line argument. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgebSSbkWBUuyCpaUlaboW6-IdjHxV7Dzi3TwTbeyMIYJQue3RStFG1obWxtam1ibWZtbm1hbWlrFwrQA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
          a     ; First command-line argument
           <>3  ; Grouped into sublists of length 3
        FI      ; Filtered on this function:
      H_        ;   Prefix (all but the last item)
    $>          ;   Folded on > (in this case, truthy iff the first item > the second)
   M            ; Map this function to each remaining sublist:
_@2             ;   Get the item at index 2
```

---

### No flags, 14 bytes

Here's a recursive solution without flags:

```lisp
Ib<aPcIgfVg@>3
```

Takes the numbers as separate command-line arguments. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhbrPJNsEgOSPdPTwtId7IwhglC5zdFGOoY6xjqmOiY6ZjrmOhY6lrFQKQA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
Ib<a            ; If the second argument is less than the first:
    Pc          ;   Print the third argument
      Ig        ; If the arglist is truthy (not empty):
        fV      ;   Call the current function again with arglist...
          g@>3  ;   ... current arglist without the first three elements
```

When `g` is empty, all of `a`, `b`, and `c` are set to nil. Since nil is not less than nil, `b<a` is false and the first if statement is not executed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
3ẇ{rẸ<?£
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPTMlRTElQkElODclN0JyJUUxJUJBJUI4JTNDJTNGJUMyJUEzJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9MyUyQzElMkM0JTJDMSUyQzUlMkM5JTJDMiUyQzYlMkM1JmZsYWdzPW8=)

##### Explanation

```python
3ẇ{rẸ<?£  # Implicit input
3ẇ        # Split into threes
  {       # Loop over them:
   rẸ     #  Reverse and dump
     <    #  Check if less than
      ?£  #  If true, print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [janet](https://janet-lang.org), 60 bytes

```scheme
(fn[l](map last(filter(fn[x](<(x 1)(x 0)))(partition 3 l))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL (Dyalog Unicode), <s>38</s> <s>29</s> 25 bytes

```
{((0=3|⍳⍴⍵)^⍵>1⌽⍵)/2⌽⍵}
```

The index origin is set to 0 (⎕IO←0).

[Try it on TryAPL.org!](https://tryapl.org/?clear&q=%E2%8E%95io%E2%86%900%E2%8B%84%7B((0%3D3%7C%E2%8D%B3%E2%8D%B4%E2%8D%B5)%5E%E2%8D%B5%3E1%E2%8C%BD%E2%8D%B5)%2F2%E2%8C%BD%E2%8D%B5%7D2%2C1%2C3%2C5%2C4%2C6%2C8%2C7%2C9%E2%8B%84%7B((0%3D3%7C%E2%8D%B3%E2%8D%B4%E2%8D%B5)%5E%E2%8D%B5%3E1%E2%8C%BD%E2%8D%B5)%2F2%E2%8C%BD%E2%8D%B5%7D3%2C1%2C4%2C1%2C5%2C9%2C2%2C6%2C5&run)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 29 bytes

```julia
~a=(!x=a[x:3:end])(3)[!2.<!1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc67CoMwFAbgPU8RcbFwKJqLGqng0jfoFjIEGmiLvdBY6uSrp0fpkCINZPjJl3P@y6s/2zKEybZZMrZWjw1v3O1oNhnf6IRtd0lhQkr3o70@ekc6f7q/6aQ5FCDwSlDAoARpCEnpwfnBk856754DKkNXp22pNhEp8DvHURKHVFCDMivCcA9HIJDUiL6EY1SxW3danPhZl@egFBSMm7jRnGPF@ExAyNL86Y1PC6lqFZM5hg8)

In Julia 1.0, a space is required to disambiguate the period, which could be [either a decimal or part of a dot operator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/#man-dot-operators).

-2 bytes thanks to MarcMush: use return value from function definition

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##dc67CoMwFAbgPU8RcbFwKJqLGqng0jfoFjIEGmiLvdBY6uSrp0fpkCINZPjJl3P@y6s/2zKEybZZMrZWjw1v3O1oNhnf6IRtd0lhQkr3o70@ekc6f7q/6aQ5FCDwSlDAoARpCEnpwfnBk856754DKkNXp22pNhEp8DvHURKHVFCDMivCcA9HIJDUiL6EY1SxW3danPhZl@egFBSMm7jRnGPF@ExAyNL86Y1PC6lqFZM5hg8 "Julia 0.6 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica 65 bytes

```
{K={};Cases[Partition[#,3],{a_,b_,c_}->If[b<a,AppendTo[K,c]]];K}&
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 44 bytes

```
[ 3 group [ first2 > ] [ last ] filter-map ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY8xbsMwDEX3nOJfoEEi27HdAl2LLF2KTkEGwqBdoYqsUAzQtOjZXdoeOnxQ71H4AHvqdJTp/e34@vKIQcZb8nFA5uuNY8cZnyyRAwaOLBT8N6kfY8aF9OP/15a/VCgjCavek/ioeNpsfvBr2cOhQIkKB9Ro0C7WmS/MlWYb86stzJaWytjZplobdju0LfauWNHmnLI6LDzPmevGSqaTlSx34ITeS1aHZ5wNAmW1R@@DsjxcKOE81YiUUrhjm9EFJpn@AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 7.5 bytes (15 nibbles)

```
.|`/3$`/<<$-/\
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboW6_RqEvSNVRL0bWxUdPVjIIJQue3RStHGOoY6JkBsqmOpY6RjpmMaqxQLlQYA)

```
.|`/3$`/<<$-/\
  `/3$          # split into chunks of 3
 |              # and filter these for positive results of
      `/        #   folding over
        <<$     #   the group without the 3rd (last) element
           -    #   by subtraction
.               # now map over the remaining groups of 3
             \  #   reverse each
            /   #   and now get the first element
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 87 bytes

```go
func(A[]int)(O[]int){for i:=0;i<len(A);i+=3{if A[i]>A[i+1]{O=append(O,A[i+2])}}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LZBNasMwEIX3OoVqKEhkWvz_k1QBn8DddeGaIlIriNayUe1shE_SjSn0LD1DblPJzkJ6mg_mzRt9_5z75Xo38NMHP7e441Ih2Q29Hh890Y0eQheusWC_0yge8uuLmNSJlHUj1UhJtakRvcZyz_yDfPpsFSnpQe5YZKTAZS2bo712QWMqxoehVe-kAkfChs4z0u04aTXf7P-c_RqCUGyQ_MJ7hutmHWOQmQGZAEKIIIYEUsggh8LBEAILE4tTi7INRhbG9iRQ2J4UkrXd96EoIAijtQoj94Q4SV1pZS2z3BnMCLnF3oC7FJor-z82kUHP2sYRxLu_vCp2xE48wBywIJxS23dbZ1k2_Qc)