# String subtraction

Tags: code-golf, string

### Objective

Create a function to reverse string concatenation

### Input

Two strings (alphanumeric + spaces), where one should be subtracted for the other.

- You can assume that the string to be subtracted will never be larger than the other one.

### Output

The result from the subtraction

### Subtraction

You should remove one string from the start or the end of another string.
If the string is present in the start and in the end, you can only remove one, which one will be removed is up to you.
If the string isn't in the start or in the end, or isn't an exact match, it is an invalid subtraction and you should output the original string.

### Test Cases

#### Valid Subtraction

```
'abcde','ab' -> 'cde'
'abcde','cde' -> 'ab'
'abab','ab' -> 'ab'
'abcab','ab' -> 'abc' or 'cab'
'ababcde','ab' -> 'abcde'
'acdbcd','cd' -> 'acdb'
'abcde','abcde' -> ''
'abcde','' -> 'abcde'
'','' -> ''
```

#### Invalid Subtraction (returns original string)

```
'abcde','ae' -> 'abcde'
'abcde','aa' -> 'abcde'
'abcde','bcd' -> 'abcde'
'abcde','xab' -> 'abcde'
'abcde','yde' -> 'abcde'
```

#### Invalid Input (don't need to be handled)

```
'','a' -> ''
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Why is the result of the first case not `cde`? What do you mean by valid? Do we need to judge the validity of the input, or do you mean that we will not receive invalid inputs?

Comment: @LeakyNun was a typing error, fixed

Comment: I think the empty string edge-case should probably be in the invalid section - mind you I suppose it doesn't make any difference to the result :)

Comment: I think you should drop the terms "valid" and "invalid", as they have a common meaning on PPCG which you are clearly not intending.

Comment: Damn you, `'abcde','bcd' -> 'abcde'`, for breaking my solution

Comment: Can we assume the strings will be regex-safe (alphanumeric + spaces)?

Comment: I'd suggest `'ababcde',  'ab'` → `'abcde'` as a test case. Some naive algorithms fail on that one.

Comment: @ais523 good point

Comment: Wait, why `'abcde','bcd' -> 'abcde'`? `abcde` contains `bcd`, and should therefore return `ae`.

Comment: @MDXF the objective here is "reverse a concatenation", not just to remove a substring c:

Comment: @Rod Yeah, just noticed that. Whoops.

Comment: @Rod You might consider retitling the challenge "Reverse string concatenation"?

Comment: Suggested Testcase `AbcdEbcd, bcd` => `AbcdE` and not `AEbcd`

Comment: @Wernisch I guess this is covered by `'acdbcd','cd' -> 'acdb'`, right?

Comment: @Rob, You are right, apologies.  Had incorrectly copied that test case.

Answer (score 18):

## Java 8, <s>46</s> <s>45</s> <s>44</s> 40 bytes

-1 byte thanks to TheLethalCoder

-1 byte because I'm dumb (thanks Rod!)

-4 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

```
a->b->a.replaceFirst("^"+b+"|"+b+"$","")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#dVNNb8IwDL33V1jRDu1aKti1Awkm7bbTjoxJThtYpn4pSdEQ47cz94M2jJJDEtvvvcSxc5ZZWSgD37jHsDIyDR8jJ05Ra3hDmcPRARplxVMZgzZoaNkXMoGMou67UTLfrTeAaqe9DlyPFaSY8QRhDjhZ8MkCQyXKFGPxKpU2LvtkPvfZbzM/sIAxL3J6di9rhDYvqIUmnSMw5HEiWFBvWNCjB3ez2P4ad4u@JxMnFGh1RuW7zUjEdv63B/o4F3HUze9c4udO7ofrqzXKrLdP1utuC@XK3ICkR51GIP0ZPA8vHaYi35kv8oM/hye7qE1pDtqILCwqE5ZUJJPmLvtgDHyrVmu5IZvcAdyG/FkXhMmiC6sqd9t2CQYoiVxZxPNaYt0qfV7OMF83adtDjfYKeHCxqVGntjGzE1TCVCoHHnK3xnkhug0ksk6hnIXaUiNTjw/MJfDuMwC/A19a8Mv5Fw72nNP5/Ac) (includes all test cases)

A Java answer actually beats a few other practical languages. *Smiles. (and now it beats JS!)*

Comment: Use currying to save a byte `a->b->`

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Thanks.

Comment: Why did you leave in the unused hashmap in your online example?

Comment: You can change the `First` to `All` for -2 bytes. Because of the `^` and `$` it's always either at the end or start of the String, so even with `replaceAll` it only replaces it once. [Try it here.](https://tinyurl.com/luxfvyt) PS: I added the previous byte-counts striked-through to your answer, which is what usually is done after code-golf edits here on PPCG.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I knew about the strike-throughs, guess I just forgot this time. However, if i use `All` instead of `First`, this becomes true: `"abab" + "ab" -> ""`

Comment: @Okx Ah, good call, missed that part of the `abcab + ab` test case. In that case you'll indeed need `First`. Oh, but you can still golf it by 4 bytes by changing `"(^"+b+")|("+b+"$)"` to `"^"+b+"|"+b+"$"` if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 9):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (Try It Online!), 12 bytes

```
~cpĊh.∧Ċtw|w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@1@XXHCkK0PvUcfyI10l5TXl//8rJSYlp6Qq/VdKTlECAA)

Takes the string to subtract from from standard input, and the string to subtract as a command line argument.

### Explanation

```
~cpĊh.∧Ċtw|w
~c            Split {the input} into pieces
  p           and (possibly) rearrange those pieces
   Ċ          such that there are two pieces
    h         and the first
     .        matches the command line argument
      ∧       then
         w    print
        t     the last
       Ċ      piece.
          |   If all else fails,
           w  print {the input}.
```

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), 41 bytes

```
s=>t=>s.replace(eval(`/^${t}|${t}$/`),'')
```

Takes input via currying syntax, i.e. `f("abab")("ab")`.

Comment: Now, why have I never thought to use `eval()` for constructing RegExes before?!

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 21 bytes

1 byte thanks to Martin Ender.

```
(.*);(\1|(.*)\1$|)
$3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/ivoaelaa0RY1gDYsQYqtRocqkY//@fmGSdmJScksoFxFAWWCgxCUInwxgwOYQ6GMWVCNeZCGUACSirAm5BJUwjAA)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>76</s> <s>70</s> <s>45</s> 41 bytes

```js
s=>t=>s.replace(RegExp(`^${t}|${t}$`),"")
```

---

### Try It

```js
f=
s=>t=>s.replace(RegExp(`^${t}|${t}$`),"")
o.innerText=f(i.value="abcde")(j.value="ab")
i.oninput=j.oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(i.value)(j.value)
```

```html
<input id=i><input id=j><pre id=o>
```

Comment: You don't need `new `.

Comment: @programmer500, I kinda gave up working on this when I saw ETH's version! :D Updated now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
k"^|$"¬qV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@5@tFFejonRoTWHY//9KiUnJKalpSjoKSiAKAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 21 bytes

```perl6
->$_,$b {S/^$b|$b$//}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#bY5dToNAFIXfZxU3DXVAB9AXY0pL3IO@WTUw3BoS/sLQpk3FxeijSzB96Ya6BDoDFKH6MnfmO@eeM0uBsLq1uEPiDVzwNECYVaarvTLNh@2D/aL575qv2XZZKcd9gaKAGURhgkI3rNjLJlsC8LH/jidvYMNh90kPuy@Y6jA1n@izewmG21GblGQpGx9likOyyEvgqo50yCLN23TTBX0eJmHB5jnG6QrZHNcZ8gIDA1RZKEB9VK89jcVgcPIwEFkeJsUCRuOba8FgfCdAhco5YtDfYl3u/sfKMI9IWVHP5wFSJidVW1S9SEfVWWMpKyrHr7VlfAB55xzmNm@p8EDe6uhWkKDX2Mxa6dFhRgf6e3jWc@Le/9zv@s@E9Z8ft8ImGFQcAQ)

### Expanded:

```perl6
-> $_, $b {   # pointy block lambda

  S/          # Str replace and return (implicitly against ｢$_｣)

  |   ^ $b    # starting with the second argument
  |     $b $  # or ending with the second argument

  //          # replace with nothing.

}
```

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic (TI-84 Plus CE), 63 bytes

```
Prompt Str0,Str2
inString(Str0,Str2
If Ans
sub(Str0,1,Ans-1)+sub(Str0,Ans+length(Str2),length(Str0)-Ans+1-length(Str2→Str0
Str0
```

Comment: I have a question, why didn't you use Str1 as a variable?

Comment: @Zacharý I think I had something stored in it at the time. I don't really remember.

Comment: What does `Ans` even refer to on the fourth line?

Comment: @Zacharý `Ans` refers to the last evaluated value, so in this case it refers to the value returned by `inString(`, which is the index of the substring `Str2` in the string `Str0` or 0 if the substring does not appear. An if statement does not modify the value of Ans, so on the fourth line the index is still in `Ans`.

Comment: Oh, I forgot how `inString` worked. Nice golf!

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>31</s> 30 bytes

-1 thanks to  [Zacharý](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55550/zachar%c3%bd).

This actually uses reverse (i.e. the inverse of) concatenation! Takes original string as left argument, and what to subtract as right argument.

```apl
{0::⍺{0::⍺⋄,∘⍵⍣¯1⊢⍺}⍵⋄⍵,⍣¯1⊢⍺}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P7g0qaQoMbnkUduEagMrq0e9u6DUo@4WnUcdMx71bn3Uu/jQesNHXYuAorUgfncLkNRBEf7/X11ZWTksMSczRQFmZGZ@npU6l3piUnJKqjpMEMjFFANxQIJAOQx1WMSwmpicAhRFNhKb1TCLUISBIigcoEc888qI8QoWwxITMcWSsDmmAltAVILdh@QAz7yC0hIrdQA)

Ungolfed:

```apl
{
    0::⍺{         ⍝ if an error happens, apply the following function on the arguments
        0::⍺          ⍝ if an error happens, return the left argument unmodified
        ,∘⍵⍣¯1⊢⍺      ⍝ inverse-append right argument on left argument
        }⍵
    ⍵,⍣¯1⊢⍺      ⍝ inverse-prepend the right argument on the left argument
}
```

Legend:

`{`…`}` anonymous function

`⍺` left argument of the current function

`⍵` right argument of the current function

`0::`… if any error happens, execute this, else…

`⍣¯1⊢` inverse

`,∘⍵` concatenate *⍵* on the right

`⍵,` concatenate *⍵* on the left

Comment: I think you can save a byte with `{0::⍺{0::⍺⋄,∘⍵⍣¯1⊢⍺}⍵⋄⍵,⍣¯1⊢⍺}`.

Comment: @Zacharý Yes, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <del>66</del> <del>61</del> 49 bytes

```bash
case $1 in *$2)echo ${1%$2};;*)echo ${1#$2};;esac
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@cWJyqoGKokJmnoKVipJmanJGvoFJtqKpiVGttrQXnK4P5qcWJyf///09MSk5JBZIA)

less golfed:

```bash
a=$1;
case $1 in 
    *$2)  c=${a%$2};;       
    $2*)  c=${a#$2};;
      *)  c=$1;;
esac;
echo $c
```

Uses case to test begining or end, and array prefix/suffix (% / #) substraction

Comment: Nice use of `case`, but longer than necessary. The 2nd and 3rd pattern could be merged into a single one: `*)c=${1#$2};;`. Then with only 2 branches would be shorter to `echo` each directly instead of using variable `$c`: `case $1 in *$2)echo ${1%$2};;*)echo ${1#$2};;esac`. Or you could keep using it, but without `case`: `c=${1%$2};[[ $c = $1 ]]&&c=${1#$2};echo $c`.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>69</s> <s>68</s> <s>64</s> <s>57</s> <s>51</s> 45 bytes

This ended up being a completely different solution with Regex.

*Thanks to [Value Ink](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52194) for -2 bytes!*
*and [Felipe Nardi Batista](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66418/) for the massive -6 bytes!*

```py
import re
lambda s,c:re.sub(c+'$|^'+c,'',s,1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#hZHLCsIwEEX3fsUIwiQaBLdCF/6HCHkVArWGTgQF/71OH1KtrW4yyb1nJpckz451oc/GaSBl95Xf0tUIu8HV44QbqxAVqZ1chHO8VAkqX2siz7tcoDbWeVRcUUKWATbHxbffrB3A5IfP57f2sWsHO5TQKqj4lkYZjRkF6YR3xjqW2iwvhJWpsF3tmCl/7obBmpzqZ5O9CP2PMEP2OeT24wV65O5GUWIVyiTwUBSQPCWwmjxBbDrdkh@6B3KxDmW8JiG3FIvAHfwVUspaG89zFHB9Ag)

Comment: For -2 bytes: `re.sub(c.join("^|$"),'',s,1)`

Comment: For -6 bytes:`c+'$|^'+c`

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, 162 bytes

```
(c=Characters;a=c@#;b=c@#2;l=Length;t={};If[l@Intersection[a,b]==l@b,If[MemberQ[Partition[a,l@b,1],b],t=a;Table[t=DeleteCases[t,b[[i]],1,1],{i,l@b}]],t=a];""<>t)&
```

test input style ["abcde","ab"]

Comment: Nice solution! You can save a byte by using `#` instead of `#1` — they mean exactly the same. Also, instead of using `StringJoin@t`, you can cheat by joining an empty string to it with `""<>t`, which automatically joins everything in `t` together too. Have you seen the [Mathematica golfing tips page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12900/tips-for-golfing-in-mathematica)?

Comment: There are a few more things you can do to save bytes (I don't think you don't need to define `t={};` at the start, for instance), but it might be easier to use a different approach entirely — have you tried using the `StringReplace` function?

Comment: You are allowed to take a String array as input, so you don't really need `c=Characters;a=c@#;b=c@#2;`

Comment: Also, `l@Intersection[a,b]` is `l[a∩b]`.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 54 Bytes

```php
[,$x,$y]=$argv;echo preg_replace("#^$y|$y$#","",$x,1);
```

[Testcases](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/34d575ef526f172bb1b56d3f9b88dd5a6cab580f)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>72</s> 65 bytes

```python
a,b=input()
l=len(b)
print[[a,a[:-l]][b==a[-l:]],a[l:]][b==a[:l]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@5@ok2SbmVdQWqKhyZVjm5Oap5GkyVVQlJlXEh2dqJMYbaWbExsbnWRrmxitm2MVGwsUAlEQESug3P//6onJScnqOuqJSeoA)

-7 bytes thanks to @FelipeNardiBatista

Comment: [golfed](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@5@ok2SbmVdQWqKhyZVjm5Oap5GkyVVQlJlXEh2dqJMYbaWbExsbnWRrmxitm2MVGwsUAlEQESug3P//6onJScnqOuqJSeoA)

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 68 bytes

```python
def f(s,c):v=len(c);print[s[v:],s[:-v],s][[s[:v],s[-v:],c].index(c)]
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#fZFNCsMgEIXXySmGQFBh0gNY2ouIi2Q0ECi2xCLp6VNNoe0iGReOvM/50bc6P8IoI5LS6XLzQZI6P@YpPE00SVuMRncpB2uyoMvJdEUne5qC80u@b9fxPkNEIJgCSCn6gZwXmKNQWMP/@sGy79GcdJzJQb4ruYy3tsxMn3jMd9C@@i3IVet7Bg7soAv7ta/yCKXrajMSmjZ708am3WxGEN1VYF0V14HU@gY)**

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 49 bytes

```hs
f s a b|s==b=a|a/=b,h:t<-a=f(s++[h])t b|1<3=s
f""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#bY3LCoMwEEX3fsWYVUKSPuhOnP5Bv8BmMdH6gCpiFGzx3632gbZ0M1zOPdzRmrRFHvVDH2oXU9XwQESGlJWyRyQj5dJd@ZnA6iNN0Jqn1ktpZ034/s7T@l7U/K/JyMbJhQm@/PigMQUHkz04RIs00BatyoM21IQpd9NCbkQ79fvwgM7LMGVsLKmoAKGk@gS8boqqhQ10Vdw1zQ0yARF/zadMzYEJBSsy328SJz/gHYRaMSbM@AA) Usage: `f"" "abcdef" "ab"`. Alternatively, define `(-)=f""`and use like  `"abcdef" - "ab"`.

This regex-free solution works by recursively splitting the string in all its pre- and postfixes and checking whether the string to be substracted matches one of them.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 88 bytes

```c#
s=>r=>s.StartsWith(r)?s.Substring(r.Length):s.EndsWith(r)?s.Substring(0,s.IndexOf(r)):s;
```

Compiles to a `Func<string, Func<string, string>>`.

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>20</s> <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```
pryr::f(sub(sprintf('^%s|%s$',b,b),'',a))
```

*-1 byte thanks to MickyT!*

Returns an anonymous function (which has arguments in the order `b,a`). Computes the string difference `a-b`. `sub` is a simple substitution that swaps the first occurrence of the pattern with, in this case, the empty string `''`. Constructs the regex with `sprintf` to match only at the beginning and end of string. Requires the `pryr` package to be installed.

On the TIO link, uses the more verbose `function(a,b)` definition for the function for four more bytes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/r#DcnBCcAwCAXQZRq@git0lYIKgVxsqcmtu9tc3@tn9RU@xx2kYpzLKJ93xOyEq@XX8oDYHgFEuTaruRoEruD6AQ)

Comment: What about the `'abcde','bcd' -> 'abcde'` case?

Comment: "`sub` is a simple substitution that simply swaps the first occurrence of `b` in `a`": Will this swap if the second string is in the middle of the first string?

Comment: I misread the question! Oops. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: you can get 1 byte back with `sprintf('^%s|%s$',b,b)`

Comment: @MickyT, thanks! fixed.

Answer (score 1):

#### Ruby (lambda expression), 29 bytes

```
->a,b{a.sub /^#{b}|#{b}$/,""}
```

Yay for regex interpolation! Requires regex-safe subtrahends, but that's okay as per the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/), 37 bytes

```
proc s {a b} {regsub "^$b|$b$" $a {}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/tcl#ZZB9bsMgDMX/zymeIg6wC/QkVSfxYVKkNImASJsYZ88caEuySQjMz89@lrfFzxoBSUJlJE9DWBX6T6F@hBI9hETKuesCRUQKkZUdWK20IUgFfnIDFT4BZ8t55etfH/LPHiWoUBuOuQ32KB@d9nuf5I1SPhTypxyetNXQsXNF8h/a/f6yr/NQhX2bdzs2sbMnqe9lJRBtMaMMwQ1TRXi4aaXJgFcavbzvoXHWkqdJE6udRbqG6N00QM@PRXrCNUC86kQrvEG00hsuF3zk4ggsK5v3CzuTqcY98wwaA50kVrrxJOnytv0C) (now running all tests)

Tcl is straightforward. `proc s {a b}` defines a function named `s` which takes parameters `a` and `b`. `regsub` substitutes `{}`, which is an empty string, for the value of `b` when it's at the start or end of `a`. The return is implicit.

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>21</s> 32 bytes

```
{sub("^"$2"|"$2"$",z,$1);$0=$1}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/awk#@19dXJqkoRSnpGKkVAMiVJR0qnRUDDWtVQxsVQxrDf//T0xKTklVSEzigjCAGMhKTIKKwBgIVckpQCZQGRdMCKIDxFYAAA)

Original submission naively replaced text within first string, not just at beginning or end.

```
{sub($2,z,$1);$0=$1}1
```

[Try it online !](https://tio.run/nexus/awk#@19dXJqkoWKkU6WjYqhprWJgq2JYa/j/f2JSckqqQmISF4QBxEBWYhJUBMZAqEpOATKByrhgQhAdILYCAA)

Originally tried without the braces, but it required tricks to print out empty lines and or no-matches which ended up adding more bytes than this version.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 96 bytes

It's common knowledge that string manipulation in C is cumbersome, as an extension golfing would be borderline masochistic. Sounds alright to me.

```
f(a,b,t,l)char**a,*b,*t;{t=*a;l=strlen(b);bcmp(t,b,l)?bcmp(t+=strlen(t)-l,b,l)||(*t=0):(*a+=l);}
```

One of the less readable programs I've written. Takes two inputs (despite how the function looks), a `char**` pointing to the string to deconcatenate and a `char*` which is the string to remove. The input pointer is edited in place and becomes the output (who cases about memory leaks anyway).

Example usage:

```
char *a = malloc(6);
strcpy(a, "abcde");
char *b = malloc(4);
strcpy(b, "abc");
f(&a,b);
printf("%s\n", a); // "de"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 121 bytes

```
(lambda(x y)(cond((equal(#1=subseq x 0 #3=(length y))y)(#1#x #3#))((equal(#1#x #2=(-(length x)#3#))y)(#1#x 0 #2#))(t x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDLDoIwEEXX8hU3bQwziSY@1vgvhdZHglQFE9jw6zotPhBZzNDT0zvJFOWpvjyo9P6Cvb@BWnSMU4WUSJm8sE5BugIj@YJYXyRc/hhT8J9SWEExRkgynjMOHthgfH4@qpucze85n2a3cfwIdKHOmJMZhs96kKzgbBo0UGlv0kUoWO4Qej9XkOWAZFvmnFsTV0WFryyRu95NSXqd1fe8dlcRV9DbjEpXHZqjeCyqXutWqGb@Pghkk9HybbYchbctKZvgN3LB/AgTpT0B)

The usual wordy Common Lisp!

Ungolfed version:

```
(defun f(x y)
  (cond ((equal (subseq x 0 (length y)) y)               ; if x starts with y
         (subseq x (length y)))                          ; return rest of x
        ((equal (subseq x (- (length x) (length y))) y)  ; if x ends with x
         (subseq x 0 (- (length x) (length y))))         ; return first part of x
        (t x)))                                          ; else return x
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 91 bytes

```
{a,b->val v=b.length
if(a.startsWith(b))a.drop(v)else if(a.endsWith(b))a.dropLast(v)else a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY@xDoIwEIb3PsWFqU2AByCCcXNgc3C@pgUaayFtwRjCs9cK4mDiDXd/8v3Dd7fea2VCMxq4ozIUbesKOFmLz8PFW2XaisFMIM6EGtzIC6AbSGG7DLLqE6EMM6Y8q97dqeS5lqb1HVENxdx5tN5dle8oZwxzYfuBTkxqJ2EtSCN@cI3O7xVcwm6BUIKVKGplJGVwLCBJvor8HxyioafxAxoVGSNLOEute3j0Vguy7hc)

Comment: ? `{a,b->var c=a.removePrefix(b);if(a==c){c=a.removeSuffix(b)};c}`

Comment: @mazzy feel free to submit that as your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, <s>34</s> 40 bytes

*+6 bytes when `Invalid Subtraction` test cases added*

```powershell
param($s,$t)$s-replace"^$t(?!.*$t$)|$t$"
```

Comment:

The regexp expression `^$t|$t$` does not work as expected: it replaces both matches instead one (flag `g` always on). So, we are forced to use the negative lookahead group.

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {
    param($s,$t)$s-replace"^$t(?!.*$t$)|$t$"
}

@(
    ,('abcde','ab', 'cde')
    ,('abcde','cde', 'ab')
    ,('abab','ab', 'ab')
    ,('abcab','ab', 'abc', 'cab')
    ,('ababcde','ab', 'abcde')
    ,('acdbcd','cd', 'acdb')
    ,('abcde','abcde', '')
    ,('abcde','', 'abcde')
    ,('','', '')

    ,('abcde','ae', 'abcde')
    ,('abcde','aa', 'abcde')
    ,('abcde','bcd', 'abcde')
    ,('abcde','xab', 'abcde')
    ,('abcde','yde', 'abcde')

    ,('','a', '')
) | % {
    $s,$t,$e = $_
    $r = &$f $s $t
    "$($r-in$e): $r"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True: cde
True: ab
True: ab
True: abc
True: abcde
True: acdb
True:
True: abcde
True:
```

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 57 bytes

Whegh, this is a mess in QBIC/QBasic...

```
B=@ `+B┘x=instr(;,;)~x|?_t_sB,x-1|+_sB,x+_lC|,_lB|||\?B

B=@ `+B          Prepend a string to B$. Thisis a hack to avoid errors with 
                 removing substrings stating at index 1
┘                Line-break in QBasic output
       (;,;)     Read the string (B$) and the to-be-removed substring (C$)
x=instr          And make x to be the starting index of the first C$ in B$
~x|              IF X <> 0 (ie C$ is present in B$)
?                PRINT
 _t                trimmed version (drops the prepended space)
  _sB,x-1|+        of a substring from 1 to x (the start of C$) -1
  _sB,x+_lC|,_lB   and the rest of the string, starting after C$
                     _l takes the length of a string
  |||              End TRIM, end Substring, end Length
\?B              When missing C$, just print B$
```

Answer (score 0):

I initially misread the instructions.  Thanks, [Ørjan Johansen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66041/%C3%98rjan-johansen) for pointing out my mistake!

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <strike>46</strike> 51 bytes

```powershell
Function F($o,$a){([regex]"^$a").replace($o,'',1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@@9Wmpdckpmfp@CmoZKvo5KoWa0RXZSanloRqxSnkqikqVeUWpCTmJwKklVX1zHUtK79/x8A)

Comment: This fails on the 'abcde' 'bcd' case.

Comment: I'm seeing expected results from that test case -- TIO [here](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@@9Wmpdckpmfp@CmoZKvE12Ump5aEauSqFmtkqhXlFqQk5icCpJQV9cx1LSutVZwU1BPTEpOSVVXUAdS6v//AwA)

Comment: It's a listed test case of the OP and the result should be `abcde` - `bcd` does not occur at either end of the string.

Comment: You are correct.  I misread the instructions.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), <s>71</s> 65 bytes

Accepting suggestions

```lua
a,b=...p='(.*)'print(a:match('^'..b..p)or a:match(p..b..'$')or a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/lua#@5@ok2Srp6dXYKuuoaelqV5QlJlXopFolZtYkpyhoR6nrqeXBJTVzC9SgAkWgIXUVdTBgpr///9PTEpOTAKSAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 129 bytes

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND(B1,A1)=1,SUBSTITUTE(A1,B1,"",1),IF(FIND(B1,A1,LEN(A1)-LEN(B1))>LEN(A1)-LEN(B1),LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN(B1)),A1)),A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <s>56</s> 53 bytes

```
s/^(.*),(.*)\1$/\2/
s/^(.*),\1(.*)$/\2/
s/.*,(.*)/\1/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1g/TkNPS1MHRMQYqujHGOlzwcRiDEEUTExPC6xIP8ZQ////xCSdxKTklNR/@QUlmfl5xf91iwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 19 bytes

```
Y'^.X:baRyNa?yb.'$x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/Uj1OL8IqKTGo0i/RvjJJT12l4v///4lJiUnJKamJSUAWAA)

Kinda sad this isn't shorter. The main problem is that Pip's `R` operator replaces *all* matches, not just the first one; otherwise, `aR"^|$"J Xbx` would work for 12 bytes.

```
                     a, b are command-line args; x is empty string (implicit)
    X:b              Convert b to a regex in-place
 '^.                 Prepend ^
Y                    and yank that regex into the y variable
       aR         x  In a, replace the following expression with the empty string:
         yNa?         Is there a match of y in a? I.e., does b match at the beginning of a?
             y        If so, replace y (b at the beginning of a)
              b.'$    If not, replace b with $ appended (b at the end of a)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Kotlin, <s>62</s> <s>42</s> 56 bytes

*+12 bytes I think that type definitions are mandatory in the Kotlin lambda with 2 arguments*

```kotlin
{a:String,b:String->Regex("^$b|$b$").replaceFirst(a,"")}
```

Test script:

```kotlin
var f = {a:String,b:String->Regex("^$b|$b$").replaceFirst(a,"")}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(f("abcde","ab"))
    println(f("abcab","ab"))
    println(f("abcde","bcd"))
}
```

Output:

```kotlin
cde
cab
abcde
```

### Kotlin (without Regex), <s>62</s> 76 bytes

```kotlin
{a:String,b:String->var c=a.removePrefix(b)
if(a==c){c=a.removeSuffix(b)}
c}
```