# Build a Semi-Zigzag

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

You will be given a positive integer `N` as input. Your task is to build a Semi-Zigzag, of `N` sides, each of length `N`. Since it is relatively hard to clearly describe the task, here are some examples:

- `N = 1`:

  ```
  O
  ```
- `N = 2`:

  ```
  O
   O O
  ```
- `N = 3`:

  ```
  O       O
   O     O
    O O O
  ```
- `N = 4`:

  ```
  O           O O O O
   O         O
    O       O
     O O O O
  ```
- `N = 5`:

  ```
  O               O O O O O
   O             O         O
    O           O           O
     O         O             O
      O O O O O               O
  ```
- `N = 6`:

  ```
  O                   O O O O O O
   O                 O           O
    O               O             O
     O             O               O
      O           O                 O
       O O O O O O                   O O O O O O
  ```
- `N = 7`:

  ```
  O                       O O O O O O O                       O
   O                     O             O                     O
    O                   O               O                   O
     O                 O                 O                 O
      O               O                   O               O
       O             O                     O             O
        O O O O O O O                       O O O O O O O
  ```
- [A larger test case with `N = 9`](https://pastebin.com/BHGM6p5y)

As you can see, a Semi-Zigzag is made of alternating diagonal and horizontal lines, and it always begins with a top-left to bottom right diagonal line. Take note that the characters on the horizontal lines are separated by a space.

## Rules

- You may choose any non-whitespace *character* instead of `O`, it may even be inconsistent.
- You may output / return the result as a String or as a list of Strings, each representing one *line*.
- You may have a trailing or leading newline.
- **[Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)** apply.
- You can take input and provide output by **[any standard mean](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)**.
- If possible, please add a testing link to your submission. I will upvote any answer that shows golfing efforts and has an explanation.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes ***in every language*** wins!

Comment: [Sandbox Post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/13500#13500).

Comment: Do we have to put spaces between O that are horizontal ?

Comment: @HatsuPointerKun *Take note that the characters on the horizontal lines are separated by a space.* – Yes, you do have to put spaces.

Comment: Ah, yes. I should learn to read. Thanks

Comment: What is the highest number test case? Haven't tried all the answers but they seem to get borked at anything that a screen can't take from one side to the other. (i.e. 15)

Comment: @JohnHamilton The answers should *theoretically* work for any number given as input. They must not worry about what a screen can hold.

Answer (score 10):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 24 bytes

```
ＦＮ«↶§7117ι×⁺#× ﹪ι²⁻Ｉθ¹»#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT0Awv9jaGFyY29hbP//77ym77yuwqvihrbCpzcxMTfOucOX4oG6I8OXIO@5qs65wrLigbvvvKnOuMK5wrsj//85)

-5 thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil).

AST:

```
Program
├Ｆ: For
│├Ｎ: Input number
│└Program
│ ├↶: Pivot Left
│ │└§: At index
│ │ ├'7117': String '7117'
│ │ └ι: Identifier ι
│ └Print
│  └×: Product
│   ├⁺: Sum
│   │├'#': String '#'
│   │└×: Product
│   │ ├' ': String ' '
│   │ └﹪: Modulo
│   │  ├ι: Identifier ι
│   │  └2: Number 2
│   └⁻: Difference
│    ├Ｉ: Cast
│    │└θ: Identifier θ
│    └1: Number 1
└Print
 └'#': String '#'
```

Comment: It was too easy for Charcoal :)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder This feels really ungolfed actually...not sure how to golf it.

Comment: The OP said that the character can be any and does not need to be consistent, so I was going for something along the lines of `ＦＮ§⟦↘→↗→⟧ι⁻Ｉθ¹→` (15 bytes only), but lists of directions do not seem to work right in Charcoal. A pity.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Tried that too but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: At first I tried `¿﹪﹪ι⁴¦³↶¹↷¹` but then I found `↶Ｉ§7117ι` which saves you 4 bytes.

Comment: `§` works on numbers? Wait; ohhhhh right it's a string. BTW it actually saves me 5 bytes.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Yeah directions aren't a datatype which makes it golfier on other areas

Comment: @ASCII-only Idea: maybe actually implement `dls`.

Comment: `dls`? That's a thing just it isn't actually a list, it's just syntax that makes it look like that. There's a good (ish?) reason why directions aren't a datatype

Comment: @ASCII-only I don't think there's a reason at all is there? I'd like to iterate over a `dls` with `ι` for example...right?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Well yeah but IIRC in the early stages we didn't add it because it would have caused a ton of ambiguities (plus it's ambiguous here, Charcoal doesn't have a print statement that matches two variables and really it'd just make so many other things less golfy)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63096/discussion-between-erik-the-outgolfer-and-ascii-only).

Comment: Oh, `PivotLeft` casts its parameter to an int, I hadn't realised that.

Comment: @Neil Umm, it doesn't? It doesn't seem to work without `Ｉ`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was just confused as to where the extra byte saving was coming from; I guess I must have just miscounted your original pivoting code. (Although, ASCII-only has recently changed Pivot to make the cast, it's just not live on TIO yet.)

Comment: @Neil You certainly miscounted...when it goes live on TIO I'll change it (benefits of no non-competing).

Comment: @CarlosAlejo `ＦＮ✳§⟦↘→↗→⟧ι⁻θ¹O` will work after Dennis pulls, `✳` being cast to direction

Comment: @ASCII-only You actually implemented that? wow

Comment: @ASCII-only `ＧＨ✳✳ＥＮ§⟦↘→↗→⟧ιθO` also works, nice! (Not quite what this question wants though, but never mind.)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer not exactly, that was meant to almost work, I just realized the way to make it work was to say to the parser you know it's a direction (btw they can be cast from strings and numbers too, cast atindex 7010 should work too

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>157</s> 153 bytes

```python
n=input()
o,s=q='O '
def p(k,t=q*n+s*(4*n-6)):print(t*n)[k*~-n:][:n*3/2*~-n+1]
p(2)
for i in range(n-2):p(0,i*s+s+o+s*(4*n-7-2*i)+o+s*(2*n+i-2))
n>1>p(5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1NCsIwEEb3OUV2nZkkaONPoZBewQOULgRbDYVJ2sSFG68eK@Lywfe@F1/5EdiWws5zfGZAEXRyi6sushK3cZIRZp3dQqwSwZHYnBHbuHrOkImxn@ltuB36lumws19Q9SAiWBRTWKWXnuV65fsIbOxmwl57Siqp8D9sjCWPP7Zbx287FNzVXYQTltJ8AA)

- `n*3/2*~-n+1` is the width of each line: ⌊3n/2⌋ · (n−1) + 1 characters.
- The string `q*n+s*(4*n-6)` represents the top and bottom rows. If we repeat it and slice `[2*(n-1):]` we get the top row; if we slice `[5*(n-1):]` we get the bottom row. Hence the definition of `p` and the calls to `p(2)` and `p(5)`. But since we need the repetition and line-length slicing for all other lines anyway, we reuse `p` in the loop.
- The `i*s+s+o+…` is just a boring expression for the middle rows.
- `n>1>p(5)` will short-circuit if `n≯1`, causing `p(5)` to not get evaluated. Hence, it’s shorthand for `if n>1:p(5)`.

Comment: Wow, awesome solution, so clever. You earned my upvote

Comment: Wow, never knew Python had short circuiting on comparisons like that, +1.

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, <s>126</s> <s>125</s> <s>121</s> <s>112</s> <s>104</s> <s>89</s> 86 bytes

```
(m=" "&~Array~{#,#^2-#+1};Do[m[[1[i,#,-i][[j~Mod~4]],j#-#+i+1-j]]="X",{j,#},{i,#}];m)&
```

- `#` is the input number for an anonymous function (ended by the final `&`).
- `m=" "&~Array~{#,#^2-#+1};` makes a matrix of space characters of the right size by filling an array of given dimensions `#,#^2-#+1` with the outputs of the constant anonymous function "output a space" `" "&`.
- `Do[foo,{j,#},{i,#}]` is a pair of nested do loops, where `j` ranges from `1` to `#` and inside of that `i` ranges from `1` to `#`.
- `m[[1[i,#,-i][[j~Mod~4]],j#-#+i+1-j]]="X"` sets the the corresponding part of the matrix to be the character `X` based on `j` and `i`. The `-i` uses negative indexing to save bytes from `#-i+1`. (I forgot to write `Mod[j,4]` as `j~Mod~4` in the original version of this code.) Jenny_mathy pointed out that we can use the modular residue to index into the list directly (rather than using `Switch`) to save 9 bytes, and JungHwan Min pointed out that we didn't need to use `ReplacePart` since we can set a part of an array and that `1[i,#,-i][[j~Mod~4]]` uses the odd behavior and generality of `[[foo]]` to save bytes over `{1,i,#,-i}[[j~Mod~4+1]]`
- Since [meta established that a list of characters is a string](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/whats-a-string) (as [JungHwan Min pointed out](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136660/build-a-semi-zigzag/136689#comment334433_136696)) we don't need to map any function across the rows of the matrix of characters since it's already a list of "string"s.

You can test this out in the [Wolfram Cloud sandbox](http://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com) by pasting code like the following and hitting Shift+Enter or the numpad Enter:

```
(m=" "&~Array~{#,#^2-#+1};Do[m[[1[i,#,-i][[j~Mod~4]],j#-#+i+1-j]]="X",{j,#},{i,#}];m)&@9//MatrixForm
```

Comment: Very nice! you can replace StringJoin with   ""<>#&    to  save 4 bytes

Comment: @Jenny_mathy Thanks for the tip! That seems pretty useful.

Comment: You can also replace   Switch[...]   with   {1,i,#,-i}[[j~Mod~4+1]]  and save 9 bytes!

Comment: @Jenny_mathy excellent! That's a great technique and seems so natural in hindsight. I'd love to use an offset or alter the Do ranges to avoid the unsightly +1, but those methods wouldn't save bytes.

Comment: You don't actually need `ReplacePart` here. `m=ReplacePart[...]` can be `m[[{1,i,#,-i}[[j~Mod~4+1]],j#-#+i+1-j]]="X"` -- You can `Set` a `Part` of a list. That gets rid of 15 bytes.

Comment: @JungHwanMin Wow, thanks!

Comment: `{1,i,#,-i}[[j~Mod~4+1]]` can also be `1[i,#,-i][[j~Mod~4]]`. This trick works because `[[0]]` returns the `Head` of an expression.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 179 bytes

```
Rotate[(c=Column)@(t=Table)[{c@(a=Array)[" "~t~#<>(v="o")&,z,0],c@t[t[" ",z-1]<>v,z-1],c@a[t[" ",z-2-#]<>v&,z-1,0],c@t[v,z-Boole[!#~Mod~4<1]-1]}[[i~Mod~4+1]],{i,0,(z=#)-1}],Pi/2]&
```

edit for @JungHwanMin

Comment: I didn't expect it to be that short, well done!

Comment: Just a question: Can `Mod[z,4]==0` be replaced with `Mod[z,4]<1`?

Comment: yes, I can golf some things down...

Comment: I don't really know Mathematica, but can you replace `Mod[#,4]` with `#~Mod~4` for -1 bytes?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder The same can be done with `Mod[i,4]` and `t[" ", #]` but not the other instances of `t` since you'd need parentheses for either the subtraction or the grouping with `c@`, so the total saving from that infix notation is 3 bytes.

Comment: yes, of course! fixed

Comment: Oops... accidentally downvoted. Could you edit the answer so I can flip that upside down?

Comment: `-Boole[!#~Mod~4<1]-1` can be reduced to `-Boole[#~Mod~4>0]-1`

Answer (score 4):

### C++, <s>321</s> 234 bytes

-87 bytes thanks to Zacharý

```cpp
#include<vector>
#include<string>
auto z(int n){std::vector<std::string>l;l.resize(n,std::string(n*n+n/2*(n-1),32));l[0][0]=79;int i=0,j,o=0;for(;i<n;++i)for(j=1;j<n;++j)l[i%4?i%4-1?i%4-2?0:n-j-1:n-1:j][i*n+j-i+(o+=i%2)]=79;return l;}
```

Returns a vector of strings

Comment: I got it down to 318 bytes: https://repl.it/JpJ2

Comment: Correction, I got it down to **239 bytes**: https://repl.it/JpJ2/1

Comment: Sorry for the spam, 234 bytes: https://repl.it/JpJ2/3

Comment: What can I say except you're welcome!

Comment: @Zacharý thanks you very much sir

Comment: Yeah, I don't have the will power to create huge golfs like this, so my mind focuses on small elements of other golfs, allowing me to golf 87 bytes off of someone's code and still not have a flippin' clue how it works.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>21</s> <s>20</s> 19 bytes

#### Code

Uses the new canvas mode:

```
Fx<)Nè'ONÉúR3212NèΛ
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/frcJG0@/wCnV/v8Odh3cFGRsZGgG552b//28GAA)

#### Explanation:

```
F                      # For N in range(0, input)
 x<)                   #   Push the array [input, 2 × input - 1]
    Nè                 #   Retrieve the Nth element
      'ONÉúR           #   Push "O" if N is odd, else "O "
            3212Nè     #   Retrieve the Nth element of 3212
                  Λ    #   Write to canvas
```

For input **6**, this gives the following arguments (in the same order) for the canvas:

```
[<num>, <fill>, <patt>]
[6,     'O',     3]
[11,    'O ',    2]
[6,     'O',     1]
[11,    'O ',    2]
[6,     'O',     3]
[11,    'O ',    2]
```

To explain what the canvas does, we pick the first set of arguments from the list above.

The number **6** determines the *length* of the string that will be written into the canvas. The filler is used to write on the canvas, which in this case is `O`. It cyclically runs through the filler string. The direction of the string is determined by the final argument, the direction. The directions are:

```
7  0  1
 \ | /
6- X -2
 / | \
5  4  3
```

This means that the **3** sets the direction to *south-east*, which can also be [tried online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fTEHJX0nBWOHc7P//AQ).

Comment: also note that canvas mode is in development and very unstable

Comment: :O 05AB1E is mutating into Charcoal (also this is beating Charcoal O_o)

Comment: @ASCII-only Yeah, I saw the rise of all the ASCII-based languages (Charcoal, SOGL, V, etc.) and saw 05AB1E sink into the background, so I had to do something about it :p

Comment: so you copied charcoal? :P 05ab1e even has a canvas and directional printing (although charcoal only supports this style of printing with length via python)

Answer (score 2):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 36 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
╝.H∫2\?.╝}F2%?№@.┌Ο};1w⁄Hh1ž}.4%1>?№
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUyNTVELkgldTIyMkIyJTVDJTNGLiV1MjU1RCU3REYyJTI1JTNGJXUyMTE2QC4ldTI1MEMldTAzOUYlN0QlM0IxdyV1MjA0NEhoMSV1MDE3RSU3RC40JTI1MSUzRSUzRiV1MjExNg__,inputs=NQ__)

The basic idea is to for each number of the input range choose either adding a diagonal or the horizontal dotted part, in which case it will turn the array around for easier adding on.
Explanation:

```
╝                                     get a diagonal from the bottom-left corner with the length of the input - the starting canvas
 .H∫                        }         for each number in the range [1,inp-1] do, pushing counter
    2\?  }                              if it divides by 2, then
       .╝                                 create another diagonal of the input
          F2%                           push counter % 2
             ?     }                    if that [is not 0]
              №                           reverse the current canvas upside down
               @.┌Ο                       get an alternation of spaces and dashes with the dash amount of the input length
                    ;                   get the canvas on top of the stack
                     1w⁄                get its 1st element length
                        H               decrease it
                         h              swap the bottom 2 items - the canvas is now at the bottom and the current addition ontop
                          1             push 1
                           ž            at 1-indexed coordinates [canvasWidth-1, 1] in the canvas insert the current part made by the Ifs
                             .4%1>?   if input%4 > 1
                                   №    reverse the array vertically
```

If the input of 1 wasn't allowed, then `ο.∫2%?.╝}F2\?№@.┌Ο};1w⁄Hh1ž}.4%1>?№` would work too. If random numbers floating around were allowed `.∫2%?.╝}F2\?№@.┌Ο};1w⁄Hh1ž}.4%1>?№` would work too. If I were not lazy and implemented [`‼`](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/P5ParserV0_12/data/charDefs.txt#L702), `}F2%?` could be replaced with `‼` for -4 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>228 226 224 215 197</s> 195 bytes

***-11 bytes Thanks to @Mr. Xcoder***

-2 bytes Thanks to @Mr. Xcoder

```python
def f(n,s=range):
 x=y=t=c=0;z=[]
 for i in s(n*n-n+2):c+=i%(n-(2<=n))<1;z+=[[x,y]];t=max(t,x);x+=2-c%2;y+=[-1,1][c%4<3]*(c%2)
 return'\n'.join(''.join(' O'[[k,j]in z]for k in s(t))for j in s(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9NboMwEIX3nGI2iJlgqphkFTNn6AFcLyIKrYk6RI4rGS5PTf9WT/Nm8X3vvsT3WU7b9jqMMKKoB4ervA10KSDxwpF7PpqVrStgnAN48AIPlIM0Urd06Wv2JUqDbcdC1Gmz1mxtUotzJvLHNWFUiUyquW36sjVLfjdaaWf78tyd3AFzSwWEIX4GqV6keppmL1j9JTxX1t7U5DJ4dbvD7cchEu3X9GtEtP0Lfk9ArUAf9yH34CXiiJ5UBmQEbV8)

### Explanation and less-golfed code:

```python
def f(n):
 x=y=t=c=0;z=[]                       #initialize everything
 for i in range(n*n-n+2):             #loop n*n-n+2 times which is the numberr of 'o's expected
    c+=i%[~-n,n]<n-1                  #if one cycle has been completed, increase c by 1, if n>1.                                            
    z+=[[x,y]]                        #add [x,y] to z(record the positions of 'o')
    t=max(t,x)                        #trap maximum value of x-coordinate(to be used later while calculatng whole string)
    r=[[2,0],[1,1],[2,0],[1,-1]][c%4] #r gives direction for x and y to move, adjust it as per c i.e. cycles
    x+=r[0];y+=r[1]                   #yield newer values of x and y 
 return '\n'.join(''.join(' o'[[k,j]in z]for k in range(t))for j in range(n)) #place space or 'o' accordingly as per the recorded posititons in z
```

Comment: Very nice work. Congratulations!

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thank you. I must say this one was tough, especially had problems identifying the correct range.

Comment: [Replace `c+=i%(n-1)<1` with `c+=i%~-n<1` for -2 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY69bsMgFIV3PwVLBBRcGbdDZXL7IvQOkWtaHPUSESJhD311F6vJcv6W812W/B3pZds@J8@8IH2FdKKvSQ4NK7BAhhE6u4LDhgXP@nca0pRviXjkDfMxscACsaugJ2pJ9XIYFYTDb0tHY1cFzhW9INoMP6cisi7Spjr2ukPtjDZVH7k1iG48vKItCpLr0C67m/p8v/wg/jzHQII/nEXu3FnPWBlW3HHO/zhZyr3NdzhlpNwuKVAWXrzV/Ac)

Comment: [215 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY8xbsMwDEX3nEJLYKmmC8vtFJW5CMshcOxWDkoHigrIHnJ1R06bLPwkl/f@eYrfo7wty7HrVa8FLhgO8tWZ3UYlnDBii7WbkXij@jEor7yoi5YXqaRszK4t0W/pWgkIU7MX/rBuLpEowcTsIv4cko6QjAv52UDNQBZsno@9sszUbt/ZpRID1eymNW0Ghi7@Bik@pXgdRi@6eKQaC6ITDJxlZl69Tn9e0Zj1Gv4tjVme0vda2oKy9VruHLxE3WtvIAMywiw3), `if 2>n:return'o'` is quite redundant. I made a work-around with `c+=i%[~-n,n][2>n]<1` instead of `c+=i%~-n<1`.

Comment: BTW, I am a great fan of this solution and want to contribute to its golfing. Very, very nice!

Comment: Sorry for the very late improvement, [195 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY9NboMwEIX3nGI2iJlgqphkFTNn6AFcLyIKrYk6RI4rGS5PTf9WT/Nm8X3vvsT3WU7b9jqMMKKoB4ervA10KSDxwpF7PpqVrStgnAN48AIPlIM0Urd06Wv2JUqDbcdC1Gmz1mxtUotzJvLHNWFUiUyquW36sjVLfjdaaWf78tyd3AFzSwWEIX4GqV6keppmL1j9JTxX1t7U5DJ4dbvD7cchEu3X9GtEtP0Lfk9ArUAf9yH34CXiiJ5UBmQEbV8)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks, and it's never late... :)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>106</s> 87 bytes

```
SparseArray[j=i=1;k=#-1;Array[{j+=Im@i;k∣#&&(i*=I);j,#+1}->"o"&,l=k#+1,0],{#,l}," "]&
```

Returns a `SparseArray` object of `String`s. To visualize the output, you can append `Grid@`. Throws an error for case `1`, but it's safe to ignore.

#### Explanation

```
j=i=1
```

Set `i` and `j` to 1.

```
k=#-1
```

Set `k` to input - 1.

```
l=k#+1
```

Set `l` to `k*input + 1`

```
Array[ ..., l= ...,0]
```

Iterate `l` times, starting from `0`, incrementing by `1` each time...

---

```
j+=Im@i
```

Add the imaginary component of `i` to `j`...

```
k∣#&&(i*=I)
```

If the current iteration is divisible by `k`, multiply `i` by the imaginary unit...

```
{... j,#+1}->"o"
```

Create a `Rule` object that changes element at position `{j, current iteration + 1}` to `"o"`

---

```
SparseArray[ ...,{#,l}," "]
```

Create a `SparseArray` object using the generated `Rule` objects, with dimension `{input, l}`, using `" "` as blank.

[Try it on Wolfram Sandbox!](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/)

Comment: there is something wrong with case n=3

Comment: n=2, 4,5,6 also have correctness problems, but I think this works for 7 and above.   I'm curious: is there precedent as to whether a `SparseArray` counts as an array? It can be visualized using `Grid` or `MatrixForm`, but I wouldn't normally count it as "a list of strings" here. If a 2D array of characters suffices, that cuts 8 bytes off of my solution (12 before Jenny_mathy's help), for instance.

Comment: @Jenny_mathy I don't see anything wrong... you may have pre-existing definition of `PlusMinus`, as this function never clears it. Running `ClearAll[PlusMinus]` gives a correct result.

Comment: @MarkS. read comment above?

Comment: Apparently, it's not okay to have the user manually reset the global variable [as stated here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4940/60043). Fixed by sacrificing 8 bytes.

Comment: @MarkS. Also, an array of string is okay [per meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2214/60043). If something is unclear, please ask the OP (as he/she makes the rules, not us). A simple search of "SparseArray" in this site gives an abundance of `SparseArray` responses, so I presume it's fine.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; I'm new to the site and wasn't aware of that meta consensus. That will make a lot of things with strings easier in Mathematica!

Comment: @MarkS. Also, [this page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12900/60043) has a lot of tricks on golfing Mathematica.

Comment: @JungHwanMin I edited my answer as you asked

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 197 bytes

```hs
a n c=take(2*n)$cycle$c:" "
r i n x y=take(div(3*n)2*(n-1)+1)$(' '<$[1..i])++(cycle$"O "++(a(2*n-i-3)y)++"O "++(a(n+i-2)x))
z n=take n$(r 0 n 'O' ' '):[r i n ' ' ' '|i<-[1..n-2]]++[r(n-1)n ' ' 'O']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BbsIwDIbP5CmsKFJioqC1HCYh@ghb76tyiEoFFsWggjaK9u6d27JNPtlf/v/LIV2PTdsOQwKGurilY@PyJaOp@7ptTL3RoFUHJPQO/cx39OnW8iZfOg4Z@gyNs2C3pspWK4rovZvTugQtSxobA4U19sL@juwp5HhHVA/gqRnYuA5exGVLKQSLm2p223m@aRtGCYc8Ru@rbvrAE5c2DpeO@PZB@0faS6qA3VktppvR74Vor4fzF7BanNLlDSYATuyo1CnRb@AfPptG5WscfgA)

*Thanks to @Lynn : fixed the spaces between `O`s on horizontal segments of the zigzag, but it costed a lot of bytes!*

Some explanations:

- `r` is a row of the output: it has the `0 y y y y y 0 x x x 0 y ...` format, the number of `x`and `y` depending on the row and the initial `n`
- for the top row, `x='0'`and `y=' '`
- for the middle rows, `x=' '`and `y=' '`
- for the bottom row, `x=' '`and `y='0'`
- `take(div(3*n)2*(n-1)+1)` cuts an infinite row at the right place
- every output has one top row and one bottom row except when `n=1`: `take n` handles this case.

Comment: Nicely golfed! You can drop a couple of those spaces, I think. And `replicate n x` can be replaced by `x<$[1..n]`. Also, your answer lacks the spaces between `O`s on horizontal segments of the zigzag.

Comment: @Lynn thanks! with the spaces on horizontal segments, my method becomes cumbersome, but i wanted to fix the code anyway...

Comment: You can save quite a bit by using operators and removing unneeded spaces, see [here](https://tio.run/##ZY5NbsIwEIX3PsXItWIPllETFpUiuAE0i@6aWpUVIrAIQwRpS6LePXV@FkgdzWI8b973fHS3U1lVfU9RsWncqVTJglAUbVGVokg5cKb8E@Ed2kne@2@1CifJQpGJUccolAS5Fnm8XHqLWqvJzDPg4RFwxpsVRq3W84q0NwlGd2Qd0EgFEko9hxiZyQDDNB9Dwxj616/NACeTWKt1rsbgWc6k7eurp@bdHzp3AIIN7C9QfzVvzXVLoPhr2HDQGm7Hy0/Qw8TTD@LI4H@dXb37fHB3kyHn3CJjZ@cH/nz0kDp878X2fw).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>155</s> <s>151</s> <s>146</s> 137 bytes

```python
m=input()
n=m-1
r=range(n+2)
for L in zip(*[' '*i+'O'+n*' 'for i in(r+[n,m]*~-n+r[-2::-1]+([m,0]*n)[:-1])*m][:1+3*m/2*n]):print''.join(L)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY4xCgIxEEX7nCJgkcxkoyYWSmBvsOABQgoLV0fIbAhroYVXj7uI3X88ePzymu8T@9ZyT1yeswbBfbZO1L5e@HbVbDyIcapykMTyTUVjVFIhGXVWhnHZq6XF6moidznhx7Kp0foQrEtGx9ztEzLEFQFzisGZA@adR04QSiWeldo@piUxQNv8e/L3wHUnCGIjR03Qjl8)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Ahh. I see now.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Fixed now.

Comment: I am one year late to the golfing party, but `\`L\`[2::5]` saves a byte over `''.join(L)`