# Sum \$\text{Square}^2\$

Tags: code-golf, math, number, decision-problem

Let \$n=42\$ (Input)

Then divisors are : 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 21, 42

Squaring each divisor : 1, 4, 9, 36, 49, 196, 441, 1764

Taking sum (adding) : 2500

Since \$50\times 50=2500\$ therefore we return a truthy value. If it is not a perfect square, return a falsy value.

## Examples :

```
42  ---> true
1   ---> true
246 ---> true
10  ---> false
16  ---> false
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes for each language wins

Thanks to @Arnauld for pointing out the sequence : [A046655](https://oeis.org/A046655)

Comment: Can the program output 0 if the result is true, and any other number if the result is false?

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```r
!sum((y=1:(x=scan()))[!x%%y]^2)^.5%%1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X7G4NFdDo9LW0EqjwrY4OTFPQ1NTM1qxQlW1MjbOSDNOz1RV1fC/kYnZfwA)

Uses the classic "test if perfect square" approach, taking the non-integral part of the square root `S^.5%%1` and taking the logical negation of it, as it maps zero (perfect square) to `TRUE` and nonzero to `FALSE`.

Thanks to [Robert S](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81727/robert-s) for saving a couple of bytes!

Comment: Could you use `scan()` to save a few bytes?

Comment: @RobertS. doh! I've been doing too much "real" R coding lately!

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>46 44</s>  42 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @Hedi*

```javascript
n=>!((g=d=>d&&d*d*!(n%d)+g(d-1))(n)**.5%1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dczRCoIwGIbh865iHSj/P3M2Mc8mdB0RMdwm5tpkWtDVL4NOJPxOH773Ll9yakM/zrnzSkcjohPNHqATSjQqTRVVdA8uUZh1oHKOCA4pZaeEY2y9m7zVzPoODFQlIiFFQebw1Lu18S9tWFnVi278jr@mkXb6w3qFK70wxs4hyPeSWIZX9pAjwO1ABiSiIQPJCEdmejvrAAYxfgA)

### Commented

```javascript
n =>             // n = input
  !(             // we will eventually convert the result to a Boolean
    (g = d =>    // g is a recursive function taking the current divisor d
      d &&       //   if d is equal to 0, stop recursion 
      d * d      //   otherwise, compute d²
      * !(n % d) //   add it to the result if d is a divisor of n
      + g(d - 1) //   add the result of a recursive call with the next divisor
    )(n)         // initial call to g with d = n
    ** .5 % 1    // test whether the output of g is a perfect square
  )              // return true if it is or false otherwise
```

Comment: You can save one byte with `d` going from `n` to `0` instead of `2` to `n` like this: `n=>!((g=d=>d?d*d*!(n%d)+g(d-1):0)(n)**.5%1)`

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÑnOÅ²
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MQ8/8Othzb9/29iBAA)**

#### How?

```
ÑnOÅ²
Ñ     - divisors
 n    - square
  O   - sum
   Å² - is square?
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), <s>434</s> <s>428</s> 415 bytes

```
,.Ajax,.Ford,.Puck,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Ford]Ford:Listen tothy.Scene V:.Ajax:You be the sum ofyou a cat.Ford:Is the remainder of the quotient betweenyou I worse a cat?[Exit Ajax][Enter Puck]Ford:If soyou be the sum ofyou the square ofI.[Exit Puck][Enter Ajax]Ford:Be you nicer I?If solet usScene V.[Exit Ford][Enter Puck]Puck:Is the square ofthe square root ofI worse I?You zero.If notyou cat.Open heart
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDNasMwDH4VPUDwoezkS9igA8Ngg8JglB68RCHeWqu1Zdr05TPL8UYOuwjrs74fKZ6P89yoxy97a9Qzhb5Rb6n7zkjHYLTadehRHvutZwwgg2B9DzJ7kKJfXGT0wMTjVOffdVHUH5TgE4FHhJhOQMOUAQud5eKlTSx/AU/W@T7L01CASyJ26DmT@YrohWbgSiHiQm/325vjkuZQk0nsJZAZINL0n3XpLskGzIBRi0ghrtZbRJ4QhOFdl2HTFs0jMqRYV6zscod1BCm/i/15rZpAxOJe1zGtHOmOgVT28MTiKgd6PeejjmgDz/PD5gc)

*-13 bytes thanks to Jo King!*

Outputs `1` for true result, outputs `0` for false result.

Comment: [415 bytes](https://tio.run/##bVDNasMwDH4VPUDwoezkS9igA8Ngg8JglB68RCHeWqu1Zdr05TPL8UYOuwjrs74fKZ6P89yoxy97a9Qzhb5Rb6n7zkjHYLTadehRHvutZwwgg2B9DzJ7kKJfXGT0wMTjVOffdVHUH5TgE4FHhJhOQMOUAQud5eKlTSx/AU/W@T7L01CASyJ26DmT@YrohWbgSiHiQm/325vjkuZQk0nsJZAZINL0n3XpLskGzIBRi0ghrtZbRJ4QhOFdl2HTFs0jMqRYV6zscod1BCm/i/15rZpAxOJe1zGtHOmOgVT28MTiKgd6PeejjmgDz/PD5gc "Shakespeare Programming Language – Try It Online") with a third character

Comment: @JoKing [371 with \[Exeunt\]](https://tio.run/##bZAxbsMwDEWvwgMYGopMXowWSABNLdCpCDKoMhOrdUhHopCkl3cowUk7dBHED/L9T6ZpnOfGPH@5S2M2HPvGvGX/rYoXsK1590hYPtv1BTPJbrsmwQhlABz1UGZ25WntHohlDEmQQFiGa8Uu@pUzfCrJ2AQyIEQ8ukC9onhfhVNmCUiiXXJGJAtl5MwxITjwTjqNEKQ631OUqA/zxItHoaV8VHARanXKLqIKtm7XfvzX6GAKB/OC1ZeCV/4PRu4qekSBnOpR7hs8oH@KyCzFZsltu9/ldQPzOulpBnRR5nn1dAM "Shakespeare Programming Language – Try It Online")

Comment: @JoKing [361 by referring to a variable by name.](https://tio.run/##bZCxCsIwEIZf5R6gZBCnLsVBIZOCk4hDbK@02t7V5ILWl69JtOLgEi4/fH@@ixu6acrU6mIemdqwrTK18@U1JKWAztW@RMI4HNcP9CSn45oELUQADFUQmVM8cl0DsXStEyQQlmZMtfmBPZwRpEFwvgeuxxAYKI0o7VJssTctVaGW6xTcPEuLJIGTOyJpiMydrcM3WQSdVpLFbBS1vyKOx3@vptvNG4sh0GrVg/60xqYigR0KeJfWn/2@yM/FMsun9d0QpiKumvaaDZ5oWW2H8CENGivTtFy8AA "Shakespeare Programming Language – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 55 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum(i*i*(n%i<1)for i in range(1,n+1))**.5%1==0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FckxDsIwDAXQGU7hpVKSWqiOSoeKnAQYgiBgif5WoQyc3qhvfctvfc2IVtLF3nm63TNh/Hwnp0GDQ6Mn8WWupKSgmvF8OGG04n0Ih2MjKXW2PbY/95GFYz@wdCzDddzvlqpYqTh4sz8)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>67</s> <s>63</s> <s>60</s> 59 bytes

*-1 bytes* thanks to @JonathanFrech

```c
i,s;f(n){for(s=i=0;i++<n;)s+=n%i?0:i*i;n=sqrt(s);n=n*n==s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dctBCsIwEIXhfU8hhcJM00CMxYUxeBE3JZIy0I6a6a706sbi2rzVg48/6DGEnKkTF4Fxjc8E4skbR0pd2aEozw3dzIVacuzlnRYQ3B@37L24Lc8DMWC1Vod9r0S8RKibx53rLkJvEd1fOZbA9udiY4rya7b8CXEaRsl6Ptmsp/kL)

Comment: Can `++i<=n` be `i++<n`?

Comment: @JonathanFrech that seems to work, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 5 bytes

```
ᛦq
```

Explanation:

```
      Factors
 ᛦ      Squared
       Summed
       is in?
   q    infinite list of square numbers
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//8PcCa0PZy8DUmsKP8ydOuv/f0MzAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>12</s> 8 bytes

```
f^₂ᵐ+~^₂
```

-4 bytes thanks to Fatelize cause i didn't realize brachylog has a factors functions

## explanation

```
f^₂ᵐ+~^₂            #   full code
f                   #       get divisors
 ^₂ᵐ                #           square each one
    +               #       added together
      ~^₂           #       is the result of squaring a number
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koKtrp6BUrvaobcOjpqZHHcuVSopKU5Ue7uqsAXHSEnOKwbzah1sn/E@LA6oBMrTrQIz//6NNjHQUDHUUjEzMgLQBEJvFAgA)

Comment: `f^₂ᵐ` is 4 bytes shorter than `ḋ{⊇×^₂}ᵘ`

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
─²Σ°
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RlIZDm84tPrTh/38TIwA)

### Explanation

```
─     Get all divisors as list (implicit input)
 ²    Square (implicit map)
  Σ   Sum
   °  Is perfect square?
```

Very similar to other answers, compared to 05AB1E I gain one byte for my "is perfect square" operator.

Comment: You know, something called "MathGolf" really should have a norm operator... that would have gotten you down to 3 bytes :)

Comment: @MishaLavrov that's not a bad idea! Right now I don't have as many vector operations as I'd like, one of these days I'll change that

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
Z\UsX^tk=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D8qJrQ4Iq4k2/a/S1RFSOx/EyMuQy4jEzMuQwMuQzMA)

As simple as it gets

```
Z\ % Divisors of (implicit) input
U  % Square
s  % Sum
X^ % Square root
t  % Duplicate this value
k= % Is it equal to its rounded value?
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
F²SÆ²
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPUYlQzIlQjJTJUMzJTg2JUMyJUIyJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9NDIlMjAlMjAtJTNFJTIwVHJ1ZSUwQTElMjAlMjAlMjAtJTNFJTIwVHJ1ZSUwQTI0NiUyMC0lM0UlMjBUcnVlJTBBMTAlMjAlMjAtJTNFJTIwRmFsc2UlMEExNiUyMCUyMC0lM0UlMjBGYWxzZSZmbGFncz1DZQ==)

##### Explanation

```python
F²SÆ²  # Implicit input
F      # Factors
 ²     # Square
  S    # Sum
   Æ²  # Perfect square
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>11</s> <s>9</s> 7 bytes

*-2 bytes from @Giuseppe and another -2 from @Shaggy*

```
â x²¬v1
```

---

```
â x²¬v1             Full program. Implicity input U
â                   get all integer divisors of U
  x²                square each element and sum
    ¬               square root result
     v1           return true if divisible by 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///AihYpDmw6tKTP8/9/ECAA)

Comment: [-2 more bytes](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46672095#46672095)

Answer (score 2):

### Matlab, <strike>39</strike> 37 bytes

```
@(v)~mod(sqrt(sum(divisors(v).^2)),1)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work on Octave (on tio) so no tio link.

**Note** As @LuisMendo stated, `divisors()` belongs to Symbolic Toolbox.

Comment: It looks like `divisors` belongs to the Symbolic Toolbox. You should state that in the title. Also, you can use `~···` instead of `···==0`

Comment: You can shorten this by using `sum(...)^.5` instead of `sqrt(sum(...))`

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>68</s> 56 bytes

```powershell
param($n)1..$n|%{$a+=$_*$_*!($n%$_)};1..$a|?{$_*$_-eq$a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVP01BPTyWvRrVaJVHbViVeC4gUgcKqKvGatdYgucQa@2qwuG5qoUpi7f///02MAA)

<s>Seems long ...</s>
*-12 bytes thanks to mazzy*

Does exactly what it says on the tin. Takes the range from `1` to input `$n` and multiplies out the square `$_*$_` times whether it's a divisor or not `!($n%$_)`. This makes divisors equal to a nonzero number and non-divisors equal to zero. We then take the sum of them with our accumulator `$a`. Next, we loop again from `1` up to `$a` and pull out those numbers where `|?{...}` it squared is `-eq`ual to `$a`. That is left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

Outputs a positive integer for truthy, and nothing for falsey.

Comment: the rare case where `$args[0]` is shorter :) `1..$args[0]|%{$a+=$_*$_*!($n%$_)};1..$a|?{$_*$_-eq$a}`

Comment: @mazzy It's not, because you need `$n` inside the loop for `!($n%$_)`. But, your rewrite of the sum saved 12 bytes, so thanks!

Comment: what a shame. so I would like to find a case where `$args[0]` is shorter :)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>26</s> <s>25</s> 22 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{~1!%+/x*x*~1!x%:1+!x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v7rOUFFVW79Cq0LLqsI2vkLVylBbsaLWQd3ESMFQwcjETMHQQMHQ7P9/AA)

**Explanation:**

```
{~1!%+/x*x*~1!x%:1+!x} / the solution
{                    } / lambda taking x as input
                   !x  / range 0..x-1                        \
                 1+    / add 1                               |
              x%:      / x divided by and save result into x |
            1!         / modulo 1                            | get divisors
           ~           / not                                 |
         x*            / multiply by x                       /
       x*              / multiply by x (aka square)          > square
     +/                / sum up                              > sum up
    %                  / square root                         \  
  1!                   / modulo 1                            | check if a square
 ~                     / not                                 /
```

**Notes:**

- -1 bytes taking inspiration from the [PowerShell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171955/69200) solution
- -3 bytes taking inspiration from the [APL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171960/69200) solution

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 18 bytes

```apl
0=1|.5*⍨2+.*⍨∘∪⍳∨⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///38DWsEbPVOtR7wojbT0Q9ahjxqOOVY96Nz/qWPGoa9H/tEdtEx719j3qm@rp/6ir@dB640dtE4G84CBnIBni4Rn8/1HvqupHvVttDa3UQ4pKU9UfdbeouyXmFKeq1x5akXZohYmRgqGCkYmZgqGBgqEZAA)

Anonymous lambda. Returns 1 for truthy and 0 for falsy (test cases in TIO are prettified).

Shoutouts to @H.PWiz for 4 bytes!

#### How:

```apl
0=1|.5*⍨2+.*⍨∘∪⍳∨⊢   ⍝ Main function, argument ⍵ → 42
                ∨⊢   ⍝ Greatest common divisor (∨) between ⍵ (⊢)
               ⍳      ⍝ and the range (⍳) [1..⍵]
              ∪      ⍝ Get the unique items (all the divisors of 42; 1 2 3 6 7 14 21 42)
             ∘        ⍝ Then
            ⍨         ⍝ Swap arguments of
        2+.*          ⍝ dot product (.) of sum (+) and power (*) between the list and 2 
                      ⍝ (sums the result of each element in the vector squared)
       ⍨              ⍝ Use the result vector as base
    .5*               ⍝ Take the square root
  1|                  ⍝ Modulo 1
0=                    ⍝ Equals 0
```

Comment: Can you do the equivalent of `not` rather than `0=` to save a byte?

Comment: @streetster unfortunately, I cannot for 2 reasons. First, APL's `not` operator (`~`), when used monadically, only works with booleans (either 0 or 1). Since any number modulo 1 never equals 1, if I used `~` instead of `0=`, I'd get a `domain error` on any number that's not a perfect square, since decimal values are out of `~`'s domain. Furthermore, I cannot simply omit the `0=`, since APL's truthy value is 1, not 0, and it wouldn't have a consistent output for falsy values.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 7 bytes

```
ð²ƩĐř²∈
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARgA5/9weXT//8OwwrLGqcSQxZnCsuKIiP//NDI)

#### Explanation

```
            Implicit input
ð           Get list of divisors
 ²          Square each element
  Ʃ         Sum the list [n]
   Đ        Duplicate the top of the stack
    ř²      Push the first n square numbers
      ∈     Is n in the list of square numbers?
            Implicit output
```

---

```
ð²Ʃ√ĐƖ=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARcA6P9weXT//8OwwrLGqeKImsSQxpY9//80MQ)

#### Explanation

```
            Implicit input
ð           Get list of divisors
 ²          Square each element
  Ʃ         Sum the list [n]
   √        Take the square root of n
    Đ       Duplicate the top of the stack
     Ɩ      Cast to an integer
      =     Are the top two elements on the stack equal to each other?
            Implicit output
```

---

```
ð²Ʃ√1%¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//8IZDm46tfNQxy1D10Jr//02MAA)

#### Explanation

```
            Implicit input
ð           Get list of divisors
 ²          Square each element
  Ʃ         Sum the list [n]
   √        Take the square root of n
    1%      Take the square root of n modulo 1
      ¬     Negate [python typecasting ftw :)]
            Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>78</s> <s>64</s> 53 bytes

*-14 bytes thanks to [Ørjan Johansen](/u/66041). -11 bytes thanks to [ovs](/u/64121).*

```hs
f x=sum[i^2|i<-[1..x],x`mod`i<1]`elem`map(^2)[1..x^2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwra4NDc6M86oJtNGN9pQT68iVqciITc/JSHTxjA2ITUnNTchN7FAI85IEywbZxT7PzcxM0/BVgEo7BuvoFFQlJlXopemqRBtYqRjqGNkYqZjaKBjaBb7HwA)

Hey, it's been a while since I've... written *any* code, so my Haskell and golfing might a bit rusty. I forgot the troublesome Haskell numeric types. :P

Comment: It's shorter (but slower) to avoid those conversions by searching for the square root with another list comprehension. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JclBCsMgEADAr5hbA6tkJeSk/UFfIGsitKHauAlNCx78uz10rvMM5@uxba2tolQ28vxmF72u0UiHShWCsuT9vkSDZF2SWNN/CJLXV6auG7y2llsOkYUVORy3WVyOd@SPWnvhRg0IepwAB8CJ2g8 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Shorter: f x|s<-sum[i^2|i<-[1..x],mod x i<1]=round(sqrt$toEnum s)^2==s

Comment: Building up on Ørjan Johansen's suggestion, [this](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwra4NDc6M86oJtNGN9pQT68iVqciITc/JSHTxjA2ITUnNTchN7FAI85IEywbZxT7PzcxM0/BVgEo7BuvoFFQlJlXopemqRBtYqRjqGNkYqZjaKBjaBb7HwA) should work for 53 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 23 bytes

```
n->issquare(sigma(n,2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYdBCoAgEAC/snjaBYUS8ZYfiQ4eUoRaNq1Drzc7DDMjsRaTpSdYoLMJpbXriXXHVvIZkbUl6lHkeJHBBJBa@B6p/lGQkIk0rM5qmDVY54engd@ofw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), <s>4430</s> 4305 bytes

```
Go to Post Office:w 1 l 1 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to The Babelfishery:s 1 l 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.0 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.0 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:n 1 l 1 l 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Rob's Rest.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to Rob's Rest:w 1 r 2 l 1 r.Go to Cyclone:s 1 l 1 l 2 l.[B]Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:n 1 r 3 l.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to Addition Alley:w 1 r 3 r 1 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:n 1 l 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.Go to Divide and Conquer:n 2 r 2 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Sunny Skies Park:e 1 l 1 l 2 l 1 l.Go to Zoom Zoom:n 1 r.Go to Cyclone:w.Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.Pickup a passenger going to Trunkers.Go to Sunny Skies Park:n 1 r.Go to Trunkers:s 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.Go to Equal's Corner:w 1 l.Switch to plan C if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Riverview Bridge.Go to Sunny Skies Park:n.Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Riverview Bridge:n 1 r 1 r.Go to Cyclone:w 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Sunny Skies Park:n 1 r.Go to Cyclone:n 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.Go to Multiplication Station:s 1 l 2 r 4 l.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to Rob's Rest:s 1 r 2 l 1 l 1 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to Addition Alley:s 1 l 1 l 2 r 1 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Rob's Rest.Go to Rob's Rest:n 1 l 1 l 1 l 2 r 1 r.Go to Cyclone:s 1 l 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Magic Eight.Go to Sunny Skies Park:n 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:n 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Pickup a passenger going to Magic Eight.Go to Magic Eight:s 1 l 2 r.Switch to plan D if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to Cyclone:n 1 l 2 r.Switch to plan B.[C]Go to Sunny Skies Park:n.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to Cyclone:n 1 l.Switch to plan B.[D]Go to Cyclone:n 1 l 2 r.Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.Go to Sunny Skies Park:n 1 r.Go to Rob's Rest:s 2 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:s 1 l 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Zoom Zoom:n.Go to Cyclone:w.[E]Pickup a passenger going to Joyless Park.Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.Go to Joyless Park:n 2 r 2 r 2 l.Go to Cyclone:w 1 r 2 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Pickup a passenger going to Joyless Park.Go to Joyless Park:n 2 r 2 r 2 l.Go to Cyclone:w 1 r 2 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.Go to Divide and Conquer:n 2 r 2 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Magic Eight.1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:e 1 r 3 r 1 l 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Magic Eight.Go to Magic Eight:w 1 r 2 r 1 r.Switch to plan F if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Riverview Bridge.Go to Joyless Park:e 2 l 4 r.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.Go to The Underground:w 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Fueler Up:s.Go to Riverview Bridge:n 3 l.Go to Cyclone:w 2 l.Switch to plan E.[F]Go to Joyless Park:e 2 l 4 r.Pickup a passenger going to What's The Difference.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:w 1 r 2 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.Go to Multiplication Station:s 1 l 2 r 4 l.Pickup a passenger going to What's The Difference.Go to What's The Difference:n 2 l 1 r 3 l.Pickup a passenger going to Knots Landing.Go to Knots Landing:e 4 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to The Babelfishery:w 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:n 1 l 1 r.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVjJbtswEP2VufUmNLLRg2/xFqCrEScoUMMHRhrJhBnSISW7/npXEr1QiyVaUYseZAPc5s2bmceRIvKbHg4PAiIBM6Ei@BEE1MPBDu6AJY9M/50Z9dbxBghsiFLIQ5QQCsrDdNfTCmFIXpAFVK1Q7h19WHF4oE4n1p422ntMcHQ@AlWwIzRKx0kE84hIb0WZD9/jV5SCiXBvt0jDqZoa8CMk/bgNjj6Klw8KHlFFtcvufT8BJDjcM4Yn85e9GbMyNZZxoaePXp850mAWw2WdoTHdUh@BcB9Ggr/FKJ27DgiR0GsgotLD/ODRy16WP9I66nk2zuGp3TuPOd/DfE1RwYzItXMjZ9pmeSIx72aBuhV@EdAAzahm/uiFv4R4zX407wXvd915PXmLCUvybyQkx3pXnmTM1yjVNV9MpKe1Om1vQaD35we15DjzHY28VTq9YYTDCGgAXEDCiJHb9XVKtyi3FHcwlNQPr4aFd0dwPgGKAI5lVRHiRs1pyKyqvOGNwfgWs4huGPVIVrCJEqT/bbZoy9WTRzFL66ffRlAMyVSGZDIrQbGRKFNs7WTKuAFKGIt3iWyU91q@SUg9mNBwFdXHvqWqWu27DaAxcgl9sZzHt5dzZSjzV0SFoaGzGC1bFb6N982YKvCMl9ewd6ZDpcUWupGrM7f1ZW2f2zYE520YF2XpklxMapukz2LPUL2nMzBPMHoC93yNX9T8pFJdMJAD/teQVHj979snU0ve28Gi0Xe2lVpTyU5Uai8KRT3trDnJhRaz0PUty7Dp3eyZ@yhDKWLuG69mxuix8bIvx2mMLJl93gzU9Y6nV5GVblkXJ85iumzNwc8ViRLxSh0a0yBAidzDFuJlXzD/Xe9UTYE@vHIuK0xm9aL3hYtIwdekqtO01mfmxpIw9Tv8RNCciMYnCqf80YKfPzEcDm7/0x8)

I went to a lot of places in Townsburg that I've never visited before for this program. Because this program is HUGE (mainly due to the fact that there isn't a one-stop way to take square roots; I still don't actually do that, though), I'm going to attempt to sketch out an explanation of this program.

```
Go to Post Office:w 1 l 1 r 1 l.

[Take an input line from STDIN.]

Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery:s 1 l 1 r.

[Take it to The Babelfishery, which converts the string to a double.]
[If you were to give it a double, it gives back a string.]

Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.

[We're going to clone this number by sending it to the Cyclone.]

0 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.

[In Taxi, numeric passengers are introduced once they wait at Starchild Numerology.]
[This passenger will be our running squares total.]

0 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.

[This passenger will be our counter, going from 1 to the inputted number.]
[Yes, it's starting at 0 here, but it is incremented at the start of our loop.]

Go to Starchild Numerology:n 1 l 1 l 1 l 2 l.
Pickup a passenger going to Rob's Rest.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Rob's Rest:w 1 r 2 l 1 r.
Go to Cyclone:s 1 l 1 l 2 l.

[Drop off the squares total at Rob's Rest. We'll pick it back up later when we need it.]
[Also, do the actual cloning of the inputted number.]

[At the start of each loop, our only passenger is the counter, going to Addition Alley.]

[B]
Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.

[Pick up one of the clones of the inputted number.]
[We will leave the other clone here for later.]

1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
Go to Starchild Numerology:n 1 r 3 l.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Addition Alley:w 1 r 3 r 1 r 1 r.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.

[Pick up the number 1, and add it to the counter, then pick up the result.]
[This new passenger is our new counter.]

Go to Cyclone:n 1 l 1 l.
Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.
Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.

[First we pick up the other clone of the inputted number, going to Sunny Skies Park.]
[Sunny Skies Park is basically a First-In-First-Out queue, where we will stick it for later.]
[Then we pick up a clone of the counter which we just dropped off, so we can divide the input by it.]
[We will leave the other clone here for later.]

Go to Divide and Conquer:n 2 r 2 r 1 r.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.

[Divide the inputted number by the counter, and prepare to clone it.]

Go to Sunny Skies Park:e 1 l 1 l 2 l 1 l.

[Drop off our clone of the inputted number at Sunny Skies Park.]

Go to Zoom Zoom:n 1 r.

[Can't forget to get gas!]
[Zoom Zoom is a close gas station, and we have so many credits that one stop here every iteration fills us up completely.]

Go to Cyclone:w.
Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.
Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.
Pickup a passenger going to Trunkers.

[First we pick up the other clone of the counter, going to Sunny Skies Park for later.]
[Then we pick up a clone of the division result, going to Equal's Corner.]
[Equal's Corner takes multiple numeric passengers, and returns the value of one of them if they are equal, but otherwise it returns no one.]
[Finally we pick up the other clone of the division result, going to Trunkers.]
[Dropping off a passenger at Trunkers is equivalent to the floor function. We need it here because division results are "exact".]
[(Well, as exact as double precision arithmetic can be.)]
[We will compare the result of this to the exact result of the division.]

Go to Sunny Skies Park:n 1 r.

[Drop off our clone of the counter at Sunny Skies Park.]

Go to Trunkers:s 1 l.
Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.
Go to Equal's Corner:w 1 l.

[Compare the exact division result with the floored division result.]
[If they are equal, then the value of one of them will be waiting.]
[This also means that the counter is a divisor of the input, and we should add the square of the counter to our running squares total.]
[If they are not equal, no one will be waiting, the counter is not a divisor of the input, and nothing should happen.]

Switch to plan C if no one is waiting.

[This is Taxi's only conditional operator.]
[It jumps to a bracketed label (in this case, C) if there is no one waiting at this stop.]
[Of course, there is an unconditional version of this, too.]

[If we are on this path, we are adding the square of the counter to our running squares total.]

Pickup a passenger going to Riverview Bridge.

[We don't actually need the passenger that's waiting here (and leaving it there will not work at all).]
[So what do you do when you have a pesky passenger you don't want? You take them to Riverview Bridge!]
[Riverview Bridge has a lovely view, but passengers dropped off there always seem to fall in the river.]
[This means you don't collect your fare for bringing them there, but at least the pesky passenger is gone.]

Go to Sunny Skies Park:n.
Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.

[We want to pick up the counter (so we can multiply it by itself). That dang input is in the way, but we still need it.]
[So what do we do? We just take it back to where it was waiting!]
[Yup, even though one would never do this in real life, a passenger's current location is a perfectly legal destination in Taxi.]

Go to Riverview Bridge:n 1 r 1 r.

[So long, Equal's Corner result!]

Go to Cyclone:w 2 l.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Sunny Skies Park:n 1 r.

[We clone the counter so we can still use it, then we drop the inputted number back at Sunny Side Park.]
[Again, we will leave the other clone here for later.]

Go to Cyclone:n 1 l.
Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.
Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.
Go to Multiplication Station:s 1 l 2 r 4 l.

[Square the counter.]

Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Rob's Rest:s 1 r 2 l 1 l 1 r 1 r.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Addition Alley:s 1 l 1 l 2 r 1 r 1 r.
Pickup a passenger going to Rob's Rest.
Go to Rob's Rest:n 1 l 1 l 1 l 2 r 1 r.

[Pick up the running squares total from Rob's Rest, add it to the square of the counter, then bring it back.]

Go to Cyclone:s 1 l 1 l 2 l.
Pickup a passenger going to Magic Eight.

[Pick up the counter, going to Magic Eight.]
[Magic Eight takes two numeric passengers, and returns the first passenger if it is less than the second, but otherwise it returns no one.]
[We will compare the counter to the inputted number...]

Go to Sunny Skies Park:n 1 r.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Cyclone:n 1 l.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Pickup a passenger going to Magic Eight.

[...who we take now, so we can make a clone of it and compare it to the counter.]

Go to Magic Eight:s 1 l 2 r.
Switch to plan D if no one is waiting.

[Compare.]
[If the counter is waiting here, the loop is to continue.]
[If not, switch to plan D, end the loop, and start detecting whether or not the running squares total is a square itself.]

Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Cyclone:n 1 l 2 r.
Switch to plan B.

[Reset everything, and loop back to the start of plan B.]

[C]

[If we are on this path, the counter is not a divisor of the inputted number, but the loop should continue anyways.]

Go to Sunny Skies Park:n.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Cyclone:n 1 l.
Switch to plan B.

[Reset everything, and loop back to the start of plan B.]

[D]

[We are finally out of the loop. Now it's time for the real fun.]

Go to Cyclone:n 1 l 2 r.
Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.
Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.
Go to Sunny Skies Park:n 1 r.

[We don't need the inputted number anymore, but we can't change its destination from the Cyclone.]
[So we go to the Cyclone, so we can take the two clones and bring them to Sunny Skies Park forever.]
[We could send them to Riverview Bridge, but that will take more bytes.]

Go to Rob's Rest:s 2 r 1 r.

[Pick up our running squares total from Rob's Rest, so it can go out and see the town.]

Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Cyclone:s 1 l 1 l 2 l.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Zoom Zoom:n.
Go to Cyclone:w.

[We need to end up with 4 clones of the total.]
[Two of them will actually be used as the counter in this loop.]

[At the start of each loop, we have no passengers.]

[E]
Pickup a passenger going to Joyless Park.
Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.
Go to Joyless Park:n 2 r 2 r 2 l.

[We will leave one clone of the total at Joyless Park (like Sunny Side Park, but on the opposite side of town).]
[The other clone will be used in a division.]

Go to Cyclone:w 1 r 2 l 2 l.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Pickup a passenger going to Joyless Park.
Go to Joyless Park:n 2 r 2 r 2 l.

[We will leave one clone of the counter at Joyless Park.]
[We will clone the other clone (clone-ception?).]

Go to Cyclone:w 1 r 2 l 2 l.
Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.
Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.
Go to Divide and Conquer:n 2 r 2 r 1 r.

[We will use both clones of the counter in a division.]
[Divide and Conquer can take 3 arguments, and the result here will be equivalent to total / counter^2 .]
[If the square of the counter is equal to the total, the result will be 1.]
[If the square of the counter is less than the total, the result will be greater than 1.]
[If the square of the counter is greater than the total, the result will be less than 1.]

Pickup a passenger going to Magic Eight.
1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
Go to Starchild Numerology:e 1 r 3 r 1 l 1 l 2 l.
Pickup a passenger going to Magic Eight.
Go to Magic Eight:w 1 r 2 r 1 r.
Switch to plan F if no one is waiting.

[We compare the result of the division against 1 to decide our next course of action.]
[If it is greater or equal, the loop should end, and the counter is equal to the floor of the square root.]
[If it is less, the loop should continue.]

Pickup a passenger going to Riverview Bridge.

[Whoops, we don't actually need this anymore.]

Go to Joyless Park:e 2 l 4 r.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.

[We will clone the total later, so we can reuse it in the next loop iteration.]

Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.
Go to The Underground:w 1 l.

[Instead of taking the number 1 and subtracting it from the counter, we can do an optimization here.]
[The Underground is a destination that takes 1 passenger, and subtracts 1 from it.]
[If the result is positive, it returns the result. Otherwise, it returns no one.]
[The latter result will not happen for us, however.]

Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.

[We will clone the counter later, so we can reuse it in the next loop iteration.]

Go to Fueler Up:s.

[Gotta remember to stop for gas!]

Go to Riverview Bridge:n 3 l.

[So long, Magic Eight result!]

Go to Cyclone:w 2 l.
Switch to plan E.

[Reset everything, and loop back to the start of plan E.]

[F]

Go to Joyless Park:e 2 l 4 r.
Pickup a passenger going to What's The Difference.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.

[Once we've figured out the square root of the total, we're still not done.]

Go to Cyclone:w 1 r 2 l 2 l.
Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.
Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.
Go to Multiplication Station:s 1 l 2 r 4 l.

[We actually square the square root...]

Pickup a passenger going to What's The Difference.
Go to What's The Difference:n 2 l 1 r 3 l.

[...and subtract it from the total at What's The Difference (which subtracts dropped-off passengers).]

Pickup a passenger going to Knots Landing.
Go to Knots Landing:e 4 r 1 l.

[If the result is 0, the total is a perfect square, and a truthy value should be output.]
[If the result is nonzero, the total is not a perfect square, and a falsy value should be output.]
[Luckily, Knots Landing does our work for us.]
[Knots Landing inverts the boolean logic of numeric passengers (i.e. 0 becomes 1, nonzero becomes 0).]

Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery:w 1 l.

[Convert it to a string...]

Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office:n 1 l 1 r.

[...and output it.]

[We would exit the program by going to the Taxi Garage, but that takes bytes.]
[The boss fires us because we didn't bring the taxi back to the garage, but that gets output to STDERR, so that's OK.]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
K²∑∆²
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCJLwrLiiJHiiIbCsiIsIiIsIjQyIl0=)

```
   ∆² # Is
  ∑   # The sum of
 ²    # The squares of
K     # The factors of the input
   ∆² # A perfect square?
```

Answer (score 2):

## Vyxal, 14 bytes ([Test cases](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLGm8m+4biKVOKAusabOio7xpIr4oiaOuG5mT0iLCIiLCIxLDQyLDI0NiwxMCwxNiJd))

```
ɾḊT›ƛ:*;ƒ+√:ṙ=
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLJvuG4ilTigLrigb0qTeKIkeKImjrhuZk9IiwiIiwiMjQ2Il0=) for 12 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ÆD²SÆ²
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm8uhTcGH2w5t@v//v4kRAA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm8uhTcGH2w5t@n90z@H2R01r3P//NzHSUTDUUTAyMQPSBkBsBgA).

#### How?

```
ÆD²SÆ² - Main Link: integer
ÆD     - divisors
  ²    - square
   S   - sum
    Æ² - is square?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
£İ□ṁ□Ḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fG5yvnaCtpKBrp6B0Yn3xo6bGokPb/h9afGTDo2kLH@5sBJE7uv7//29ixGXIZWRixmVowGVoBgA)

#### Explanation

```
£İ□ṁ□Ḋ  -- example input 12
     Ḋ  -- divisors: [1,2,3,4,6,12]
   ṁ    -- map the following ..
    □   -- | square: [1,4,9,16,36,144]
        -- .. and sum: 210
£       -- is it element of (assumes sorted)
 İ□     -- | list of squares: [1,4,9,16..196,225,..
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 5 bytes

```
ds¦Σụ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9nYWlh//9kc8KmzqPhu6X/ZeKGkcKm/1s0MiAxIDI0NiAxMCAxNl0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 41 bytes

```
a=>sum(q*q for q:1..a+1if a%q<1)**.5%1==0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@59m@z/R1q64NFejUKtQIS2/SKHQylBPL1HbMDNNIVG10MZQU0tLz1TV0NbW4H9BUWZeiUaahomRpiYXjGOIxDYyMUOWMUDmAGX@AwA)

Similar approach to the Python answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 32 bytes

```
IntegerQ@Sqrt[2~DivisorSigma~#]&
```

Pure function. Takes a number as input and returns `True` or `False` as output. Not entirely sure if there's a shorter method for checking perfect squares.

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / MATLAB, 43 bytes

```matlab
@(n)~mod(sqrt(sum(find(~mod(n,1:n)).^2)),1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI0@zLjc/RaO4sKhEo7g0VyMtMy9FAyyUp2NolaepqRdnpKmpY6j5P03DxEiTK03DEEQYmZiB2QZg0kzzPwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 34 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to nwellnhof*

```perl6
{grep($_%%*,1..$_)>>².sum**.5%%1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Or0otUBDJV5VVUvHUE9PJV7Tzu7QJr3i0lwtLT1TVVXD2v9p@UUKNoYKJkYKRiZmCoYGCoZmdgrVXAoKxYmVCkoq8Qq2dgpKdWlAQzS5av8DAA)

Comment: `**.5` is one byte shorter than `.sqrt`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>68</s> 67 bytes

```scala
def j(s:Int)=Math.sqrt((1 to s).filter(s%_<1).map(a=>a*a).sum)%1==0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcqxCoMwEADQvV@RRbgrIRgRh9IIjh2c@gHlqpEqGqN3BaH029Ohb37c0UxpfU6@E9XSGJQ/xIeeVRPjJ/V@UBPw5RYEXUvyMrztAmCVrIrRDOMsfgfOHleLZqEI5Go6Exp@L5hZ5/J09xuUhba6KCttc22r/zxcHfcxyBxgggMRT9@Ufg)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>75</s> 70 bytes

```java
n->{int s=0,i=0;for(;++i<=n;)s+=n%i<1?i*i:0;return Math.sqrt(s)%1==0;}
```

-5 bytes thanks to *@archangel.mjj*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hY7BbsIwDIbvfQpfkJJ1VC1CHAhhTzAuHNEOIQRmKA5LXKQJ9dlLClxRL5bsz/78H83VjI@7U2drEyN8G6RbBoDELuyNdbDqW4Ct97UzBFYkBCRVmrZZKpENo4UVEOiOxstbz6MuP1GXau@DUHmOC01KxlzTCBfVF37gvFTBcRMofeTfIv4FFlGOKp2O2k714kuzrZP45b963ME5pRNrDkiHzQ8Y@Yy2/o/szoVvuLgkxDUJKqyYTuQj5duFaoBPprMhQzm08DK0WdvdAQ)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{             // Method with integer parameter and boolean return-type
  int s=0,       //  Sum-integer, starting at 0
      i=0;       //  Divisor integer, starting at 0
  for(;++i<=n;)  //  Loop `i` in the range [1, n]
    s+=n%i<1?    //   If `n` is divisible by `i`:
        i*i      //    Increase the sum by the square of `i`
       :         //   Else:
        0;       //    Leave the sum the same by adding 0
  return Math.sqrt(s)%1==0;}
                 //  Return whether the sum `s` is a perfect square
```

Comment: Hi, you can cut 5 bytes by removing the t variable (do the eval and assignment within the body of the for loop), like so: `n->{int s=0,i=0;for(;++i<=n;)s+=n%i<1?i*i:0;return Math.sqrt(s)%1==0;}`

Comment: @archangel.mjj Ah, of course. Not sure how I missed that. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 67 bytes

```
func[n][s: 0 repeat d n[if n % d = 0[s: d * d + s]](sqrt s)% 1 = 0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rcm9CoAgGIXhvas4S9DPohINQTfRKt8QqeDyUWrXbzpUw4GH8wZr8maNpsYt2d18aCYdFwgEe9o9wYC1d2C0hStEjQZD2YhI1MUrJMS@hayV8hk8JzhMqnkpP6lp/l/xc84P)

Answer (score 1):

### F#, 111 bytes

```
let d n=Seq.where(fun v->n%v=0){1..n}
let u n=
 let m=d n|>Seq.sumBy(fun x->x*x)
 d m|>Seq.exists(fun x->x*x=m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7LCsIwEEX3/YqhULBCS5XSjSYLwb3QpbqommrApJpHjajfXicpiAMhgXPvmbQ6O3aKDcOVGTiBJDW7548LU2zSWgl9RmXSkyJ9zfJcfiKfspiKwL8Ewcab@oq2YvUMFZdRN3VphDYxMua4NvoPEpEO2@VaGvXcdFwaug9i0XAJjTr3gH6cbTlfwGwB87LCu8BT7QN4U/BebpiCUQsZDcSPV3FdW1HfbaMYEPyx@9GbwoWthDjhO5McYuz@hdOQK4Yv)

So `d` gets the divisors for all numbers between 1 and `n` inclusive. In the main function `u`, the first line assigns the sum of all squared divisors to `m`. The second line gets the divisors for `m` and determines if any of them squared equals `m`.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 47 bytes

```
$a+=$_*$_*!($n%$_)for 1..$n;$a=!($a**.5=~/\D/);
```

Returns 1 for true and nothing for false.

#### Explanation:

```
$a+=              for 1..$n;                      sum over i=1 to n
    $_*$_                                         square each component of the sum
         *!($n%$_)                                multiply by 1 if i divides n.
                            $a=                   a equals
                                ($a**.5           whether the square root of a
                               !       =~/\D/);   does not contain a non-digit.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 47 bytes

A lambda accepting a numeric argument.

```
n->s=(1..n).sum{i->n%i?0:i*i}
!(s%Math.sqrt(s))
```

**Explanation**

`(1..n)` creates an array of the values 1 to n

`n%i` is false (as 0 is falsy) if `i` divides `n` without remainder

`n%i ? 0 : i*i` is the sum of the square of the value `i` if it divides `n` without remainder, otherwise is 0

`sum{ i-> n%i ? 0 : i*i }` sums the previous result across all `i` in the array.

`s%Math.sqrt(s)` is false (as 0 is falsy) if the sqrt of `s` divides `s` without remainder

`!(s%Math.sqrt(s))` returns from the lambda (`return` implicit on last statement) `!false` when the sqrt of `s` divides `s` without remainder

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/J@SmqaQk5iblJKoYKtQ/T9P167YVsNQTy9PU6@4NLc6U9cuTzXT3sAqUyuzlktRo1jVN7EkQ6@4sKhEo1hT838tV0FRZl5JTh7UEA0TI010IUMMESMTM0xVBphCQFVFqSWlRXn/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>10</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
▀ùj╦┬44eR
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=df976acbc234346552&i=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A36%0A37%0A38%0A39%0A40%0A41%0A42%0A43%0A44%0A245%0A246%0A247%0A286%0A287%0A288&a=1&m=2)

#### Unpacked (11 bytes) and explanation:

```
:d{J+kc|qJ=
:d             Implicit input. Make list of divisors.
  {  k         Reduce using block:
   J+            Square and add to the running total.
      c        Copy this sum of squares on the stack.
       |qJ     Take square root, rounding down. Square.
          =    Check for equality.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>141</s> <s>137</s> <s>135</s> <s>131</s> 61 bytes

Thanks ASCII-only.

```
a=>Math.Sqrt(Enumerable.Range(1,a).Sum(b=>a%b==0?b*b:0))%1==0
```

Explanation:

```
a => Math.Sqrt(                                                    ) % 1 == 0 //Square root, test for whole number
               Enumerable.Range(1, a).Sum(                        ) //Sum 1 through a with..
                                          b => a % b==0 ? b * b: 0 //b^2 if a modulo b = 0, else 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5lXoqOQlJ@fY6eQpmD7P9HWzjexJEMvuLCoRMM1rzQ3tSgxKSdVLygxLz1Vw1AnUVMvuDRXI8nWLlE1ydbWwD5JK8nKQFNT1RDI@W/NFVAENFAjTcPESFPT@v9/AA)

Comment: Divide by zero exception because division by zero is undefined...

Comment: [Fixed?](https://tio.run/##DcqxCsIwEADQX8lSSGwtrTiZHg7OBaGD891ZNVAT7J2ClH579M2PZcvCOb8lxLsZvqLj0/OEIua8iKIGNp8UrqbHEK1bQlSDsN9VVDE0/pZmS9B66gA9laXjErAggOZIGzo0/pSipGmsL3PQ0faoj3p4zWrZFe1/Ob@uOecf)

Comment: Wait... this isn't valid

Comment: [here](https://tio.run/##RY2xCsIwFEVn@xVZComtpRUn09RBcCsIHZyTZ4qBmmDyKkjpt8cMguu5h3sg7CBAhEmGQK5Ltgko0QB5O3MnvTSWsgQ3wyegflaX2UJrLJZEOTd1ZCQiStEtCRFVgqj56DxVouGqFZKromBQCJkrIeqT2qpjzb3G2VvyO@wlPqrh5ZECy5tk8TXyf@/sbHCTrm7eoKYjPewZS/OarTF@AQ)

Comment: [using the implicit imports of the REPL](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5lXoqOQlJ@fY6eQpmD7P9HWzjexJEMvuLCoRMM1rzQ3tSgxKSdVLygxLz1Vw1AnUVMvuDRXI8nWLlE1ydbWwD5JK8nKQFNT1RDI@W/NFVAENFAjTcPESFPT@v9/AA) (mostly for free LINQ)

Comment: Thanks @ASCII-only!

Comment: Note that REPL counts as a different language (well, different implementation) because it behaves differently to normal C# (mostly the imports)

Comment: @ASCIIOnly - How about `a%b==0` vs `a%b<1` ?

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <strike>26</strike> 16 bytes

```
!%@s^R2*M{yPQ2 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/37PQQDWuODcuxUjLt7oyIDDZMMMwI8rQ2uD/fxMjAA)

I'm new to Pyth (and golfing in general) so this is pretty bad. Pyth doesn't have a built-in to get divisors, so I had to do that. Up until the perfect-square check, it was pretty alright, but after that it became a bit cluttered because of the if statement. Criticism is welcome.

*-10 bytes thanks to Sok*

Explanation:

```
            Q               #get user input
       *M{yP                #get the divisors
    ^R2                     #square each divisor
   s                        #sum the list
  @          2              #get square root
 %             1            #check if sqrt is a whole number (mod 1)
!                           #invert (0 -> True, any other num -> False)
```

Comment: A few savings for you - `m^d2` can be `^R2`, and `@` functions as the root operator, so `^...c1h1` can be `@...2`. The return value is if the root mod 1 is non-zero - that is, should return True if the result of the mod is 0, and False otherwise - this means we can just use `!` to invert the truthiness of the mod. Full program is then `!%@s^R2*M{yPQ2 1` - [demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%21%25%40s%5ER2%2aM%7ByPQ2+1&input=42&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>24</s> 20 bytes

```
1∣Norm@Divisors@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/d/wUcdiv/yiXAeXzLLM4vyiYgdltf/6DgrVJkY6hjpGJmY6hgY6hma1sf8B)

`Divisors` finds all the divisors of a number, `Norm` takes the square root of the sum of squares, and then we test if this is divisible by 1 (i.e., is an integer).

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>115</s> 74 bytes

Thanks to user [Misha Lavrov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/74672/misha-lavrov) for teaching me how to properly do code golf! :)

```cs
a=>{int s=0;for(int i=0;i++<=a;)s+=a%i==0?i*i:0;return Math.Sqrt(s)%1==0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1NC8IwEETv/RV7EVKrpX7gwRg9CIKgFxU8x5jqQk0wuxWk9LfXKDinx8yDMTQ0PtiuJnQ3OL6J7UOaShPBpUmINaOBTe0MLNDx4OJ9tYRSdVotm1gAqUKWPogvY2TMsoXSMqVM6R4qVaywj/NCBst1cLDXfM@Pz8CC0t4ozrLt5P/m5fEaDXQibRIAWHtHvrL5OSDbHTorShG7lw2cn/zW8WQs/s7B6utPSWNk0rbdeDr7AA)

Ungolfed:

```cs
a => {                              // reads input
    int s = 0;                      // holds sum of squares
    for(int i = 0; i++ <= a;)       // index from 1 to input, inclusive
    {
        s +=                        // add to sum
            a % i == 0 ?            // check if remainder of input divided by current index is zero
                i * i : 0;          // if true, add square of current index, else add zero
    }
    return Math.Sqrt(s) % 1 == 0;   // prints "True" if square root is whole number, "False" otherwise
}
```

Comment: I think it's standard to do input and output via a pure function, something like [this](https://tio.run/##NY1NC8IwEETv/RV7EVKrpX7gwRg9CIKgFxU8x5jqQk0wuxWk9LfXKDinx8yDMTQ0PtiuJnQ3OL6J7UOaShPBpUmINaOBTe0MLNDx4OJ9tYRSdVotm1gAqUKWPogvY2TMsoXSMqVM6R4qVaywj/NCBst1cLDXfM@Pz8CC0t4ozrLt5P/m5fEaDXQibRIAWHtHvrL5OSDbHTorShG7lw2cn/zW8WQs/s7B6utPSWNk0rbdeDr7AA). So you don't have to count the length of `Console.ReadLine()` and such, that way.

Comment: Good to know, thank you. I'll keep this in mind for the future!

Comment: [using the interpreter saves a bit](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5lXoqOQlJ@fY6eQpmD7P9HWzjexJEMvuLCoRMM1rzQ3tSgxKSdVLygxLz1Vw1AnUVMvuDRXI8nWLlE1ydbWwD5JK8nKQFNT1RDI@W/NFVAENFAjTcPESFPT@v9/AA), although i've already posted this link on the other C# answer, so not sure what to do

Comment: Also, invalid, you need to use `System.Math.Sqrt` - the `System` import isn't free, so this is the cheapest alternative

Comment: [also, no need to convert input since this is a function](https://tio.run/##NY2xCsIwFEX3fsVbConVUkUcTFMHwUmnDs5pTPVBTTAvFaT022Mc3A73XDiaVtp5E0dCe4f2Q8E8hR4UEXRTRkEF1HAarYYabVh2zg0N9DIq2UxpAJKV6J1nP8bEWBS1VIJTIVWOUlYHXOC@Et6E0Vu4qPAo25cPjHi@TlrMUfwzb4e39EDL@JQBwNFZcoMprx6DOaM1rGeb7Y5zkc1z/AI)

Comment: Ok, still working on how it wants a link..

Comment: 70 bytes.  `a=>{int s=0,i=0;for(;i++<=a;)s+=a%i>0?0:i*i;return Math.Sqrt(s)%1==0;}`

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 5 bytes

```
V²ΣÆ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr/P@zQpnOLD7cd2vT/v4kRAA)
Explanation:

```
V²ΣÆ²    
V      Pushes input's divisors
 ²     Squares
   Σ   Sum
    Æ² Returns whether value is a proper square.
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 23 chars, 46 bytes

```
{0=1∣√+/×⍨(0=a∣⍵)/a←⍳⍵}
```

test:

```
   g←{0=1∣√+/×⍨(0=a∣⍵)/a←⍳⍵}     
   g¨ 42 1 246 10 16
1 1 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 39 bytes

```arturo
$=>[=floor<=sqrt∑map factors&'x->x*x]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?9sVxUj)

```
$=>[              ; a function where input is assigned to &
    factors&      ; divisors of the input
    map _ 'x->x*x ; square each
    ∑             ; sum
    sqrt          ; square root
    <=            ; duplicate
    floor         ; floor
    =             ; are the equal?
]                 ; end function
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 45 bytes

```ruby
->n{(1..n).map{n%_1<1?_1*_1:0}.sum**0.5%1==0}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsHiNNuYpaUlaboWN3V17fKqNQz19PI09XITC6rzVOMNbQzt4w214g2tDGr1iktztbQM9ExVDW1tDWqhmuzKMzJzUhXSU0uKuRQKSkuKFZTSopWrVeL1kjPycwv0irJKi0s0jDVrYxVsFZSr06KBMiX58ZmxtUpcqXkpEFMWrDMx4jLkMjIx4zI04DI0g4gCAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 33 bytes

```lua
nt(sqrt(1+sum(factors(n)|x^2))%1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/z@vRKO4sKhEw1C7uDRXIy0xuSS/qFgjT7OmIs5IU1PVUPP///8mRgA)