# Tips for Golfing in Symja

Tags: tips

Symja is a ["computer algebra language & Java symbolic math library for Android NCalc calculator"](https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library). It's a fun little language, so I'm wondering if y'all have any tips for golfing in Symja.

<s>As per usual, "remove comments", etc, isn't really an answer.</s> It turns out that there is no comment system in Symja, so "remove comments" isn't an answer. :P

Comment: remove comments

Comment: @QuoraExpert I would, but there are no comments to remove in the first place! :P

Comment: I should use this language more, that way I don't have to make up any excuses for never commenting my code :D

Comment: LOL! NICE EDIT!!

Comment: This language is basically just Mathematica but uses round brackets instead of square ones, so [Tips for golfing in Mathematica](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12900/tips-for-golfing-in-mathematica) would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

## Don't Use `Print`...Use the Formatted Output

Here's an example fizzbuzz:

```
For(i=1,i<101,i++,s="";If(Mod(i,5)==0,s=s<>"Fizz");If(Mod(i,3)==0,s=s<>"Buzz");If(Mod(i,5)*Mod(i,3)!=0,s=s<>ToString(i));Print(s))
```

Now, this is alright, but it can be improved:

```
For(i=1,i<101,i++,If(Mod(i,5)==0,s=s<>"Fizz");If(Mod(i,3)==0,s=s<>"Buzz");If(Mod(i,5)*Mod(i,3)!=0,s=s<>ToString(i));s=s<>"\n");s
```

Sure, it's only two bytes shorter, but hey, *it's two bytes shorter*.

Just put all the output into a string and tack a `;<variable_name>` onto the end and you'll have a shorter program (usually).