# Flatten a parabola keeping the distances between points along the curve constant

Tags: code-golf, math

#### Background

Math SE's HNQ [How to straighten a parabola?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4209381/284619) has 4,000+ views, ~60 up votes, 16 bookmarks and six answers so far and has a related companion HNQ in Mathematica SE [How to straighten a curve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/251570/47301) which includes a second part asking to move a point cloud along with the curve that we can ignore here.

From the Math SE question:

> Consider the function \$f(x)=a_0x^2\$ for some \$a_0\in \mathbb{R}^+\$. Take \$x_0\in\mathbb{R}^+\$ so that the arc length \$L\$ between \$(0,0)\$ and \$(x_0,f(x_0))\$ is fixed. Given a different arbitrary \$a_1\$, how does one find the point \$(x_1,y_1)\$ so that the arc length is the same?
>
> Schematically,
>
> [image: flattening a parabola]
>
> In other words, I'm looking for a function \$g:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}\$, \$g(a_0,a_1,x_0)\$, that takes an initial fixed quadratic coefficient \$a_0\$ and point and returns the corresponding point after "straightening" via the new coefficient \$a_1\$, keeping the arc length with respect to \$(0,0)\$. Note that the \$y\$ coordinates are simply given by \$y_0=f(x_0)\$ and \$y_1=a_1x_1^2\$.
>
> [image: flattening a parabola]

#### Problem

Given a positive integer n and values a<sub>0</sub> and a<sub>1</sub> defining the original and new parabolas:

1. Generate \$n\$ equally spaced values for \$x_0\$ from 0 to 1 and corresponding  \$y_0\$ values.
2. Calculate the new \$x_1\$ and \$y_1\$ such that their path distances along the new parabola are equal to their old distances.
3. Output the \$x_0\$, \$x_1\$ and \$y_1\$ lists so that a user could plot the two parabolas.

**note:** The basis of the calculation can come from any of the answers to either linked question or something totally different. If you choose to use a numerical rather than analytical solution an error of \$1 \times 10^{-3}\$ would be sufficient for the user to make their plot.

Regular Code Golf; goal is shortest answer.

#### Example

This is quite a bit late but here is an example calculation and results. I chose the same numbers as in Eta's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233178/85527) in order to check my math.

[image: flattening the parabola code golf]

```
s0: [0.00000, 0.13589, 0.32491, 0.59085, 0.94211, 1.38218, 1.91278, 2.53486, 3.24903]
x0: [0.00000, 0.12500, 0.25000, 0.37500, 0.50000, 0.62500, 0.75000, 0.87500, 1.00000]
x1: [0.00000, 0.13248, 0.29124, 0.46652, 0.64682, 0.82802, 1.00900, 1.18950, 1.36954]
```

script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import root

def get_lengths(x, a): # https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+sqrt%281%2B4+a%5E2x%5E2%29+x%3D0+to+1
    return 0.5 * x * np.sqrt(4 * a**2 * x**2 + 1) + (np.arcsinh(2 * a * x)) / (4 * a)

def mini_me(x, a, targets):
    return get_lengths(x, a) - targets

a0, a1 = 3, 1.5

x0 = np.arange(9)/8

lengths_0 = get_lengths(x0, a0)

wow = root(mini_me, x0.copy(), args=(a1, lengths_0))

x1 = wow.x

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

y0, y1 = a0 * x0**2, a1 * x1**2

ax.plot(x0, y0, '-')
ax.plot(x0, y0, 'ok')

ax.plot(x1, y1, '-')
ax.plot(x1, y1, 'ok')

np.set_printoptions(precision=5, floatmode='fixed')

things = [str(q).replace(' ', ', ') for q in (lengths_0, x0, x1)]
names = [q + ': ' for q in ('s0', 'x0', 'x1')]

for name, thing in zip(names, things):
    print('    ' + name + thing)
    
_, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
xmin, _ = ax.get_xlim()

ax.text(x0[-1:]+0.03, y0[-1:]-0.1, str(a0) + 'x²')
ax.text(x1[-1:]-0.04, y1[-1:]-0.1, str(a1) + 'x²', horizontalalignment='right')

title = '\n'.join([name + thing for (name, thing) in zip(names, things)])

ax.set_title(title, fontsize=9)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you provide some test cases?

Comment: @Bubbler Ah! Yes I should have done that. I'll do so within an hour. *Thanks!* (perhaps your advice can also be mentioned in [Is my third code golf question too hard, or just not sufficiently low-hanging fruit? What might I do to make the number of answers nonzero?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23746/85527) in meta?)

Comment: Feel free to mess around with a copy of [my solution's Wolfram Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/eta./Published/CurveFlattening.nb) to generate, verify, and/or visualize some test cases!

Comment: @Eta I've finally added an example, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, <del>108</del> 107 bytes

```
{n,a,b}=Input[];L=ArcLength;Subdivide@--n
x/.FindRoot[{t,t^2a}~L~{t,0,#}-{t,t^2b}~L~{t,0,x},{x,0}]&/@%
%^2b
```

(Assuming an interactive environment). Input is entered in the form `{n, a0, a1}`.
Below is the output of a sample run with input `{9, 3, 1.5}`:

```
{0, 1/8, 1/4, 3/8, 1/2, 5/8, 3/4, 7/8, 1}
{0., 0.13247799662957596, 0.2912428843578418, 0.4665152489073556, 0.6468180849532895, 0.8280191118364263, 1.0089961907516996, 1.189503180997409, 1.369535545562379}
{0., 0.026325629386478908, 0.1272336265336128, 0.3264547161946379, 0.6275604525339613, 1.0284234743495764, 1.5271099694271602, 2.122376726404432, 2.8134414158382643}
```

### Explanation

This uses `FindRoot` to find `x`s where the `ArcLength` of the original equation to each point in x0 matches the `ArcLength` of the flattened equation up to each `x`.

Here is a visualization of the points in the example:
[image]

With the (identical) corresponding arc lengths at each point:

```
{0., 0.1358872650466621, 0.32491055615709175, 0.5908450391982809, 0.9421066199781004, 1.3821781999397988, 1.9127768947936938, 2.534864156640448, 3.249029586202852}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer! If you haven't already, make sure to check out the [Tips for Golfing in Mathematica](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12900/tips-for-golfing-in-mathematica?r=SearchResults&s=1|58.0185) to see if there's any way to shorten your answer.

Comment: [91 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b737GoKLEyuuL9pIXVFTrlOuVxRsq1@npumXkpQfn5JdHp0UYVykaxyrpARrlyrLKRTnW5TkVtrI6ysU61gY5hbawaV7qtY1FycGZehoOytvKjjlkahtrKcUaaav8DijLzSvQdQjKKUhNTHNKijfWNdIx1LGP/AwA) function taking `[a1, a0, n]` returning a list of `{x0, x1, y1}`s